# Git Status Takes a Long Time to Complete

Tags: windows, git

I'm using `git` to manage files in a local directory on a Windows machine - no network is involved here, I'm not pushing or pulling to/from another machine.  My directory has maybe 100 files in it, all test files, pretty small.  When I run `git status`, it regularly takes 20-30 seconds to complete.  Is this normal?  Is there anything I can do to speed it up, or a better way to see what the state of my repository is (changed files, untracked files, etc)?  Other `git` commands seem to complete much faster.

Comment: Which git version are you using? Please consider asking for help either on msysGit Google Group, or on git mailing list (git [at] vger.kernel.org, you don't need to subscribe), perhaps this is a bug in git.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ways to improve git status performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4994772/3510513)

Comment: See also "[UNTRACKED FILES AND PERFORMANCE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74889434/6309)" with `git status`.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Have you tried *[git gc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc)*?  This cleans cruft out of the git repo.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick.  I'm very surprised though that after only a couple of commits that the repository would have that much stuff that can be cleaned up - thanks!

Comment: Hehe, I just ran the `git status` using the `time` command and got a "real" time of 30.464s. I then ran `git gc` then `time git status` once more and got a real time of 35.409s. Pretty strange.

Comment: This fixed me from 33 seconds down to less than 1 second for most of my repositories. It would be nice if Git would tell you to do this when you start getting to that point. I never knew it was needed.

Comment: When running `git status` multiple times in a row, the subsequent runs take just fraction of the first one. So, if you are running `git status`, then `git gc` and then `git status` again, it is expected it will run super quick.

Comment: Thanks! I had attempted a few solutions but only this simple one solved the problem. :)

Answer (score 28):

Running `git fsck` has resolved this issue for me in the past.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck

Comment: this worked for me. could explain little more about it.

Answer (score 12):

Are you using some kind of virus protection software? Maybe that is interfering with things. `git` is very fast for me on windows with repositories of 1000's of files.

Comment: Yes, employer mandated TrendMicro OfficeScan. I killed the virus scanner, same results with git status.

Comment: Another variant on this theme is on-the-fly encryption software such as Credant, which can make your box remarkably slower.

Comment: This was the problem for me. Killed Kaspersky antivirus and status was back to <1 second.

Comment: Damn AV - it seems that anti-malware "solutions" cause as many problems as they supposedly solve..

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried repacking? [git-repack](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack).

Otherwise, try duplicating the directory, and deleting the .git folder in the duplicated directory.  Then create a new git directory and see if it's still slow.

If it's still slow, then it sounds like a system or hardware issue.  Git finishes status on hundreds of files for me in less than 5 seconds.

Comment: repack seemed to help - after running it, I ran status, and it returned immediately.  However, I waited a few seconds and ran status again, and it took 30 seconds.  I tried duplicating the directory, and got the same problem.

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  Do you have an external drive? Or a USB flash stick? Try copying the repo over there and see if there's any difference.  It's possible there's an issue with the drive it's currently on.

Comment: No difference on a USB drive.

Comment: That's really strange.  All I can really say at this point is that I don't know.  You could try copying your repo and try it on someone else's computer -- that should, at least, tell you if it's a problem local to your system.

Answer (score 7):

On a similar issue I found that having a git repo in a directory below my existing git repo caused a massive slow down.

I moved the secondary git repo somewhere else and now the speed is fast!

Comment: I add similar problem. What happend is did git init in a subdirectory. The problem of that is then, subdir is kind of hidden (you need to do git status inside to see the changes) but I guess git is still trying to compute them. I ignore the subdir and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 7):

For me, the slowness was due to having a lot of untracked files (temporary and output files from scripts.) Running `git status -uno`, which excludes the untracked files, ran much faster, and meets my requirements

Answer (score 6):

For some reason `git status` is particularly slow after moving or copying the repository folder to a new location.

Subsequent runs are usually quicker in this case.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this slowness in the first run? I tried git gc,but it didn't help.It's not a problem since it only happens on the first time after copying the files.

Comment: I am not aware of a way to avoid the initial slowness, but if there was some command that could do it, it would probably be doing the same thing as the initial `git status` command, so would probably take the same amount of time to complete.

Answer (score 5):

My `git status` was very slow (up to one minute), because the global `.gitignore` file was located in my windows userprofile, which was stored on an inaccessible network share.

`git config --global core.excludesfile`
 showed something like `\\Nxxxx0\User\Username\Eigene Dateien\gitignore_global.txt`

For some reason `\\Nxxxx0` was inaccessible and my userprofile was loaded from a backup system `\\Nxxxxx1`. It took some time to figure that out, because usually my userprofile is bound to a drive letter by an enterprise startup script and accessing that drive letter was working as usual.
I'm not sure why the git-config used the network share and not the drive letter (probably a younger me is to blame)

After setting 
`git config --global core.excludesfile $HOME/Eigene\ Dateien/gitignore_global.txt`
 `git status` was back to normal speed.

Answer (score 2):

Older versions of git have a performance issue with git status - see [Ways to improve git status performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994772/ways-to-improve-git-status-performance/43644347#43644347) for more info.

git 2.13 has 1 fix, and 2.17 more. i moved from 2.7 to 2.23 and it resolved slow status. There is another improvement planned for 2.24 soon.

Answer (score 2):

Often git is extremely slow because of the large number of untracked files.
Try this,

```
git status -uno
```

Answer (score 1):

For files you do not version, see also "[UNTRACKED FILES AND PERFORMANCE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74889434/6309)" with `git status`.

Another aspect of [`git status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) which will be improved (in Git 2.14.x/2.15, Q4 2017) is when it shows ignored files as well ([`git status --ignored`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#git-status---ignored))

> "`git status --ignored`", when noticing that a directory without any
> tracked path is ignored, still enumerated all the ignored paths in
> the directory, which is unnecessary.
> The codepath has been optimized to avoid this overhead.

See [commit 5aaa7fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5aaa7fd39aafb83fdb30a6af4685eda5fc1cd382) (18 Sep 2017) by [Jameson Miller (`jamill`)](https://github.com/jamill).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 075bc9c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/075bc9c79818a5e18b43f6e5aeb8ff6415381ca9), 29 Sep 2017)</sup>

> ### Improve performance of `git status --ignored`

> Improve the performance of the directory listing logic when it wants to list non-empty ignored directories. In order to show non-empty ignored directories, the existing logic will recursively iterate through all contents of an ignored directory.
> This change introduces the optimization to stop iterating through the contents once it finds the first file. This can have a significant improvement in 'git status --ignored' performance in repositories with a large number of files in ignored directories.

> For an example of the performance difference on an example repository with
> 196,000 files in 400 ignored directories:

```
| Command                    |  Time (s) |
| -------------------------- | --------- |
| git status                 |   1.2     |
| git status --ignored (old) |   3.9     |
| git status --ignored (new) |   1.4     |
```

For more improvment (set in Git 2.17, Q2 2018), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183769/git-status-takes-a-long-time-to-complete).

Comment: Totally random example here: `node_modules` might be affected by this perf change.  Just maybe.

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was a huge ZIP file within this git directory. Also `*.zip` is a line in the `.gitignore` file:

```
CMakeCache.txt
CMakeFiles
Makefile
cmake_install.cmake
[...]
*.csv
*.zip
[...]
```

I have moved this zip file (~915 MB) to some other folder, and this solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there was an issue with the fact that the internet provider where I'm located doesn't support IPv4.

> SSH supports both IPv4 and IPv6 and prefers IPv6 if the DNS retrieves
> AAAA record, but my ISP doesn't support IPv6, which results in huge
> delays

I was able to figure this out thanks to  giridharkannan over at the [atlassian community](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Slow-SSH-clone-pull-push/qaq-p/953843)

They suggest changing the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file so it contains the line:

```
AddressFamily inet
```

However, I am using windows. Setting up an IPv4 address did not let SSH ignore IPv6 and it was still taking very long to perform `git pull`s and `git push`es

So, I ended up appending the -4 flag that you can append to ssh to force it to use IPv4, this works for both `git pull` and `git push`:

```
git pull -4
git push -4
```

This should also work for *nix without needing to change the ssh_config file.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671706/configure-git-to-use-ipv4-instead-of-ipv6-by-default) is an answer which goes into more detail about how to force git to use either IPv4 or IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, slowness was caused by running `git status` as a different user from the owner of the files in the project.

While not applicable in all instance, a simple `chown` to your current user may do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why this is the case, but I had this issue with a repo that uses Git LFS when `git-lfs` was not installed. I hadn't installed it because I didn't actually need any of the files, but installing `git-lfs` fixed the speed issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

The issue for me was that I had a lot of different repositories cloned onto my local hard drive, the more repos you have the longer it will take to run commands like git status.

I simply deleted a lot of the repos which I no longer needed locally, and my git status went from 1minute~ to 5 seconds.

I can't see any answers similar to this here.

Comment: I don't think this can affect the standard `git status` you run in one directory in any way. If your repositories are checked out into different directories, you can only run `git status` for one of them at a time. It might be a different story if your git repos are overlapping, but that's a bad idea anyways.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak it definitely can. They were all over on different places on my hard drive for me but it greatly affected my load times when typing git status. After removing duplicate repositories it immediately became faster from multiple minutes to 5 seconds.

Answer (score -17):

Try starting with a fresh clone of your checkout.

```
git clone myrepo mynewrepo
```

and then do git status in mynewrepo.

Alternatively, and if you are braver, clean out the rubbish from your existing checkout.

```
git clean -dfx
```

This avoids git having to scan some (possibly large) set of ignored or not checked-in files.

Comment: I don't think deleting all your ignored files (what git clean does) would help, it's already ignoring them. More likely running git clean would delete all your configuration files, etc etc. And this command is not undoable. Re-cloning (first saving your old repository in case you need it) is far better than running git clean and has the same effect.

Comment: I have to disagree with this answer, running git clean -dfx may break things.