# How can I debug git/git-shell related problems?

Tags: git, debugging, trace

How can I have some debug information regarding git/git-shell?

I had a problem, that `user1` could clone a repository without problem, while `user2` could clone only an empty one. I had set `GIT_TRACE=1`, but nothing useful was told.

Finally, after a long trial and error, it turned out that it was a permission problem on a file. An appropriate error message could short-circuit this problem.

Comment: Note: in addition of `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE`, you will have with Git 2.9.x/2.10 `GIT_TRACE_CURL`. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38285866/6309).

Comment: And (Q2 2019, three years after `GIT_TRACE_CURL`), you now have `trace2`. Example: `git config --global trace2.normalTarget ~/log.normal`. See [my (new) answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094711/6309).

Comment: `trace2` can even display `git config` values used at runtime, used during the execution of a `git` command! ([Git 2.38, Q3 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68965888/6309))

Answer (score 319):

For even more verbose output use following:

`GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git pull origin master`

Comment: There are a few GIT_TRACE options, beyond the core one. Here's the über-verbose option: `set -x; GIT_TRACE=2 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=2 GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=2 GIT_TRACE_PACK_ACCESS=2 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=2 GIT_TRACE_PACKFILE=2 GIT_TRACE_SETUP=2 GIT_TRACE_SHALLOW=2 git pull origin master -v -v; set +x`

Comment: That's just a whole line you can paste into your terminal. You should replace the `git pull origin master` part with the command you want to execute.

Comment: On Windows you can set these variables, one at a time (one per line), like this: `set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` `set GIT_TRACE=1` `git pull origin master`

Comment: And on powershell you can set them like this: ```$Env:GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1```

Comment: @PaulIrish's oneliner wrapped in parantheses (so that the `set -x` does not leak into the shell on abort/ Ctrl+c ) ... and making underlying *ssh* invocations extra-verbose  ....: `(set -x; GIT_TRACE=2 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=2 GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=2 GIT_TRACE_PACK_ACCESS=2 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=2 GIT_TRACE_PACKFILE=2 GIT_TRACE_SETUP=2 GIT_TRACE_SHALLOW=2 GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv"` **`git <command> -vv`** `)`

Answer (score 147):

#### Debugging

Git has a fairly complete set of traces embedded which you can use to debug your git problems.

To turn them on, you can define the following variables:

- `GIT_TRACE` for general traces,
- `GIT_TRACE_PACK_ACCESS` for tracing of packfile access,
- `GIT_TRACE_PACKET` for packet-level tracing for network operations,
- `GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE` for logging the performance data,
- `GIT_TRACE_SETUP` for information about discovering the repository and environment it’s interacting with,
- `GIT_MERGE_VERBOSITY` for debugging recursive merge strategy (values: 0-5),
- `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE` for logging all curl messages (equivalent to `curl -v`),
- `GIT_TRACE_SHALLOW` for debugging fetching/cloning of shallow repositories.

Possible values can include:

- `true`, `1` or `2` to write to stderr,
- an absolute path starting with `/` to trace output to the specified file.

For more details, see: [Git Internals - Environment Variables](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#Debugging)

---

#### SSH

For SSH issues, try the following commands:

```
echo 'ssh -vvv "$*"' > ssh && chmod +x ssh
GIT_SSH="$PWD/ssh" git pull origin master
```

or use `ssh` to validate your credentials, e.g.

```
ssh -vvvT git@github.com
```

or over HTTPS port:

```
ssh -vvvT -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
```

<sup>Note: Reduce number of `-v` to reduce the verbosity level.</sup>

---

#### Examples

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git status
20:11:39.565701 git.c:350               trace: built-in: git 'status'

$ GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=$PWD/gc.log git gc
Counting objects: 143760, done.
...
$ head gc.log 
20:12:37.214410 trace.c:420             performance: 0.090286000 s: git command: 'git' 'pack-refs' '--all' '--prune'
20:12:37.378101 trace.c:420             performance: 0.156971000 s: git command: 'git' 'reflog' 'expire' '--all'
...

$ GIT_TRACE_PACKET=true git pull origin master
20:16:53.062183 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch< 93eb028c6b2f8b1d694d1173a4ddf32b48e371ce HEAD\0multi_ack thin-pack side-band side-band-64k ofs-delta shallow no-progress include-tag multi_ack_detailed symref=HEAD:refs/heads/master agent=git/2:2.6.5~update-ref-initial-update-1494-g76b680d
...
```

Comment: Changing `echo 'ssh -vvv $*' > ssh && chmod +x ssh` to `echo 'ssh -vvv "$@"' > ssh && chmod +x ssh` should be safer in the edge case where a single parameter has a space in it.

Comment: @AlexanderBird, ...though not as safe as one would _want_, because when ssh is given several different arguments in the command-to-run-remotely position, it just concatenates them together with spaces into a single string the remote shell `eval`s as code. One might end up with something like `ssh -vvv "${*@Q}"` in trying to do it right.

Answer (score 55):

If its over SSH, you can use the following:

For a higher debug level for type -vv or -vvv for debug level 2 and 3 respectively:

```
# Debug level 1
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git clone <repositoryurl>

# Debug level 2
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vv" git clone <repositoryurl>

# Debug level 3
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git clone <repositoryurl>
```

This is mainly useful to handle public and private key problems with the server.
You can use this command for any git command, not only 'git clone'.

Comment: Yes, this works perfect. Better than others.  Yes, this works perfect. Better than others.

Comment: This would be most useful as I have to resolve a key problem now, but it doesn't work for me with git 1.8.3.1 and OpenSSH_6.6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013 on CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core). :(

Comment: @GregDubicki Strange. Let me know what works for you so that I can update the answer.

Comment: On Windows use `set GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -v` (no quotes).

Comment: On Powershell you'd use `$env:GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v"` ... the above commenter didn't mean "Windows" but `cmd.exe` _on_ Windows.

Answer (score 51):

try this one:

```
GIT_TRACE=1 git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 24):

Git 2.9.x/2.10 (Q3 2016) adds another debug option: `GIT_TRACE_CURL`.

See [commit 73e57aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/73e57aaf4ded85bb5387365f1ebefaabf80cf073), [commit 74c682d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/74c682d3c63bff8860af5caf9bd38a5413568709) (23 May 2016) by [Elia Pinto (`devzero2000`)](https://github.com/devzero2000).
Helped-by: [Torsten Bögershausen (`tboegi`)](https://github.com/tboegi), Ramsay Jones ramsay@ramsayjones.plus.com, [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster), [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco), and [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2f84df2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2f84df2ca0f7a5174d2eb5f4ee52324ce8f807b9), 06 Jul 2016)</sup>

> ### `http.c`: implement the `GIT_TRACE_CURL` environment variable

> Implement the `GIT_TRACE_CURL` environment variable to allow a greater degree of detail of `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE`, in particular the complete transport header and all the data payload exchanged.
> It might be useful if a particular situation could require a more thorough debugging analysis.

[The documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/74c682d3c63bff8860af5caf9bd38a5413568709/Documentation/git.txt#L1078-L1083) will state:

> ```
> GIT_TRACE_CURL
> ```
>
> Enables a curl full trace dump of all incoming and outgoing data,     including descriptive information, of the git transport protocol.
> This is similar to doing `curl --trace-ascii` on the command line.
>
> This option overrides setting the `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE` environment variable.

---

You can see that new option used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38752916/6309), but also in the Git 2.11 (Q4 2016) tests:

See [commit 14e2411](https://github.com/git/git/commit/14e24114d9cfe2f878ee540e4df485c2cae8253a), [commit 81590bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81590bf77db239c156c8ba5c3042d231b1a5995e), [commit 4527aa1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4527aa10a6030fc8b4b65f1081b7089a9c6d9457), [commit 4eee6c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4eee6c6ddc73a3d09e8703a168fe4bb121162d15) (07 Sep 2016) by [Elia Pinto (`devzero2000`)](https://github.com/devzero2000).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 930b67e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/930b67ebd7450a72248111582c1955cd6f174519), 12 Sep 2016)</sup>

> Use the new `GIT_TRACE_CURL` environment variable instead
> of the **deprecated** `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE`.

```
GIT_TRACE_CURL=true git clone --quiet $HTTPD_URL/smart/repo.git
```

---

Note that all command do not necessarily emit traces.
For instance: you would need Git 2.32 (Q2 2021) before the reflog expiry machinery has been taught to emit trace events.

See [commit 34c3199](https://github.com/git/git/commit/34c319970d1ccdeaa612fccdfa3e6a5f2847f1e7) (23 Apr 2021) by [Han-Wen Nienhuys (`hanwen`)](https://github.com/hanwen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a850356](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a850356d1b29ad915acb9f9e144867e90db16da3), 07 May 2021)</sup>

> ### [`refs/debug`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/34c319970d1ccdeaa612fccdfa3e6a5f2847f1e7): trace into reflog expiry too
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Han-Wen Nienhuys</sup>

---

With Git 2.39 (Q4 2022), redact headers from cURL's `h2h3` module in `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE` and others.

See [commit b637a41](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b637a41ebe0e65b6d64dd65efaf848b4705dcbed) (11 Nov 2022) by [Glen Choo (`chooglen`)](https://github.com/chooglen).
See [commit 73c49a4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/73c49a447461449ada646b74dfa5dcb0e9f3e879) (11 Nov 2022) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6adf170](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6adf17050b1b28612fd49a11b302b959fee1e192), 23 Nov 2022)</sup>

> ### [`http`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b637a41ebe0e65b6d64dd65efaf848b4705dcbed): redact curl `h2h3` headers in info
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Glen Choo</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> With `GIT_TRACE_CURL=1` or `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1,` sensitive headers like "Authorization" and "Cookie" get redacted.
> However, since [`curl/curl` commit f8c3724](https://github.com/curl/curl/commit/f8c3724aa90472c0e617ddbbc420aa199971eb77), curl's `h2h3` module (invoked when using HTTP/2) also prints headers in its "`info`", which don't get redacted.
> For example,
>
> ```
> echo 'github.com  TRUE    /   FALSE   1698960413304   o   foo=bar' >cookiefile &&
> GIT_TRACE_CURL=1 GIT_TRACE_CURL_NO_DATA=1 git \
>   -c 'http.cookiefile=cookiefile' \
>   -c 'http.version=' \
>   ls-remote https://github.com/git/git refs/heads/main 2>output &&
> grep 'cookie' output
> ```
>
> produces output like:
>
> ```
> 23:04:16.920495 http.c:678              == Info: h2h3 [cookie: o=foo=bar]
> 23:04:16.920562 http.c:637              => Send header: cookie: o=<redacted>
> ```
>
> Teach [`http.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b637a41ebe0e65b6d64dd65efaf848b4705dcbed/http.c) to check for `h2h3` headers in info and redact them using the existing header redaction logic.
> This fixes the broken redaction logic that we noted in the previous commit, so mark the redaction tests as passing under HTTP2.

---

With Git 2.42 (Q3 2023), Git handles both "h2" and "h2h3" in curl info lines

See [commit fb7d80e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fb7d80edcae482f4fa5d4be0227dc3054734e5f3) (24 Jun 2023) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit db30130](https://github.com/git/git/commit/db30130165bef1ceff04c0163db6676db23ba2fc) (17 Jun 2023) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 94486b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94486b6763c29144c60932829a65fec0597e17b3), 24 Jun 2023)</sup>

> ### [`http`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/db30130165bef1ceff04c0163db6676db23ba2fc): handle both "h2" and "h2h3" in curl info lines
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> When redacting auth tokens in trace output from curl, we look for http/2 headers of the form "h2h3 [header: value]".
> This comes from [b637a41](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b637a41ebe0e65b6d64dd65efaf848b4705dcbed) ("`http`: redact curl h2h3 headers in info", 2022-11-11, Git v2.39.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6adf17050b1b28612fd49a11b302b959fee1e192)).
>
> But the "`h2h3`" prefix changed to just "`h2`" in [`curl`'s fc2f1e5 commit](https://github.com/curl/curl/commit/fc2f1e547a4a4b4bec5fd3c8bfde5136706488a1)  (http2: support HTTP/2 to forward proxies, non-tunneling, 2023-04-14).
> That's in released version curl 8.1.0; linking against that version means we'll fail to correctly redact the trace.
> Our t5559.17 notices and fails.
>
> We can fix this by matching either prefix, which should handle both old and new versions.

---

With Git 2.43 (Q4 2023), HTTP Header redaction code has been adjusted for a newer version of cURL library that shows its traces differently from earlier versions.

See [commit 0763c3a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0763c3a2c4f21a9e81990cc5cbee4a66d4efefcb), [commit 39fa527](https://github.com/git/git/commit/39fa527c8976da84cf70a9ea6b6d92a1fd9bd772) (15 Sep 2023) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7a90d1e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a90d1eb4d40dbddd0a88a925cf1d4de4462d69f), 22 Sep 2023)</sup>

> ### [`http`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0763c3a2c4f21a9e81990cc5cbee4a66d4efefcb): update `curl` http/2 info matching for curl 8.3.0
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> To redact header lines in http/2 curl traces, we have to parse past some prefix bytes that curl sticks in the info lines it passes to us.
> That changed once already, and we adapted in [db30130](https://github.com/git/git/commit/db30130165bef1ceff04c0163db6676db23ba2fc) (`http`: handle both , 2023-06-17, Git v2.42.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94486b6763c29144c60932829a65fec0597e17b3) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a9e066fa63149291a55f383cfa113d8bdbdaa6b3)) (http: handle both "h2" and "h2h3" in curl info lines, 2023-06-17).
>
> Now it has changed again, in [curl's fbacb14 commit](https://github.com/curl/curl/commit/fbacb14c4c0fbb31bde308c8878c6b694b6043c6) (`http2`: cleanup trace messages, 2023-08-04), which was released in curl 8.3.0.
> Running a build of `git` linked against that version will fail to redact the trace (and as before, t5559 notices and complains).
>
> The format here is a little more complicated than the other ones, as it now includes a "stream id".
> This is not constant but is always numeric, so we can easily parse past it.
>
> We'll continue to match the old versions, of course, since we want to work with many different versions of curl.
> We can't even select one format at compile time, because the behavior depends on the runtime version of `curl` we use, not the version we build against.

---

trace2 streams used to record the URLs that potentially embed authentication material, which has been corrected with Git 2.44 (Q1 2024).

See [commit b7d49ac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b7d49ac1ecd05669edada26b990eee677a7d3c25) (22 Nov 2023) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
See [commit 16fa3ee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/16fa3eebc0b92dc2aa5d875c2f1338644e3c5b99), [commit c73e7f8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c73e7f80d32073b6fafec553d5875e720287e216), [commit abcdb97](https://github.com/git/git/commit/abcdb978ea13010357ef2bf265f7bf0c55f96dbe) (22 Nov 2023) by [Jeff Hostetler (`Jeff-Hostetler`)](https://github.com/Jeff-Hostetler).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c1aefb6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c1aefb6d04fc585ead10dd99282d694d189a2995), 18 Dec 2023)</sup>

> ### [`trace2`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b7d49ac1ecd05669edada26b990eee677a7d3c25): redact passwords from https:// URLs by default
>
> <sup>Co-authored-by: Jeff Hostetler</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff Hostetler</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> It is an unsafe practice to call something like
>
> ```
> git clone https://user:password@example.com/
> ```
>
> That not only risks leaking the password "over the shoulder" or into the readline history of the current Unix shell, it also gets logged via Trace2 if enabled.
>
> Let's at least avoid logging such secrets via Trace2, much like we avoid logging secrets in [`http.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b7d49ac1ecd05669edada26b990eee677a7d3c25/http.c).
> Much like the code in [`http.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b7d49ac1ecd05669edada26b990eee677a7d3c25/http.c) is guarded via `GIT_TRACE_REDACT` (defaulting to `true`), we guard the new code via `GIT_TRACE2_REDACT` (also defaulting to `true`).

Comment: This feature is cool! The only point is ASCII output (where they print all that is not `(ch >= 0x20) && (ch < 0x80)` as dot `.`) and no way of hex output for http data.

Comment: I like it. I am using `git version 2.39.1` and in contrast to the documentation, I seem to find that with `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=true GIT_TRACE_CURL=true git push` that `GIT_TRACE_CURL` is actually overridden by `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE`.

Comment: @learning2learn Strange, maybe a bug. These days, I usually rely only on TRACE2. From [this search](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Agit%2Fgit+GIT_CURL_VERBOSE&type=code), `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE` seems really not used anymore.

Comment: See also [commit fb7d80e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fb7d80edcae482f4fa5d4be0227dc3054734e5f3)

Answer (score 16):

Git 2.22 (Q2 2019) introduces **`trace2`** with [commit ee4512e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee4512ed481a126dadd33334186e0e759d7f2f47) by **Jeff Hostetler**:

> ### `trace2`: create new combined trace facility

> Create a new unified tracing facility for git.
> The eventual intent is to replace the current `trace_printf*` and `trace_performance*` routines with a unified set of `git_trace2*` routines.
>
> In addition to the usual printf-style API, `trace2` provides higer-level
> event verbs with fixed-fields allowing structured data to be written.
> This makes post-processing and analysis easier for external tools.
>
> Trace2 defines 3 output targets.
> These are set using the environment variables "`GIT_TR2`", "`GIT_TR2_PERF`", and "`GIT_TR2_EVENT`".
> These may be set to "1" or to an absolute pathname (just like the current `GIT_TRACE`).

Note: regarding environment variable name, always use `GIT_TRACExxx`, not `GIT_TRxxx`.
So actually `GIT_TRACE2`, `GIT_TRACE2_PERF` or `GIT_TRACE2_EVENT`.
See the Git 2.22 rename mentioned later below.

What follows is the *initial* work on this new tracing feature, with the *old* environment variable names:

> - `GIT_TR2` is intended to be a replacement for `GIT_TRACE` and logs command summary data.
> - `GIT_TR2_PERF` is intended as a replacement for `GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE`.
>   It extends the output with columns for the command process, thread, repo, absolute and relative elapsed times.
>   It reports events for child process start/stop, thread start/stop, and per-thread function nesting.
> - `GIT_TR2_EVENT` is a new structured format. It writes event data as a series of JSON records.
>
> Calls to trace2 functions log to any of the 3 output targets enabled without the need to call different `trace_printf*` or `trace_performance*` routines.

See [commit a4d3a28](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a4d3a283db5259cc372809da4dc085c3f40aebfb) (21 Mar 2019) by [Josh Steadmon (`steadmon`)](https://github.com/steadmon).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1b40314](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b403146616286e017d4fc1dfcbb056d56200655), 08 May 2019)</sup>

> ### `trace2`: write to directory targets

> When the value of a trace2 environment variable is an absolute path referring to an existing directory, write output to files (one per process) underneath the given directory.
> Files will be named according to the final component of the trace2 SID, followed by a counter to avoid potential collisions.
>
> This makes it more convenient to collect traces for every git invocation
> by unconditionally setting the relevant `trace2` envvar to a constant
> directory name.

---

See also [commit f672dee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f672deec2d56b0d7ae64ce3efd918e02efc58b9c) (29 Apr 2019), and [commit 81567ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81567caf87c655ba13260bd66d8ec67b8d6e492b), [commit 08881b9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/08881b9a4c841b77bc2a4a17510ee33b98070b9e), [commit bad229a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bad229aef232256f3fb6e8ed9c09e26ff654399c), [commit 26c6f25](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26c6f251d754a33c188ce7ad8f5ea6cb0bc740d7), [commit bce9db6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bce9db6de97c95882a7c46836bb6cc90acf0fef0), [commit 800a7f9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/800a7f99a8776b18a48cf9c1b0f9418bf4644bbd), [commit a7bc01e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a7bc01eb25c8743a9ab22d7007555b3ccad5d99c), [commit 39f4317](https://github.com/git/git/commit/39f43177442d44d8a945c3ff6a8c08f481539763), [commit a089724](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a089724958a99924d9ec7ff60a6aea63d03448f2), [commit 1703751](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1703751f21d286b383c198157a1342c35ebc11b7) (15 Apr 2019) by [Jeff Hostetler (`jeffhostetler`)](https://github.com/jeffhostetler).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5b2d1c0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5b2d1c0c6eceb5fd6c9527bc2863179644dce840), 13 May 2019)</sup>

The [new documentation](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81567caf87c655ba13260bd66d8ec67b8d6e492b#diff-9f1a5a26c622b3e584ff5b20e3076565) now includes [config settings which are only read from the system and global config files](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bce9db6de97c95882a7c46836bb6cc90acf0fef0) (meaning repository local and worktree config files and `-c` command line arguments are not respected.)

[Example](https://github.com/git/git/blob/81567caf87c655ba13260bd66d8ec67b8d6e492b/Documentation/technical/api-trace2.txt#L53-L66):

```
$ git config --global trace2.normalTarget ~/log.normal
$ git version
git version 2.20.1.155.g426c96fcdb
```

yields

```
$ cat ~/log.normal
12:28:42.620009 common-main.c:38                  version 2.20.1.155.g426c96fcdb
12:28:42.620989 common-main.c:39                  start git version
12:28:42.621101 git.c:432                         cmd_name version (version)
12:28:42.621215 git.c:662                         exit elapsed:0.001227 code:0
12:28:42.621250 trace2/tr2_tgt_normal.c:124 atexit elapsed:0.001265 code:0
```

And for [performance measure](https://github.com/git/git/blob/81567caf87c655ba13260bd66d8ec67b8d6e492b/Documentation/technical/api-trace2.txt#L87-L102):

```
$ git config --global trace2.perfTarget ~/log.perf
$ git version
git version 2.20.1.155.g426c96fcdb
```

yields

```
$ cat ~/log.perf
12:28:42.620675 common-main.c:38                  | d0 | main                     | version      |     |           |           |            | 2.20.1.155.g426c96fcdb
12:28:42.621001 common-main.c:39                  | d0 | main                     | start        |     |  0.001173 |           |            | git version
12:28:42.621111 git.c:432                         | d0 | main                     | cmd_name     |     |           |           |            | version (version)
12:28:42.621225 git.c:662                         | d0 | main                     | exit         |     |  0.001227 |           |            | code:0
12:28:42.621259 trace2/tr2_tgt_perf.c:211         | d0 | main                     | atexit       |     |  0.001265 |           |            | code:0
```

---

As documented in Git 2.23 (Q3 2019), the environment variable to use is **`GIT_TRACE2`**.

See [commit 6114a40](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6114a405bdc548886920e2c789b14ae4990e071f) (26 Jun 2019) by [Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón (`carenas`)](https://github.com/carenas).
See [commit 3efa1c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3efa1c6b33279a233afd357c9be02b92bb60433f) (12 Jun 2019) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e9eaaa4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e9eaaa46906753ca8958df33328a0590b0287166), 09 Jul 2019)</sup>

That follows the work done in Git 2.22: [commit 4e0d3aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4e0d3aa18a60db8bf3448d4fceeed9c8ac8cc597), [commit e4b75d6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4b75d6a1d3105958c307e526ae6759e86f7f837) (19 May 2019) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 463dca6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/463dca6476be5f4998f8a836cd8141f58e1b42ee), 30 May 2019)</sup>

> ### `trace2`: rename environment variables to GIT_TRACE2*

> For an environment variable that is supposed to be set by users, the `GIT_TR2*` env vars are just too unclear, inconsistent, and ugly.
>
> Most of the established `GIT_*` environment variables don't use
> abbreviations, and in case of the few that do (`GIT_DIR`, `GIT_COMMON_DIR`, `GIT_DIFF_OPTS`) it's quite obvious what the abbreviations (`DIR` and `OPTS`) stand for.
> But what does `TR` stand for? Track, traditional, trailer, transaction, transfer, transformation, transition, translation, transplant, transport, traversal, tree,
> trigger, truncate, trust, or ...?!
>
> The trace2 facility, as the '2' suffix in its name suggests, is
> supposed to eventually supercede Git's original trace facility.
> It's reasonable to expect that the corresponding environment variables
> follow suit, and after the original `GIT_TRACE` variables they are
> called `GIT_TRACE2`; there is no such thing is '`GIT_TR`'.
>
> All trace2-specific config variables are, very sensibly, in the
> '`trace2`' section, not in '`tr2`'.
>
> OTOH, **we don't gain anything at all by omitting the last three
> characters of "trace" from the names of these environment variables**.
>
> So let's rename all `GIT_TR2*` environment variables to `GIT_TRACE2*`,
> before they make their way into a stable release.

---

Git 2.24 (Q3 2019) improves the Git repository initialization.

See [commit 22932d9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/22932d9169fea7c826c85e2407054feff30ebaf1), [commit 5732f2b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5732f2b1ef3559f2b2a5c67302f8bf21846488bc), [commit 58ebccb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/58ebccb478b34a1babf2719fd64e3adb3974139c) (06 Aug 2019) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b4a1eec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b4a1eec33249344b5c7b978d397259088cafd219), 09 Sep 2019)</sup>

> ### common-main: delay trace2 initialization

> We initialize the `trace2` system in the common main() function so that
> all programs (even ones that aren't builtins) will enable tracing.
>
> But `trace2` startup is relatively heavy-weight, as we have to actually read
> on-disk config to decide whether to trace.
> This can cause unexpected interactions with other common-main initialization. For instance, we'll end up in the config code before calling `initialize_the_repository()`, and the usual invariant that `the_repository` is never NULL will not hold.
>
> Let's push the `trace2` initialization further down in common-main, to
> just before we execute `cmd_main()`.

---

Git 2.24 (Q4 2019) makes also sure that output from `trace2` subsystem is formatted more prettily now.

See [commit 742ed63](https://github.com/git/git/commit/742ed63345a6e26399fc08e9c711e9f3fd23cc2d), [commit e344305](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e34430556c8cb7c99a561125df3c8f595c385e7e), [commit c2b890a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2b890aca50885ce7503dfe4bdae4ac83bbb2331) (09 Aug 2019), [commit ad43e37](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad43e37839ea6a3cf369af074a723a60cd66233b), [commit 04f10d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/04f10d332f47aed7d93ff3ed5c2bb3a366e44693), [commit da4589c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/da4589ce7ecb84b51b2819542f9555848dccf726) (08 Aug 2019), and [commit 371df1b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/371df1bea994d14347c3bea7a67066056d86b093) (31 Jul 2019) by [Jeff Hostetler (`jeffhostetler`)](https://github.com/jeffhostetler).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 93fc876](https://github.com/git/git/commit/93fc8760e7a29ce9e93c90c63523f0c1f25498bb), 30 Sep 2019)</sup>

And, still Git 2.24

See [commit 87db61a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/87db61a4363ad9f42cf7b0d90ad13763dc01e3af), [commit 83e57b0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/83e57b04e6ae3bc4c714812768f61bc41b1d56ad) (04 Oct 2019), and [commit 2254101](https://github.com/git/git/commit/22541013d00bc457fe1fbdc8ac8b79edc069fd7e), [commit 3d4548e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d4548e7e29177b6a5e21c73009bc40c63c8ce62) (03 Oct 2019) by [Josh Steadmon (`steadmon`)](https://github.com/steadmon).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d0ce4d9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d0ce4d9024882b5363141288979ea3689eab9998), 15 Oct 2019)</sup>

> ### [`trace2`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/83e57b04e6ae3bc4c714812768f61bc41b1d56ad): discard new traces if target directory has too many files
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Josh Steadmon</sup>

> `trace2` can write files into a target directory.
> With heavy usage, this directory can fill up with files, causing difficulty for trace-processing systems.
>
> This patch adds a config option (`trace2.maxFiles`) to set a maximum number of files that `trace2` will write to a target directory.
>
> The following behavior is enabled when the `maxFiles` is set to a positive integer:
>
> - When `trace2` would write a file to a target directory, first check whether or not the traces should be discarded.
>   Traces should be discarded if:
>
>   - there is a sentinel file declaring that there are too many files
>   - OR, the number of files exceeds `trace2.maxFiles`.
>     In the latter case, we create a sentinel file named `git-trace2-discard` to speed up future checks.
>
> The assumption is that a separate trace-processing system is dealing with the generated traces; once it processes and removes the sentinel file, it should be safe to generate new trace files again.
>
> The default value for `trace2.maxFiles` is zero, which disables the file count check.
>
> The config can also be overridden with a new environment variable: `GIT_TRACE2_MAX_FILES`.

---

And Git 2.24 (Q4 2019) teach trace2 about `git push` stages.

See [commit 25e4b80](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25e4b8099c0ed4c2b4eeb3c8a7edce3785d9aeab), [commit 5fc3118](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5fc31180d87c5f20c4cdfb89f93daf77c3bd50a1) (02 Oct 2019) by [Josh Steadmon (`steadmon`)](https://github.com/steadmon).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3b9ec27](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3b9ec279191b70e9e5ecde15910991f7c5669a17), 15 Oct 2019)</sup>

> ### [`push`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25e4b8099c0ed4c2b4eeb3c8a7edce3785d9aeab): add trace2 instrumentation
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Josh Steadmon</sup>

> Add trace2 regions in [`transport.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/25e4b8099c0ed4c2b4eeb3c8a7edce3785d9aeab/transport.c) and [`builtin/push.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/25e4b8099c0ed4c2b4eeb3c8a7edce3785d9aeab/builtin/push.c) to better track time spent in various phases of pushing:
>
> - Listing refs
> - Checking submodules
> - Pushing submodules
> - Pushing refs

---

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), some of the `Documentation/technical` is moved to header `*.h` files.

See [commit 6c51cb5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6c51cb525da47a751b856bba55522ca9d4c24dac), [commit d95a77d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d95a77d05988ed1682c3e2bf1b94523341ef58b7), [commit bbcfa30](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bbcfa3002a6534613d8b74ecac0e19876dbfc2d3), [commit f1ecbe0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1ecbe0f539ad8cb40cadb69e369cf42aa975d33), [commit 4c4066d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c4066d95d861808f655cd29bf68aa45c0f02d19), [commit 7db0305](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7db03054384e3ab8d50e4b0397b0a8d63f7436e0), [commit f3b9055](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f3b9055624cb797b1956f100a40104c9aceb4835), [commit 971b1f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/971b1f24a2190ebe288fc6544378941a0624bb95), [commit 13aa9c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/13aa9c8b708dd65f32ac12f8b2faa48f5a89f07d), [commit c0be43f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0be43f8986b1653cb4c401e288f38b1b5d595de), [commit 19ef3dd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/19ef3ddd36cdd426c35523a420c78e13a36b6f99), [commit 301d595](https://github.com/git/git/commit/301d595e7271662d2e8456d1ef68ede09b5b99a6), [commit 3a1b341](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a1b3415d9330cbe3d3cce125b971dff96d0aa4c), [commit 126c1cc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/126c1ccefbeec2b3ba368146f057054352484ef4), [commit d27eb35](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d27eb356bf253be763ab08733fae723adda27e1c), [commit 405c6b1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/405c6b1fbc699a9651e3a555612fd7a31590a509), [commit d3d7172](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d3d7172e4002a360b8a463363968593cfb261dbe), [commit 3f1480b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3f1480b745b70e9f7c0629b58a98ddcb516490bb), [commit 266f03e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/266f03eccd36b84c88206aa6d18b163223294229), [commit 13c4d7e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/13c4d7eb228ea29dba77f8800daf2bd0ac54755a) (17 Nov 2019) by [Heba Waly (`HebaWaly`)](https://github.com/HebaWaly).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 26c816a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26c816a67de449b3c5284ab97b03aeeeeabbb45c), 16 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`trace2`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6c51cb525da47a751b856bba55522ca9d4c24dac): move doc to `trace2.h`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Heba Waly</sup>

> Move the functions documentation from `Documentation/technical/api-trace2.txt` to `trace2.h` as it's easier for the developers to find the usage information beside the code instead of looking for it in another doc file.
>
> Only the functions documentation section is removed from `Documentation/technical/api-trace2.txt` as the file is full of details that seemed more appropriate to be in a separate doc file as it is, with a link to the doc file added in the trace2.h. Also the functions doc is removed to avoid having redundandt info which will be hard to keep syncronized with the documentation in the header file.

(although that reorganization had a side effect on another command, explained and fixed with Git 2.25.2 (March 2020) in [commit cc4f2eb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cc4f2eb8281ab9f6f71694834ea01c93572d224a) (14 Feb 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1235384](https://github.com/git/git/commit/123538444f7b95ec99e6add1949e837be66a973a), 17 Feb 2020)</sup>)

---

With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020): Trace2 enhancement to **allow logging of the environment variables**.

See [commit 3d3adaa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d3adaad914441a6e7b916eb8dfd5ae638aab068) (20 Mar 2020) by [Josh Steadmon (`steadmon`)](https://github.com/steadmon).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 810dc64](https://github.com/git/git/commit/810dc6481ad7c1e1a6aacebfeaed308778c6c63f), 22 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`trace2`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d3adaad914441a6e7b916eb8dfd5ae638aab068): teach Git to log environment variables
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Josh Steadmon</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Jeff Hostetler</sup>

> Via trace2, Git can already log interesting config parameters (see the `trace2_cmd_list_config()` function). However, this can grant an incomplete picture because many config parameters also allow overrides via environment variables.
>
> To allow for more complete logs, we add a new `trace2_cmd_list_env_vars()` function and supporting implementation, modeled after the pre-existing config param logging implementation.

---

With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), teach codepaths that show progress meter to also use the `start_progress()` and the `stop_progress()` calls as a "`region`" to be traced.

See [commit 98a1364](https://github.com/git/git/commit/98a136474082cdc7228d7e0e45672c5274fab701) (12 May 2020) by [Emily Shaffer (`nasamuffin`)](https://github.com/nasamuffin).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d98abce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d98abce68f4bd79aa29c66497a5eda3415668430), 14 May 2020)</sup>

> ### [`trace2`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/98a136474082cdc7228d7e0e45672c5274fab701): log progress time and throughput
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Emily Shaffer</sup>

> Rather than teaching only one operation, like '`git fetch`', how to write down throughput to traces, **we can learn about a wide range of user operations that may seem slow by adding tooling to the progress library itself**.
>
> Operations which display progress are likely to be slow-running and the kind of thing we want to monitor for performance anyways.
>
> By showing object counts and data transfer size, we should be able to make some derived measurements to ensure operations are scaling the way we expect.

And:

With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), last-minute fix for our recent change to allow use of progress API as a traceable region.

See [commit 3af029c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3af029c484fc72f546078966af538db55933e83d) (15 May 2020) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 85d6e28](https://github.com/git/git/commit/85d6e28a620c91c5c789b38271a662b384269d46), 20 May 2020)</sup>

> ### [`progress`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3af029c484fc72f546078966af538db55933e83d): call `trace2_region_leave()` only after calling `_enter()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> A user of progress API calls `start_progress()` conditionally and depends on the `display_progress()` and `stop_progress()` functions to become no-op when `start_progress()` hasn't been called.
>
> As we added a call to `trace2_region_enter()` to `start_progress()`, the calls to other trace2 API calls from the progress API functions must make sure that these trace2 calls are skipped when `start_progress()` hasn't been called on the progress struct.
>
> Specifically, do not call `trace2_region_leave()` from `stop_progress()` when we haven't called `start_progress()`, which would have called the matching `trace2_region_enter()`.

---

That last part is more robust with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020):

See [commit ac900fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ac900fddb7fd3cc760ea5c1b79a50ad4564e4a0d) (10 Aug 2020) by [Martin Ågren (`none`)](https://github.com/none).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e6ec620](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e6ec620d8b2d576908889476eb7da716d2e4bda2), 17 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`progress`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ac900fddb7fd3cc760ea5c1b79a50ad4564e4a0d): don't dereference before checking for `NULL`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Martin Ågren</sup>

> In `stop_progress()`, we're careful to check that `p_progress` is non-NULL before we dereference it, but by then we have already dereferenced it when calling `finish_if_sparse(*p_progress)`.
> And, for what it's worth, we'll go on to blindly dereference it again inside `stop_progress_msg()`.

---

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), there is even more trace, this time in a Git development environment.

See [commit 4441f42](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4441f4270758042cc38ce8c04e4350ada743b28a) (09 Sep 2020) by [Han-Wen Nienhuys (`hanwen`)](https://github.com/hanwen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c9a04f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9a04f036f6d52a2bca1c41bda6ecc1633c8e4cb), 22 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`refs`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4441f4270758042cc38ce8c04e4350ada743b28a): add `GIT_TRACE_REFS` debugging mechanism
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Han-Wen Nienhuys</sup>

> When set in the environment, `GIT_TRACE_REFS` makes `git` print operations and results as they flow through the ref storage backend.
> This helps debug discrepancies between different ref backends.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> $ GIT_TRACE_REFS="1" ./git branch
> 15:42:09.769631 refs/debug.c:26         ref_store for .git
> 15:42:09.769681 refs/debug.c:249        read_raw_ref: HEAD: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (=> refs/heads/ref-debug) type 1: 0
> 15:42:09.769695 refs/debug.c:249        read_raw_ref: refs/heads/ref-debug: 3a238e539bcdfe3f9eb5010fd218640c1b499f7a (=> refs/heads/ref-debug) type 0: 0
> 15:42:09.770282 refs/debug.c:233        ref_iterator_begin: refs/heads/ (0x1)
> 15:42:09.770290 refs/debug.c:189        iterator_advance: refs/heads/b4 (0)
> 15:42:09.770295 refs/debug.c:189        iterator_advance: refs/heads/branch3 (0)
> ```

`git` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4441f4270758042cc38ce8c04e4350ada743b28a/Documentation/git.txt#L725-L728):

> ### `GIT_TRACE_REFS`
>
> Enables trace messages for operations on the ref database.
> See `GIT_TRACE` for available trace output options.

---

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), like `die()` and `error()`, a call to `warning()` will also trigger a trace2 event.

See [commit 0ee10fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0ee10fd12968b78dbd1ccbba108599a24f31f70b) (23 Nov 2020) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2aeafbc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2aeafbc8967078b5b3804e03d48cc4d22fa045ca), 08 Dec 2020)</sup>

> ### [`usage`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0ee10fd12968b78dbd1ccbba108599a24f31f70b): add trace2 entry upon `warning()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Tan</sup>

> Emit a trace2 error event whenever `warning()` is called, just like when `die()`, `error()`, or `usage()` is called.
>
> This helps debugging issues that would trigger warnings but not errors.
> In particular, this might have helped debugging an issue I encountered with commit graphs at [$DAYJOB](https://lore.kernel.org/git/202006292207441054093-1-jonathantanmy@google.com/).
>
> There is a tradeoff between including potentially relevant messages and cluttering up the trace output produced.
> I think that `warning()` messages should be included in traces, because by its nature, Git is used over multiple invocations of the Git tool, and a failure (currently traced) in a Git invocation might be caused by an unexpected interaction in a previous Git invocation that only has a warning (currently untraced) as a symptom - as is the [case in here](https://lore.kernel.org/git/202006292207441054093-1-jonathantanmy@google.com/).

---

With Git 2.35 (Q1 2022), `exit` is properly traced:

See [commit 368b584](https://github.com/git/git/commit/368b58431588e0468ac66b013b91c50bc4c4c718) (07 Dec 2021) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 67b7017](https://github.com/git/git/commit/67b7017593d1ee878dd4aae9c51f81db1742752e), 22 Dec 2021)</sup>

> ### [`common-main.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/368b58431588e0468ac66b013b91c50bc4c4c718): call exit(), don't return
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Change the main() function to call "exit()" instead of ending with a "return" statement.
> The "exit()" function is our own wrapper that calls `trace2_cmd_exit_fl()` for us, from [`git-compat-util.h`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/368b58431588e0468ac66b013b91c50bc4c4c718/git-compat-util.h):
>
> ```
> #define exit(code) exit(trace2_cmd_exit_fl(__FILE__, __LINE__, (code)))
> ```
>
> That "exit()" wrapper has been in use ever since [ee4512e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee4512ed481a126dadd33334186e0e759d7f2f47) ("`trace2`: create new combined trace facility", 2019-02-22, Git v2.22.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f7213a3d33f81035c0707b0f547462ecfa620223) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e902e9bcae2010bc42648c80ab6adc6c5a16a4a5)).
>
> There is already code immediately downstream of our "main()" which has a hard reliance on that, e.g. the various "exit()" calls downstream of `"cmd_main()`" in "[`git.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/368b58431588e0468ac66b013b91c50bc4c4c718/git.c)".

---

With Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), the progress API is more robust regarding tracing.

See [commit b3118a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3118a56f99ca0ec872b84dc760a0dc778f3890e), [commit 74900a6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/74900a6b3513e0908b1d16df7855e9d478b20b91), [commit accf1eb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/accf1eb1d0f102c6b8f099fa6063216818e45c6b), [commit 1ccad6a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ccad6a1f175080c3896a70501dcd6c9e0a0af0a), [commit a02014b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a02014bb4c711db69e029e21f6ea776c4cc7f385), [commit bbfb1c2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bbfb1c243d5da5dc0427346315d915ba02e8d0dd), [commit 791afae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/791afae2924d032186bfad557c462c92025ac901), [commit 587c3d0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/587c3d0da67aecc7c9defb576614962f8ca3faf8), [commit 8266e0c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8266e0c02973618f68b45957a2dcb29660737486) (03 Feb 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a47fcfe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a47fcfe8712e3258d1c565cd654c9bd5312a5168), 25 Feb 2022)</sup>

> ### [`progress API`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/74900a6b3513e0908b1d16df7855e9d478b20b91): unify `stop_progress{,_msg}()`, fix trace2 bug
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> We've had a submarine bug here introduced with [9d81ecb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d81ecb52b5e6611f66c968884dde42928350b18) ("`progress`: add sparse mode to force 100% complete message", 2019-03-21, Git v2.22.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ec08c4fd951b9ea5136aaecbaec834ffb665da80) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ffac537e6cbbf934b08745a378932722df287a53)).
> The `"start_sparse_progress()`" API would only do the right thing if the progress was ended with `"stop_progress()`", not `"stop_progress_msg()`".
>
> The only user of that API uses `"stop_progress()`", but let's still fix that along with the trace2 issue by making `"stop_progress()`" a trivial wrapper for `"stop_progress_msg()`".

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried adding the verbose (`-v`) operator when you clone?

`git clone -v git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/.../linux-2.6 my2.6`

Answer (score 4):

## For older git versions (1.8 and before)

I could find **no suitable way to enable SSH debugging** in an older git and ssh versions.  I looked for environment variables using `ltrace -e getenv ...` and couldn't find any combination of GIT_TRACE or SSH_DEBUG variables that would work.

Instead here's a recipe to temporarily inject 'ssh -v' into the git->ssh sequence:

```
$ echo '/usr/bin/ssh -v ${@}' >/tmp/ssh
$ chmod +x /tmp/ssh
$ PATH=/tmp:${PATH} git clone ...
$ rm -f /tmp/ssh
```

Here's output from **git version 1.8.3** with ssh version **OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013** cloning a github repo:

```
$ (echo '/usr/bin/ssh -v ${@}' >/tmp/ssh; chmod +x /tmp/ssh; PATH=/tmp:${PATH} \
   GIT_TRACE=1 git clone https://github.com/qneill/cliff.git; \
   rm -f /tmp/ssh) 2>&1 | tee log
trace: built-in: git 'clone' 'https://github.com/qneill/cliff.git'
trace: run_command: 'git-remote-https' 'origin' 'https://github.com/qneill/cliff.git'
Cloning into 'cliff'...
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/q.neill/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com ...
...
Transferred: sent 4120, received 724232 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 21590.6, received 3795287.2
debug1: Exit status 0
trace: run_command: 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
trace: exec: 'git' 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
```

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.37 (Q3 2022), a new `bug()` and `BUG_if_bug()` API is introduced to make it easier to uniformly log "detect multiple bugs and abort in the end" pattern.

That will be part of trace2 output, which is used to debug git-shell related issues.

See [commit 6d40f0a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d40f0ad15e72daab6524988c9c4b4a3460488f8), [commit 07b1d8f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/07b1d8f184e126eef8223757844587cf91d6e14c), [commit 5b2f5d9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5b2f5d92ca5afc118d3fb798c1f25863a5011a01), [commit 53ca569](https://github.com/git/git/commit/53ca569419aed9706b052c48656715ab0b5f14fd), [commit 0cc05b0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0cc05b044fd690f37565262a5b09f60c203c5218), [commit 19d7594](https://github.com/git/git/commit/19d75948ef7abe9066efa4462108827d70565ae9) (02 Jun 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4da14b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4da14b574f2e52eb05e4fef7ed169a8f9e3a8b67), 10 Jun 2022)</sup>

> ### [`usage.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0cc05b044fd690f37565262a5b09f60c203c5218): add a non-fatal bug() function to go with BUG()
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Add a bug() function to use in cases where we'd like to indicate a runtime BUG(), but would like to defer the BUG() call because we're possibly accumulating more bug() callers to exhaustively indicate what went wrong.
>
> We already have this sort of facility in various parts of the codebase, just in the form of ad-hoc re-inventions of the functionality that this new API provides.
> E.g.
> this will be used to replace optbug() in [`parse-options.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0cc05b044fd690f37565262a5b09f60c203c5218/parse-options.c), and the 'error("BUG:[...]' we do in a loop in [`builtin/receive-pack.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0cc05b044fd690f37565262a5b09f60c203c5218/builtin/receive-pack.c).
>
> Unlike the code this replaces we'll log to trace2 with this new bug() function (as with other [`usage.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0cc05b044fd690f37565262a5b09f60c203c5218/usage.c) functions, including BUG()), we'll also be able to avoid calls to xstrfmt() in some cases, as the bug() function itself accepts variadic sprintf()-like arguments.
>
> Any caller to bug() can follow up such calls with `BUG_if_bug()`, which will BUG() out (i.e.
> abort()) if there were any preceding calls to bug(), callers can also decide not to call `BUG_if_bug()` and leave the resulting BUG() invocation until exit() time.
> There are currently no bug() API users that don't call `BUG_if_bug()` themselves after a for-loop, but allowing for not calling `BUG_if_bug()` keeps the API flexible.
> As the tests and documentation here show we'll catch missing `BUG_if_bug()` invocations in our exit() wrapper.

`technical/api-error-handling` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0cc05b044fd690f37565262a5b09f60c203c5218/Documentation/technical/api-error-handling.txt#L4):

> `BUG`, `bug`, `die`, `usage`, `error`, and `warning` report errors of

`technical/api-error-handling` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0cc05b044fd690f37565262a5b09f60c203c5218/Documentation/technical/api-error-handling.txt#L10-L31):

> - `bug` (lower-case, not `BUG`) is supposed to be used like `BUG` but
>   prints a "BUG" message instead of calling `abort()`.
>
> A call to `bug()` will then result in a "real" call to the `BUG()`
> function, either explicitly by invoking `BUG_if_bug()` after call(s)
> to `bug()`, or implicitly at `exit()` time where we'll check if we
> encountered any outstanding `bug()` invocations.
>
> If there were no prior calls to `bug()` before invoking `BUG_if_bug()`
> the latter is a NOOP. The `BUG_if_bug()` function takes the same
> arguments as `BUG()` itself. Calling `BUG_if_bug()` explicitly isn't
> necessary, but ensures that we die as soon as possible.
>
> If you know you had prior calls to `bug()` then calling `BUG()` itself
> is equivalent to calling `BUG_if_bug()`, the latter being a wrapper
> calling `BUG()` if we've set a flag indicating that we've called
> `bug()`.

`technical/api-trace2` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0cc05b044fd690f37565262a5b09f60c203c5218/Documentation/technical/api-trace2.txt#L468-L469):

> This event is emitted when one of the `BUG()`, `bug()`, `error()`,
> `die()`, `warning()`, or `usage()` functions are called.

---

With Git 2.38 (Q3 2022), you can even [print the configuration values used by a command at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68965888/6309).

Answer (score 0):

Git 2.39 (Q4 2022) adds two new `trace2` facilities, "`timer`" and "`counter`":

See [commit 8107162](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81071626ba1ec54ad72de1e0a9a49c78eb87a2c8), [commit 8ad5756](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8ad575646c0b1e927a05650a1ec64125121ae591), [commit 24a4c45](https://github.com/git/git/commit/24a4c45da9e1255df43a87bec1f646b1efa69209), [commit 3124793](https://github.com/git/git/commit/31247936041318d441de5a2681f9bcb79459c726), [commit a70839c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a70839cf36c9cad10e514f75fa1bec2e6180dbda), [commit 8e8c5ad](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e8c5ad27a0a35f1be31af48050a8c81892c452d), [commit 5bbb925](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5bbb9251378b0e62bb06e72bda0574e06dee4933), [commit 545ddca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/545ddca0c32cb3ccdffed4aa9f063c84b432940c) (24 Oct 2022) by [Jeff Hostetler (`Jeff-Hostetler`)](https://github.com/Jeff-Hostetler).
<sup>(Merged by [Taylor Blau -- `ttaylorr` --](https://github.com/ttaylorr) in [commit e5be3c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e5be3c632af4ea1ec6d9406d30f7f8cf54f5e9e7), 30 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`trace2`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8ad575646c0b1e927a05650a1ec64125121ae591): add stopwatch timers
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff Hostetler</sup>

> Timers are an alternative to Trace2 Regions.
> Regions are useful for measuring the time spent in various computation phases, such as the time to read the index, time to scan for unstaged files, time to scan for untracked files, and etc.
>
> However, regions are not appropriate in all places.
>
> For example, during a checkout, it would be very inefficient to use regions to measure the total time spent inflating objects from the ODB  (Object DataBase) from across the entire lifetime of the process; a per-`unzip()` region would flood the output and significantly slow the command; and some form of post-processing would be required to compute the time spent in `unzip()`.
>
> Timers can be used to measure a series of timer intervals and emit a single summary event (at thread and/or process exit).

`technical/api-trace2` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8ad575646c0b1e927a05650a1ec64125121ae591/Documentation/technical/api-trace2.txt#L772-L807):

> ### `"th_timer"`
>
> This event logs the amount of time that a stopwatch timer was
> running in the thread.  This event is generated when a thread
> exits for timers that requested per-thread events.
>
> ```
> {
> "event":"th_timer",
> ...
> "category":"my_category",
> "name":"my_timer",
> "intervals":5,         # number of time it was started/stopped
> "t_total":0.052741,    # total time in seconds it was running
> "t_min":0.010061,      # shortest interval
> "t_max":0.011648       # longest interval
> }
> ```
>
> ### `"timer"`
>
> This event logs the amount of time that a stopwatch timer was
> running aggregated across all threads.  This event is generated
> when the process exits.
>
> ```
> {
> "event":"timer",
> ...
> "category":"my_category",
> "name":"my_timer",
> "intervals":5,         # number of time it was started/stopped
> "t_total":0.052741,    # total time in seconds it was running
> "t_min":0.010061,      # shortest interval
> "t_max":0.011648       # longest interval
> }
> ```

`technical/api-trace2` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8ad575646c0b1e927a05650a1ec64125121ae591/Documentation/technical/api-trace2.txt#L1239-L1292):

> ### `Stopwatch Timer Events`
>
> Measure the time spent in a function call or span of code
> that might be called from many places within the code
> throughout the life of the process.
>
> ```
> static void expensive_function(void)
> {
> trace2_timer_start(TRACE2_TIMER_ID_TEST1);
> ...
> sleep_millisec(1000); // Do something expensive
> ...
> trace2_timer_stop(TRACE2_TIMER_ID_TEST1);
> }
>
> static int ut_100timer(int argc, const char **argv)
> {
> ...
>
> expensive_function();
>
> // Do something else 1...
>
> expensive_function();
>
> // Do something else 2...
>
> expensive_function();
>
> return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> In this example, we measure the total time spent in
> `expensive_function()` regardless of when it is called
> in the overall flow of the program.
>
> ```
> $ export GIT_TRACE2_PERF_BRIEF=1
> $ export GIT_TRACE2_PERF=~/log.perf
> $ t/helper/test-tool trace2 100timer 3 1000
> ...
> $ cat ~/log.perf
> d0 | main                     | version      |     |           |           |              | ...
> d0 | main                     | start        |     |  0.001453 |           |              | t/helper/test-tool trace2 100timer 3 1000
> d0 | main                     | cmd_name     |     |           |           |              | trace2 (trace2)
> d0 | main                     | exit         |     |  3.003667 |           |              | code:0
> d0 | main                     | timer        |     |           |           | test         | name:test1 intervals:3 total:3.001686 min:1.000254 max:1.000929
> d0 | main                     | atexit       |     |  3.003796 |           |              | code:0
> ```

And, still with Git 2.39:

> ### [`trace2`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81071626ba1ec54ad72de1e0a9a49c78eb87a2c8): add global counter mechanism
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff Hostetler</sup>

> Add global counters mechanism to Trace2.
>
> The Trace2 counters mechanism adds the ability to create a set of global counter variables and an API to increment them efficiently.
> Counters can optionally report per-thread usage in addition to the sum across all threads.
>
> Counter events are emitted to the Trace2 logs when a thread exits and at process exit.
>
> Counters are an alternative to `data` and `data_json` events.
>
> Counters are useful when you want to measure something across the life of the process, when you don't want per-measurement events for performance reasons, when the data does not fit conveniently within a region, or when your control flow does not easily let you write the final total.
> For example, you might use this to report the number of calls to `unzip()` or the number of de-delta steps during a checkout.

`technical/api-trace2` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/81071626ba1ec54ad72de1e0a9a49c78eb87a2c8/Documentation/technical/api-trace2.txt#L808-L838):

> ### `"th_counter"`
>
> This event logs the value of a counter variable in a thread.
> This event is generated when a thread exits for counters that
> requested per-thread events.
>
> ```
> {
> "event":"th_counter",
> ...
> "category":"my_category",
> "name":"my_counter",
> "count":23
> }
> ```
>
> ### `"counter"`
>
> This event logs the value of a counter variable across all threads.
> This event is generated when the process exits.  The total value
> reported here is the sum across all threads.
>
> ```
> {
> "event":"counter",
> ...
> "category":"my_category",
> "name":"my_counter",
> "count":23
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Windows cmd allows daisy chaining and thus the windows command answer is

`set "GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1" & set "GIT_TRACE=1" & git pull origin master`