# Git push doesnt do anything over HTTPS

Tags: git, github, push

When im pushing to my remote repository through https ,there is no response from the terminal.
[This happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSaWt.png):

[image: screenshot]

```
git push origin2 master
# noting
```

SSH works fine and I am able to push.
Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55599672/251311

Comment: which operating system is this? I've had something similar happen to me in ubuntu due to gnutls. Try running `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push origin2 master`

Comment: using windows as os

Comment: is it git bash, ubuntu subsystem or something else, what...?

Comment: git bash, tried using GUI  too and it gives a similar response when im trying to push over HTTPS.

Comment: This seems to have started plaguing Windows users just this week. As I'm not one of the affected, I don't have proper details, but it seems that some Windows thingy that asks for a password is silently *not* asking for a password even though it's waiting for you to type in a password (somewhere, probably not in whatever program you used to start the `git push`) and Git is waiting for that program. The cure seems (from other similar questions) to be to start the `git push` from some other environment, so that you can see the pop-up window pop up and enter a password.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using GIT_TRACE1, as suggested in comments, use (with a [recent enough Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094711/6309)), `GIT_TRACE2_EVENT`

```
set GIT_TRACE2_EVENT=1
git push
# to cancel traces
set GIT_TRACE2_EVENT=
```

Check also the output of `git remote -v` to check:

- that origin2 does exist
- that it is an HTTPS URL

Comment: origin2 and https url is as required. I tried using Trace as per your commands and got a similar response.

Comment: @ali_cr8 What is your version of Windows? (type winver)

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and solved it using the **GitHub Desktop** app. When you run it go to the *Repository* menu and choose *Open in Command Prompt*. Then try to push your commit with: *git push* command
It will now ask you how you wish to authenticate and give you 2 options:

1. Web Authentication <- that's the one you need
2. Personal token

choose 1 and hit ENTER, it will direct you to the GitHub page where you can grant relevant permission. That's all. Happy coding :)