# git push on the branch doing nothing after executing command - https

Tags: git, github

I'm new to GIT - I have created a branch name: first branch and trying to push to remote/central repo but when I try to execute the below command nothing happens without a error message

*

> *$ git push origin firstbranch*

- 

Other checks:

> $ git remote show origin
>
> - remote origin   Fetch URL: https://github.com/tharun1234/git-github.git
>   Push  URL:
>   https://github.com/tharun1234/git-github.git   HEAD branch: main
>   Remote branch:
>   main tracked

No commits - all clean(Everything commited both on master and branch)

> $ git status On branch firstbranch nothing to commit, working tree
> clean
>
> $ git status
> On branch master nothing to commit, working tree clean

Below is the screenshot - where it looks it waiting for something but i tried waiting long still nothing happens without an error message

[image: below is the link where i executed the git push]

Comment: try with `-v` to add verbosity

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67931716/git-push-doesnt-do-anything-over-https#comment120072116_67931716

Comment: Could you please help me with complete command to execute