# Git Credential Manager popup window not displaying until after command is cancelled. Credentials not being stored

Tags: windows, git, authentication, github

I am trying to use Git for Windows after a fresh install with all of the default settings.

Any attempt to communicate with Github (eg, clone) hangs, showing no messages but    `Cloning into...`.

When I run the command with `> GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone --verbose` , I am able to see that it is hanging on the credential manager `trace: run_command: git-credential-manager-core get`, but the credential window is displayed only AFTER I use CTRL-C to halt the operation.

Is there a setting that is preventing the popup window from being displayed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67931716/git-push-doesnt-do-anything-over-https#comment120072116_67931716