# GitBash can clone and pull but can't push, it show nothing while GitDesktop can

Tags: git, git-bash

I've just reinstall my operating system. But when i use git, I just can use clone and pull. When i use push, nothings happens, show no error. However, I use git desktop and it can push my repo. Could you help me, I have googling for this problem since last week :((
sorry for my bad English.

Comment: It would be better to post the command you used to do git push

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67931716/git-push-doesnt-do-anything-over-https#comment120072116_67931716