# Git push get stuck, take forever

Tags: git, github, git-push

I am trying to push my code to github, but after run "git push", it take me too long, and nothing happen for 15minutes though I just only added small a new txt file for testing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVjyr.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67931716/git-push-doesnt-do-anything-over-https#comment120072116_67931716

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. To fix this I restarted the ssh-agent.

```
killall ssh-agent; eval `ssh-agent`
```