# When I tried to push the code to GitHub it is not asking me username and password for authentication

Tags: git, github, git-push

I tried
git config --unset credential.helper
but that doesn't seems to work .

I am using git version 2.32.0.windows.1

Comment: What OS do you use? Have you tried removing the git entry in the credential manager itself? Have you tried restarting?

Comment: I am using Windows OS . I tried removing in the credential manager and I tried restarting as well . But Still it is not working

Comment: More details, please! In what way it doesn't work? What command(s) did you run and what the result(s)?

Comment: I ran this command  " git push origin master " . when I clicked on enter the cursor moved to the next line which is blank rather than asking for username and password for authentication   https://youtu.be/A1_Ni6Eje6Y?t=2366  This is the video I am using to learn Git . In that video when he used that command it is working fine . But for me its not working . Not Sure about the root cause . I tried everything possible

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67931716/git-push-doesnt-do-anything-over-https#comment120072116_67931716

Comment: By using command prompt It worked . Thanks for helping me out !