# When trying to push code to GitHub nothing happens

Tags: git, github, push

I am trying to push a file to my GitHub repository. When I type `git push -u origin master` and press enter, nothing shows in the screen. When I press *Ctrl+c*, then it shows a box for username. When I type my username and press enter, it shows an error.

What can I do?

[image]

Comment: No. Actually my problem is when i type this **git push -u origin master** and hit enter,  i waited for 10 minuts and nothing showing in my screen.After that i press **ctrl+c** then that aksing for username and getting that error

Comment: Can you try pushing via SSH instead of HTTPS?

Comment: try changing the origin URL. Run this command `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:anuprasadgc/game.git` after that try pushing the code

Comment: i tried SSH insted of HTTPS but no way still getting that error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67931716/git-push-doesnt-do-anything-over-https#comment120072116_67931716

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

**Steps**

```
 Open your Control Panel

 Open Credential Manager

 Click Window Credentials

 Goto Generic Credential section there would be git url update username and 
 password

 Restart Git Bash and try again to push
```