# Git Bash gets stuck on diff / log, spontaneously repeats same command over and over

Tags: git, git-bash

I'm having an odd problem with Git Bash on Windows 7 / XP. It used to work fine, but recently I find that after I perform a `git diff` or `git log`, Git Bash becomes unusable: following the diff/log, even after I return to the command prompt, Bash keeps suddenly and apparently spontaneously repeating the same command, unprompted and while I'm in the middle of typing a subsequent command.

Has anyone else had this problem? Any advice would be much appreciated, because this is really limiting Git Bash's usefulness at the moment.

Comment: Do you exit the pager with `q`?

Comment: Ah, no - I was using Ctrl-C to get back to the command prompt. Is that wrong? The strange thing is it used to work fine, but now it doesn't.

Comment: Ctrl-C should not quit the pager (and it does not on a linux system). When you Ctrl-C on windows (msysgit I suppose?), you are somehow killing the process "from the outside" (i.e. from cmd.exe).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You have to use `q` to quit git's pager. Using Ctrl-C only causes problems on windows.

Ctrl-C should not quit the pager (and it does not on a linux system). When you Ctrl-C on windows (msysgit I suppose?), you are somehow killing the process "from the outside" (i.e. from cmd.exe). I don't know the exact reasons why this happens.

As I've experienced similar problems in the past: try to hit `q` and Ctrl-C repeatedly in random order, if you're lucky you'll get a working prompt back again ;) [There's no better solution I know of – but it worked for me …]

Comment: Thanks, that totally fixes it! I am indeed using msysgit. Slightly embarrassing that I was just pressing the wrong key... It's strange and confusing though that Ctrl-C sort-of *almost* works. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: Once I stopped using Ctrl+C - no more glitches! Thank you

Comment: On Ubuntu 11, I solved that by closing and reopening the terminal.

Comment: For me, on Windows 7, "q" stops less from working but also freezes the screen. Everything I type after "q" is held on standard input until I press CTRL-C, at which point all my frustrated attempts at commands are executed in the shell!

Answer (score 1):

Note that with Git 2.12 (Q1 2017, 6+ years later), a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in a git pager session should behave better.

See [commit 46df690](https://github.com/git/git/commit/46df6906f3aaf74dafe2026b028c8c5c1a0d5f58), [commit 246f0ed](https://github.com/git/git/commit/246f0edec0b789ccfeebcf7fef85417b7cb04425), [commit 2b296c9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2b296c93d49d65303a4ce291225c8755eeab1ff8) (07 Jan 2017) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5918bdc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5918bdcf26030a2540ac25d5b8cbee82fad219fc), 18 Jan 2017)</sup>

> ### `execv_dashed_external`: wait for child on signal death

> Typing `^C` to `pager`, which usually does not kill it, killed Git and took the pager down as a collateral damage in certain process-tree structure.
> This has been fixed.

You can run any dashed external with commands like `git -p stash list`, where the command finishes running, but the pager is still going.

The short version is that everything should stop normally (Git and pager)

But in detail:

> When `git` runs a `pager`, it's important for the git process to
> hang around and wait for the `pager` to finish, even though it
> has no more data to feed it.
> This is because `git` spawns the `pager` as a child, and thus the `git` process is the session leader on the terminal. After it dies, the `pager` will finish its current read from the terminal (eating the one
> character), and then get `EIO` trying to read again.

Note: `EIO` (error 5) tands for Error I/O, and is ([source](http://aplawrence.com/Unixart/errors.html)) the:

> catchall for all manner of unexpected hardware errors. It could be from a physical error, but additionally, an orphaned process (a process whose parent has died) that attempts to read from standard input will get this. BSD systems return this if you try to open a pty device that is already in use.
> An attempt to read from a stream that is closed will return EIO, as will a disk read or write that is outside of the physical bounds of the device.
> An open of `/dev/tty` when the process has no controlling tty will spit back `EIO` also.

So (back to `^C` in a `pager`):

> When you hit `^C`, that sends `SIGINT` to `git` and to the `pager`,
> and it's a similar situation.
> The `pager` ignores it, but the `git` process needs to hang around until the pager is done. We addressed that long ago in [a3da882 (pager: do
> wait_for_pager on signal death, 2009-01-22)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a3da8821208d6243dc5530d668f7c8f089814899).

> But when you have a dashed external (or an alias pointing to a builtin, which will re-exec git for the builtin), there's an extra process in the mix.
> For instance, running:

```
$ git -c alias.l=log l
```

> will end up with a process tree like:

```
  git (parent)
    \
     git-log (child)
      \
       less (pager)
```

> If you hit `^C`, `SIGINT` goes to all of them. The pager ignores it, and the child git process will end up in wait_for_pager().
> But the parent git process will die, and the usual EIO trouble happens.

---

With Git 2.28 (Q3 2020), when an aliased command, whose output is piped to a pager by git, gets killed by a signal, the pager got into a funny state, which has been corrected (again).

See [commit c0d73a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0d73a59c956ace5e02c9f0fab336ac4dbe64102), [commit e662df7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e662df7e830a9d93ca36b74a7b5e670e139b0da1) (07 Jul 2020) by [Trygve Aaberge (`trygveaa`)](https://github.com/trygveaa).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 05920f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05920f041a57ac9ee86a8615cfca414450e65365), 15 Jul 2020)</sup>

> ### [`Ctrl+C`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e662df7e830a9d93ca36b74a7b5e670e139b0da1):Wait for child on signal death for aliases to builtins
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Trygve Aaberge</sup>

> When you hit ^C all the processes in the tree receives it.
> When a `git` command uses a pager, git ignores this and waits until the pager quits.
>
> However, when using an alias there is an additional process in the tree which didn't ignore the signal. That caused it to exit which in turn caused the pager to exit. This fixes that for aliases to builtins.
>
> This was originally fixed in [46df6906](https://github.com/git/git/commit/46df6906f3aaf74dafe2026b028c8c5c1a0d5f58) (`execv_dashed_external`: wait for child on signal death, 2017-01-06), but was broken by [ee4512ed](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee4512ed481a126dadd33334186e0e759d7f2f47) ("`trace2`: create new combined trace facility", 2019-02-22, Git v2.22.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f7213a3d33f81035c0707b0f547462ecfa620223) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e902e9bcae2010bc42648c80ab6adc6c5a16a4a5)) and then [b9140840](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b91408400757d021b10876c36280ef891b502420) ("`git`: avoid calling aliased builtins via their dashed form", 2019-07-29, Git v2.23.0-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c62bc49139f1d18e922fc98e35bb08b1aadbcafc)).

And:

> When we are running an alias to an external command, we want to wait for that process to exit even after receiving ^C which normally kills the git process. This is useful when the process is ignoring SIGINT (which e.g. pagers often do), and then we don't want it to be killed.
>
> Having an alias which invokes a pager is probably not common, but it can be useful e.g. if you have an alias to a git command which uses a subshell as one of the arguments (in which case you have to use an external command, not an alias to a builtin).
>
> This patch is similar to the previous commit, but the previous commit fixed this only for aliases to builtins, while this commit does the same for aliases to external commands. In addition to waiting after clean like the previous commit, this also enables cleaning the child (that was already enabled for aliases to builtins before the previous commit), because `wait_after_clean` relies on it. Lastly, while the previous commit fixed a regression, I don't think this has ever worked properly.

---

Note that if you are using **[trace2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094711/6309)** to debug the situation, the pager is now *properly* traced.

When a pager spawned by the user exited, the trace log did not record its exit status correctly, which has been corrected with Git 2.31 (Q1 2021).

See [commit be8fc53](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be8fc53e364211856cca7affa4472855f96f8fa9), [commit 85db79a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/85db79a96ede0a2c296b2e41df472025f32806cc), [commit c24b7f6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c24b7f67364fc89575926c7c79118df55b6103ef), [commit 61ff12f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/61ff12fa50b051141dd3b451d74dde76a87fece3) (02 Feb 2021) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit dcb11fc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dcb11fc6225edbe2bd7af63eb550b739e7f4a074), 22 Feb 2021)</sup>

> ### [`pager`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be8fc53e364211856cca7affa4472855f96f8fa9): properly log pager exit code when signalled
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> When git invokes a pager that exits with non-zero the common case is that well already return the correct `SIGPIPE` failure from it itself, but the exit code logged in trace2 has always been incorrectly reported<sup>1</sup>.
> Fix that and log the correct exit code in the logs.
>
> Since this gives us something to test outside of our recently-added tests needing a `!MINGW` prerequisite, let's refactor the test to run on `MINGW` and actually check for `SIGPIPE` outside of `MINGW`.
>
> The `wait_or_whine()` is only called with a true `"in_signal"` from from `finish_command_in_signal()`, which in turn is only used in [`pager.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/be8fc53e364211856cca7affa4472855f96f8fa9/pager.c).
>
> The "`in_signal && !WIFEXITED(status)`" case is not covered by tests.
> Let's log the default -1 in that case for good measure.
>
> 1. The incorrect logging of the exit code in was seemingly copy/pasted into `finish_command_in_signal()` in [ee4512e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee4512ed481a126dadd33334186e0e759d7f2f47) ("`trace2`: create new combined trace facility", 2019-02-22, Git v2.22.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f7213a3d33f81035c0707b0f547462ecfa620223) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e902e9bcae2010bc42648c80ab6adc6c5a16a4a5))

Answer (score 0):

Once you are stuck, try *Ctrl-Break* instead of *Ctrl-c*, it works for me. (the actual Pause/Break key near the Scroll Lock one).