# Git clone verbose output?

Tags: git, git-clone, docker-build, verbose

I have to clone a couple of big repos in my Dockerfile. It really can take an hour to clone a single repo and I want to see standard Git progress output to understand what's going on.

However, when Git is started from the Dockerfile, I see no git clone output whatsoever. The only thing printed to console is:

```
Cloning into '/root/lib/opencv'...
POST git-upload-pack (gzip 2052 to 1062 bytes)
```

and then just a silence. While, usually, I expect something like this:

```
Cloning into 'opencv'...
POST git-upload-pack (gzip 2040 to 1052 bytes)
remote: Counting objects: 158365, done.
Receiving objects:   8% (12670/158365), 2.32 MiB | 255.00 KiB/s
... and so on ...
```

How to enable git verbose output in docker build? Maybe I have to start some interactive mode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git clone verbose mode – show each incoming object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599999/git-clone-verbose-mode-show-each-incoming-object)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

As far as I understand it's not the issue of Docker, but the issue of `git`. By default, git shows progress if you are in an *interactive console*.

If you are not, you could specify additional parameters to `git clone` to output progress to stdout:

```
git clone --progress --verbose .....
```