# Calling git clone from C# app doesn't return output data

Tags: c#, git

I am calling git clone from a C# application by creating a new process and it calls git successfully but no ouput is returned to my delegate. This means I can't provide any updates to the user as the process progresses. The Clone_DataOutputReceived method is not being called at all.

```
public void CloneRepo(string repoUrl, string dataPath)
{
   var process = new Process();
   process.StartInfo.FileName = @"git.exe";
   process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"clone {repoUrl}";
   process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = dataPath;

   process.OutputDataReceived += Clone_DataOutputReceived;

   process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
   process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

   process.Start();
   process.BeginOutputReadLine();
   process.WaitForExit();
   process.CancelOutputRead();
}


private void Clone_DataOutputReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   // This method is not being called
   // Expecting d.Data to be populated with the line from the output
}
```

Comment: You redirected standard error, but never read it?

Comment: Also git changes its output if it detects an interactive console (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26056130/git-clone-verbose-output).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set FileName to "cmd.exe" and then issue process.SendCommand("git.exe")  to the cmd instance.

Comment: The process object doesn't have a SendCommand method on it that I have been able to see.