# How can I run git push/pull commands with SSH verbose mode?

Tags: git, ssh

If I run "git push" with the GIT_TRACE=2 environment variable, I get the following:

```
09:25:28.098743 git.c:349               trace: built-in: git 'push' 'origin' 'master'
09:25:28.100261 run-command.c:341       trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'git@bitbucket.org' 'git-receive-pack '\''kevinburke/letter.git'\'''
```

Which is great except sometimes I get this error:

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I only get it intermittently so I'm not sure what's going on. I know ssh has a verbose mode:

```
 -v      Verbose mode. Causes ssh to print debugging messages about its progress. 
         This is helpful in debugging connection, authentication, and configuration
         problems.  Multiple -v options increase the verbosity.  The maximum is 3.
```

It would be great if I could get `git` to run that ssh command with `-vvv` turned on. Is there a way to enable this with environment variables or with config settings?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Put this in your ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host <git-server-FQDN> LogLevel (QUIET|FATAL|ERROR|INFO|VERBOSE|DEBUG|DEBUG1|DEBUG2|DEBUG3)
```

Subsequent git commands that interact with the server should produce desired debug output.

Comment: This doesn't help if you are trying to debug issues with which ssh key is being used.  It is better to use the answer from @Flimm (e.g. GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git ... ).

Answer (score 140):

From Git version 2.3.0, you can use the environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` and pass the `-v` verbose argument like this:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git clone <REPO_SSH>
```

you can also pass `-vvv` for even more verbose level:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git clone <REPO_SSH>
```

(as seen here https://askubuntu.com/a/620985/975188)

note that you can also run this with other `git` commands, such as `git push`, `git fetch` etc.

From Git version 2.10.0, you can even configure this per repo or globally:

```
git config core.sshCommand "ssh -v"
git pull
git push
```

Comment: For older git versions (1.8 or before) I posted a recipe here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57517262/468252

Comment: Issue popped up suddenly using "git version 2.43.0.windows.1" as a VSCode plugin. Setting core.sshCommand (first to "ssh -vv" and then to plain "ssh") seemed to fix it.