# git push with ssh remote fails unless verbose

Tags: git, ssh

I have a `git` (version `2.1.2`) repository with an `ssh` remote:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  ssh://dettorer@dettorer.net:/home/dettorer/my_project (fetch)
origin  ssh://dettorer@dettorer.net:/home/dettorer/my_project (push)
```

Which fails to push:

```
$ git push
Bad port ''
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Unless… I use the `--verbose` switch:

```
$ git push --verbose
Pushing to ssh://dettorer@dettorer.net:/home/dettorer/my_project
Enter passphrase for key '/home/dettorer/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Counting objects: 7, done.
...
To ssh://dettorer@dettorer.net:/home/dettorer/my_project
   e633fe9..5d2e9de  master -> master
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master'
```

I augmented the `ssh` log level as hinted [in that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25390120/1112326), but the output for `git push` (without `--verbose`) was the exact same.

Where could it come from?

As nwinkler suggested, here is the output of the two commands with `GIT_TRACE=2`:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=2 git push
13:42:33.002392 git.c:349               trace: built-in: git 'push'
13:42:33.033594 run-command.c:341       trace: run_command: 'ssh' '-p' '' 'dettorer@dettorer.net' 'git-receive-pack '\''/home/dettorer/my_project'\'''
Bad port ''
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights

$ GIT_TRACE=2 git push -v
13:42:39.929236 git.c:349               trace: built-in: git 'push' '-v'
Pushing to ssh://dettorer@dettorer.net:/home/dettorer/my_project
13:42:39.944837 run-command.c:341       trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'dettorer@dettorer.net' 'git-receive-pack '\''/home/dettorer/my_project'\'''
Enter passphrase for key '/home/dettorer/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

So unless I use `--verbose`, there indeed is an extra `'-p'` option with an empty argument.

EDIT: this is getting more obscure:

```
$ git push origin
Bad port ''
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

$ git remote add test test
$ git push origin
Enter passphrase for key '/home/dettorer/.ssh/id_rsa': 

$ git remote remove test
$ git push origin
Bad port ''
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Do you have anything in your `.ssh/config` file? What happens if you run `ssh -vvv dettorer@dettorer.net`?

Comment: @nwinkler, nothing in my `.ssh/config` (apart from when I augmented the ssh's log level). Nothing wrong happens when using `ssh -vvv` (and I can ssh correctly even without `-vvv`).

Comment: Also, what's the output of running `GIT_TRACE=2 git push`? It should print the exact `ssh` command that's being run.

Comment: The _Bad Port ''_ message looks like there's an extra `-p ''` argument to the _ssh_ command somewhere, trying to set the port for ssh.

Comment: Indeed there is, I'm editing my question to show the output.

Comment: This is getting darker, adding a random remote (even invalid) fixes it (I edited to show this). I'll test with the last `git` version

Comment: Check whether you have anything suspicious in your environment variables, aliases, or Git configuration.

Comment: This now fixed with Git 2.3.7 (April 2015). See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29912423/6309)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, after seeing your comments, I'm pretty sure I know what's wrong.

Can you try to change your remote URL to this:

`ssh://dettorer@dettorer.net/home/dettorer/my_project`

You've got an extra colon there, which seems to be causing the issue of the additional port. I don't know why running it with `-v` fixes the problem.

The git help shows that the following is the supported format for the `ssh` protocol:

`ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/`

As you can see, the colon is only required if you need to set a port. Leave it off if you want to use the standard port.

Comment: That's what I was beginning to think, I'll see if I can reproduce with a dummy repository and the last git version and possibly file a bug report (for the different behavior induced by `--verbose`). It works without the extra '`:`', thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! +1 on the bug report, if this turns out to be an issue in Git.

Comment: Come to think of it - it would be great if Git was smart enough to notify you of the mistake. It shouldn't try to add a `-p` argument to ssh when you didn't define a port. A message or hint of some kind would have been nice.

Comment: It even works fine `-v` and ignore the empty port. It may be that a different url parser is used when in verbose mode.

Answer (score 2):

Note: with Git 2.3.7 (released yesterday, April, 27 2015), this error "`Bad port ''`" is no more.

See [commit ad34ad6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad34ad614da30387c82a54c7087705050b4de441), from [commit 6b6c5f7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6b6c5f7a2f66751a93afce54277a1f30ab0dc521) (by [Torsten Bögershausen `tboegi`](https://github.com/tboegi))

> ### `connect.c`: ignore extra colon after hostname
>
> Ignore an extra '`:`' at the end of the hostname in URL's like
>   "`ssh://example.com:/path/to/repo`"
>
> The colon is meant to separate a port number from the hostname.
>   If the port is empty, the colon should be ignored, see RFC 3986.
>
> It had been working for URLs with `ssh://` scheme, but was unintentionally
>   broken in [86ceb3, "allow `ssh://user@[2001:db8::1]/repo.git`"](https://github.com/git/git/commit/86ceb337ec340c7db9b060b90bfab05a08b8251b) (Git 2.3.4).