# Git pull and git fetch does not work on windows 10

Tags: git, windows-10

I updated my windows a few days ago and since then git has not worked right. When I run the command "git pull" or "git fetch", most of the time they do not work, simply nothing happens.

Nothing happens when i run the command.
[image: Nothing happens when i run the command.]

Following the suggestion of KurzedMetal:

I ran the command, but stopped at this point and nothing happened

[image]

Comment: maybe it's some kind of bug / incompatibility of Cygwin with Windows 10? slow servers?, too broad.

Comment: some suggestion how i can fix that incompatibility / bug?

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25390120/236871) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6178401/236871) and add the verbose/debug info to your question.

Comment: my colleague is with the same version of git in your PC and also windows 10 and the error does not occur.

Comment: Recommend closing as off-topic. Try the question on SuperUser.com...

Comment: Bad idea to upgrade. Why'd you do that?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 and Msys Git 1.9.5 with zero problems. I am not using the Bash for Git for Windows monstrosity however. I'm working with Git directly from the Windows Command Line. If Git is on your %PATH%, I recommend trying that.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if I `pull` via *Visual Studio*, it can download the data normally. (I do not know exactly what the command that Visual Studio runs, only that this has worked for me.)

However, when I `pull` from the command line, sometimes it just doesn't return. So try using *git* from *Visual Studio* as a work-around.