# git push command is never terminating

Tags: git

I have a simple, but very uncomfortable problem: `git push` doesn't work anymore for me!

When I do `git remote -v`, I get:

```
origin  git@myserver.net:myproject (fetch)
origin  git@myserver.net:myproject (push)
```

I also tried to `ping myserver.net` and it successfully send/receive data.

However, when I do `git push -v`, it just prints `Pushing to git@myserver.net:myproject` and then, literally nothing happens.
I tried to wait 20 minutes and finally killed it.

Does anyone have an idea to solve the problem or at least to get more informations about it?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried using sudo?

Comment: set GIT_TRACE=2 before your git push. Check the ssh log (http://stackoverflow.com/a/25390120/6309)

Comment: @NovalAgungPrayogo : I can't use sudo because I don't have admin rights on the server

Comment: As @VonC mentioned, this sounds like an SSH problem more than a Git problem.

Comment: You're right, definitely looks like an SSH problem because when I'm trying to `ssh git@myserver.net`, it returns me `PTY allocation request failed on channel 0`

Comment: For à simple ssh test, try ssh -Tvv git@myserver.net

Comment: This ends with
`Transferred: sent 3120, received 3264 bytes, in 1.3 seconds`

`Bytes per second: sent 2405.9, received 2516.9`    
`debug1: Exit status 2`
So it seems that the connection is working.
However, when I do `ssh -vv git@myserver.net git-receive-pack myproject`, it's hanging on `exec request accepted on channel 0`

Comment: is there any proxy on your network connection?

Comment: No. I tried multiple things this morning but can't solve the problem :(