# AWS Codecommit and GIT openSSH connection

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ssh, aws-codecommit

I'm trying to use AWS CodeCommit on Windows 10 with GIT and openSSH. I can successfully connect with Putty but I don't want to use it. 
I created a key in ~/.ssh/id_rsa and uploaded it to AWS Console.
So if I try to connect with ssh in GitBash than it works.

```
$ ssh git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
You have successfully authenticated over SSH. 
You can use Git to interact with AWS CodeCommit. 
Interactive shells are not supported.
Connection to git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com closed by remote host.
Connection to git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com closed.
```

But if I  try to pull it doesn't work.

```
$ git pull
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I checked my SSH Key ID, it's correct.

```
$ git remote -v
origin  ssh:/***********@git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/myrepo (fetch)
origin  ssh:/***********@git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/myrepo (push)
```

SSH connection seams also to work with my SSH Key ID:

```
$ ssh ***********@git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

I successfully configured it on another Windows PC for a week.

Does anybody have the same issue? Any Idea what can be wrong?

Comment: At least from the output in the git pull is provided and that your ssh keys are valid, it seems like for that particular git repository you dont have access

Comment: I always get Permission denied even my ssh keys are invalid.

Comment: The other Windows PC you have configured it on is using another IAM user. One that has the correct CodeCommit policy attached. Try comparing the two IAM users. (and post a hint here, I have the exact same problem :-)

Comment: It is the same user. It just a office PC and a home PC.

Comment: If you're using git 2.3.0+, you can use the following command to get verbose output for the SSH connection. Look for "Offering RSA public key" to see what keys the SSH client is using: GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git pull

Comment: It doesn't help. I don't see anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Clare Liguori for a tip. 
It didn't work with GIT_SSH_COMMAND but you can use this for verbose 
[How can I run git push/pull commands with SSH verbose mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388499/how-can-i-run-git-push-pull-commands-with-ssh-verbose-mode)

So I found out that my SSH KEY ID for master branch was still wrong. 
I only run `git remote set-url original ...` but i didn't change my master branch.