# Which public ssh key was used to connect to git

Tags: git

I have generated several ssh keys and have placed in git server. Is it possible somehow to know which ssh key was used while executing `git clone` command?

Comment: Per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388499/how-can-i-run-git-push-pull-commands-with-ssh-verbose-mode/36038548#36038548 you can doc `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git clone example`

Answer (score 0):

You can see your `currently active ssh-key` by `ssh-add` command.

```
$ ssh-add             # show active ssh-key file path
```

You can customize it also. Open `~/.ssh/config` file and find `Host <hostname>`, then the `IdentifyFile`  points the `id_rsa` file that git clone is using for that `<hostname>`.

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config

// sample output
Host bitbucket.org
User git
Hostname bitbucket.org
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Here, As `git clone git@bitbucket.org:<user>/<repo>.git` is using `bitbucket.org` Host and user `git`, so `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file is using as ssh-key and you need to save `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` in BitBucket account.

---

Now, if you add another ssh-key in ~/.ssh/config file like -

```
Host bitbucket-alice
User git
Hostname bitbucket.org
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentitiesOnly yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/alice
```

You need to clone with `git clone git@bitbucket-alice:<user>/<repo>.git` and it will use `~/.ssh/alice` and you need to add `~/.ssh/alice.pub` in your BitBucket account.

Comment: Well, that would say which would be used now, not which one was used when doing the clone. ;-)

Comment: @Vampire I've updated my answer showing which `ssh-key` is using when cloning a repo.

Comment: But it has nothing to do with the question. He already cloned and want to know which key was used. You just tell him how to lookup which would be used if he would do a fresh clone now.

Comment: Simply he can check `git clone url` that has used and `~/.ssh/config` file, then it is clear which ssh-key was used.

Comment: Only if ssh config didn't change and other config also didn't change anything in that selection, like some auth agent being active and so on.

Comment: ok. In that case, `ssh-add` will show currently active ssh-key. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Exactly, the **currently** active key, not the key with which the repo was cloned, whenever it was.

Answer (score -1):

You can look into the authentication log file of your Git server. In the local Git clone you have no chance.