# Does Git have a debug or verbose option explaining what it is doing?

Tags: git, debugging, verbosity

Do some or all git commands have debug or verbose options which explain what they are attempting or what other sub-commands are being executed?

Comment: Did you consult man pages? I sometimes use `strace`, though :)

Comment: You could check this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388499/how-can-i-run-git-push-pull-commands-with-ssh-verbose-mode)

Comment: If a question suggested as a duplicate answers it well enough, do I delete my question, leave it if has an answer which has more related and useful info, or simply close it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question is already answered. Please have a look [How can I debug git/git-shell related problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178401/how-can-i-debug-git-git-shell-related-problems)

To answer your question and give a quick reference, yes, there are! The following environment variables that are present in git:

GIT_SSH, GIT_TRACE, GIT_FLUSH, GIT_TRACE_PACK_ACCESS, GIT_TRACE_PACKET, GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE, GIT_TRACE_SETUP, GIT_CURL_VERBOSE, GIT_REFLOG_ACTION, GIT_NAMESPACE, GIT_DIFF_OPTS, GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF, GIT_DIFF_PATH_COUNTER, GIT_DIFF_PATH_TOTAL, GIT_MERGE_VERBOSITY.

**Usage:**

**Method 1:**
Just prepending the environment variables before the command:
GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git *YourCommandHere*

**Method 2:**
set -i; GIT_TRACE=2 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=2 GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=2 GIT_TRACE_PACK_ACCESS=2 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=2 GIT_TRACE_PACKFILE=2 GIT_TRACE_SETUP=2 GIT_TRACE_SHALLOW=2 git *YourCommandHere* -v -v; set +i

Also, you can have a look [Git Environment Variables](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#Debugging).