# How can I run git commands on Windows with SSH verbose mode?

Tags: windows, git, ssh, openssh

This is the Windows version of [How can I run git push/pull commands with SSH verbose mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388499/how-can-i-run-git-push-pull-commands-with-ssh-verbose-mode)

There are times where you just need to debug git's usage of SSH.

OpenSSH has a `-v` flag for verbose output, but how do you get git to use it?

How can I run git commands on Windows with SSH verbose mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your PATH is correctly set:

- you don't need OpenSSH-Win64 (ssh is already included in Git)
- you don't need to specify the full path for SSH

You need:

```
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

Then

```
set GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -vvv
```

Comment: That's interesting.  I knew that ssh was in "Git Bash", but didn't realize that it could be used directly from the Windows context.  Is `Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe` another port of OpenSSH like OpenSSH-Win64?  And since these tools are clearly useful, I wonder why only `Git\cmd` is added to the path when Git For Windows is installed.

Comment: By default, you get only git. But I find the other 200 commands quite handy as well.

Answer (score 6):

You can force git to provide verbose ssh output with the "GIT_SSH_COMMAND" environment variable.

For example, to get verbose output from OpenSSH-For-Windows for a `git clone` command, just open a command prompt and enter

```
set GIT_SSH_COMMAND="C:\Program Files\OpenSSH-Win64\ssh.exe" -vvv
git clone <repo_ssh_url>
```

Note the location of the quotation marks.

Alternately, you can add

```
Host *
    LogLevel DEBUG3
```

to `%userprofile%\.ssh\config`. (Create it if it doesn't exist.)

Comment: This solved the problem of WHY I needed the verbose - because git, by default, had been using is own ssh, which used a different ssh-agent and ssh-add than the ones I had used to add the keys.  So as soon as I set GIT_SSH_COMMAND as above, it worked.