# How to enable verbose mode in git push to remote

Tags: git

my pushes to git lab are always taking too long around the 17% and I want to see what files are creating trouble! I think it might be the images, I awas wondering if git has a way to show what files are being pushed to gitlab remote in my commadn shell...

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388499/how-can-i-run-git-push-pull-commands-with-ssh-verbose-mode

Comment: [Per the documentation, you can include a `-v` flag to enable verbose mode](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).  So `git push -v origin <your_branch_name>`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is your answer or it will help you if you still have this problem. :))

`git ls-tree -r -t -l --full-name HEAD | sort -n -k 4 | tail -n 1000`