# Can't push to Git Repository only when accessing it from remote

Tags: git, ssh, remote-access

I ran into a very peculiar problem with Git. I have a repository on a Gitlab server and I usually work on it from my work computer in the office (which runs Ubuntu). On there, I have set up a private/public key and everything works just fine.

Now the weird part is, when I ssh into my work computer from home and execute a pull, or push, or any other Git command requiring connection to the Gitlab server, I get an error, saying that my public key is wrong.

```
$ git push
git@collaborating.tuhh.de: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

From my understanding, if I ssh into my work computer and execute a command in the shell, it should be exactly as if I am running that same command directly sitting in front of that computer, shouldn't it?

Does anyone have an idea, why this goes wrong? Any ideas welcome!

Comment: ***public key is wrong*** Isn't error message obvious? You should use the same public key/private key pair from your home computer to access the server.

Comment: No, I think we are misunderstanding. I am not trying to push from my home computer. I  am ssh-ing into my work computer and try to push from there, where I should have exactly the same key set-up, no matter if I am using it over ssh or directly, shouldn't I?

Comment: Is your company's Gitlab server hosted in a private network for which you would require a VPN connection?

Comment: Well, not a VPN, but to ssh into my work computer I need a ProxyJump, where I first ssh into a Login server within the company network and then from there I can ssh into my work computer.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36038548

Comment: Thanks, found out that it seems to not correctly read my ~/.ssh/config file when invoking git over ssh (although the log claims to do so). My keyfile has a non-standard name (not `id_rsa`), which is specified in the .ssh/config. Accordign to the ssh output, it only tries all the standard names for keyfiles (`id_dsa`, `id_rsa`,...). When I rename my keyfile to `id_rsa` it works. That would solve the issue, but still the question arises, why is it working differently over ssh than in presence?

Comment: In order to use a different key file with SSH, there is I think a `-i` option.

Comment: Yeah okay, that also works. Might be it has something to do with the way a bash shell is initialized, when ssh-ing into a computer versus when invoking it directly from the Ubuntu desktop?

Comment: Maybe you can find out what SSH does when you use it directly from your work computer.

Comment: Will do on Monday. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Ssh is, or can be, quite complicated and fancy.  If you're using an ssh agent, remember that the agent will provide the keys, except when it doesn't.<sup>1</sup>  If you're not using an agent, the ssh configuration will always provide the keys.

Use `ssh-add -l` to view the keys the agent can see.  Inspect your `~/.ssh/config` file to see what keys you are telling ssh to send.  Use `ssh -v`, or multiple `-v` options if desired (though one usually suffices), to observe which keys your ssh client is actually trying:

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

for instance shows my ssh client offering my personal GitHub-specific RSA key to github.com.

On Git-for-Windows (not the case here but let's include it for other viewers), after making sure that `ssh -Tv ...` works, make sure that Git is using the Windows-native ssh.  See [Flimm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36038548/1256452) to [How can I run git push/pull commands with SSH verbose mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25388499/1256452) as [kiner_shah mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70720358/cant-push-to-git-repository-only-when-accessing-it-from-remote/70722648#comment125021882_70720358).

---

<sup>1</sup>I realize this by itself is kind of unhelpful.  The problem here is that there can be many reasons for "it doesn't".  This is where the `-v` trick comes in handy.  Note that `IdentitiesOnly yes` in the config means that only identities listed *in* the config will be used, although `-i` options will add on anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In the case this is still an issue for anybody who comes across this, this is what worked for me: I added the following setting to my .gitconfig file using the `git config` command below:

```
git config --global core.sshcommand "ssh -i /path/to/your/private/key
```

As a result, your git config file should look contain something like this:

```
[core]
pager = cat
sshCommand = ssh -i /path/to/your/private/key
```

And running `git config --list --global` should include something like this:

```
core.sshcommand=ssh -i /path/to/your/private/key
```