GitHub: Can't push from behind corporate proxy: "remote: No anonymous write access."
First I'd like to say I've researched solutions to this problem and none of the suggested workarounds work, including

"fatal: Authentication failed for" when pushing to GitHub from Visual Studio Code (1.62.2)
Git authentication with GitHub fails, remote: No anonymous write access

Context: I want to access and push to a GitHub repo that I own, from an enterprise LAN that requires a HTTP proxy for all external access. I was able to checkout my repo (in HTTP mode) from IntelliJ, but I can't push anything, I always get this:
remote: No anonymous write access.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/...

What I have tried:

use IntelliJ feature "login to GitHub": authorization is successful but push fails
use a PAT (both classic and fine-grained) in response to IntelliJ prompt
change the remote git URL to include the authentication info (user and PAT)
push from a shell instead of through IntelliJ
push using GitHub desktop

Nothing seems to matter.
More context:

no git credential helper is configured
I can't use SSH because corporate blocks it.
I'm under Windows 10
the proxy is set correctly in IntelliJ (test to github.com works)
if I use any garbage string instead of the PAT I get exactly the same result

I'm beginning to think that the proxy blocks or somehow alters authentication, making it unusable...
Is there anything else I can try?
UPDATE 2024-04-24
I have activated git tracing so here's what happens:
$ git -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false push --progress --porcelain origin refs/heads/master:master
16:26:28.511830 exec-cmd.c:243          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Users/gerardin/scoop/apps/git/2.44.0/mingw64/bin
16:26:28.532825 git.c:463               trace: built-in: git push --progress --porcelain origin refs/heads/master:master
16:26:28.535825 run-command.c:657       trace: run_command: GIT_DIR=.git git remote-https origin https://github.com/ogerardin/project-guarana.git
16:26:28.559824 exec-cmd.c:243          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Users/gerardin/scoop/apps/git/2.44.0/mingw64/libexec/git-core
16:26:28.567824 git.c:750               trace: exec: git-remote-https origin https://github.com/ogerardin/project-guarana.git
16:26:28.567824 run-command.c:657       trace: run_command: git-remote-https origin https://github.com/ogerardin/project-guarana.git
16:26:28.592824 exec-cmd.c:243          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Users/gerardin/scoop/apps/git/2.44.0/mingw64/libexec/git-core
16:26:28.610824 http.c:868              == Info: Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
16:26:28.618823 http.c:868              == Info: Host proxy****************************:8080 was resolved.
16:26:28.618823 http.c:868              == Info: IPv6: (none)
16:26:28.618823 http.c:868              == Info: IPv4: 10.198.237.3
16:26:28.618823 http.c:868              == Info:   Trying 10.198.237.3:8080...
16:26:28.639822 http.c:868              == Info: Connected to proxy**************************** (10.198.237.3) port 8080
16:26:28.640822 http.c:868              == Info: CONNECT tunnel: HTTP/1.1 negotiated
16:26:28.640822 http.c:868              == Info: allocate connect buffer
16:26:28.640822 http.c:868              == Info: Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to github.com:443
16:26:28.640822 http.c:815              => Send header, 0000000121 bytes (0x00000079)
16:26:28.640822 http.c:827              => Send header: CONNECT github.com:443 HTTP/1.1
16:26:28.640822 http.c:827              => Send header: Host: github.com:443
16:26:28.640822 http.c:827              => Send header: User-Agent: git/2.44.0.windows.1
16:26:28.640822 http.c:827              => Send header: Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
16:26:28.640822 http.c:827              => Send header:
16:26:28.661823 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000037 bytes (0x00000025)
16:26:28.662823 http.c:827              <= Recv header: HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
16:26:28.662823 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000002 bytes (0x00000002)
16:26:28.662823 http.c:827              <= Recv header:
16:26:28.662823 http.c:868              == Info: CONNECT phase completed
16:26:28.662823 http.c:868              == Info: CONNECT tunnel established, response 200
16:26:28.663823 http.c:868              == Info: ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
16:26:28.664386 http.c:868              == Info: TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
16:26:28.898473 http.c:868              == Info:  CAfile: C:\Users\gerardin\ssl\output\cacert.pem
16:26:28.898473 http.c:868              == Info:  CApath: none
16:26:28.898473 http.c:868              == Info: TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
16:26:28.898473 http.c:868              == Info: TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
16:26:28.899382 http.c:868              == Info: TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
16:26:28.899382 http.c:868              == Info: TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
16:26:28.900383 http.c:868              == Info: TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
16:26:28.900383 http.c:868              == Info: TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
16:26:28.900383 http.c:868              == Info: TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
16:26:28.924590 http.c:868              == Info: TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
16:26:28.924590 http.c:868              == Info: SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 / secp256r1 / rsaEncryption
16:26:28.924590 http.c:868              == Info: ALPN: server did not agree on a protocol. Uses default.
16:26:28.924590 http.c:868              == Info: Server certificate:
16:26:28.924590 http.c:868              == Info:  subject: CN=github.com
16:26:28.924590 http.c:868              == Info:  start date: Mar  7 00:00:00 2024 GMT
16:26:28.924590 http.c:868              == Info:  expire date: Mar  7 23:59:59 2025 GMT
16:26:28.924590 http.c:868              == Info:  subjectAltName: host "github.com" matched cert's "github.com"
16:26:28.924590 http.c:868              == Info:  issuer: ************************************
16:26:28.924590 http.c:868              == Info:  SSL certificate verify ok.
16:26:28.924590 http.c:868              == Info:   Certificate level 0: Public key type RSA (2048/112 Bits/secBits), signed using sha256WithRSAEncryption
16:26:28.924590 http.c:868              == Info:   Certificate level 1: Public key type RSA (4096/152 Bits/secBits), signed using sha256WithRSAEncryption
16:26:28.924590 http.c:868              == Info: using HTTP/1.x
16:26:28.924590 http.c:815              => Send header, 0000000207 bytes (0x000000cf)
16:26:28.925592 http.c:827              => Send header: GET /ogerardin/project-guarana.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1
16:26:28.925592 http.c:827              => Send header: Host: github.com
16:26:28.925592 http.c:827              => Send header: User-Agent: git/2.44.0.windows.1
16:26:28.925592 http.c:827              => Send header: Accept: */*
16:26:28.925592 http.c:827              => Send header: Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, br, zstd
16:26:28.925592 http.c:827              => Send header: Pragma: no-cache
16:26:28.925592 http.c:827              => Send header:
16:26:29.084004 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000027 bytes (0x0000001b)
16:26:29.084593 http.c:827              <= Recv header: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
16:26:29.084593 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000026 bytes (0x0000001a)
16:26:29.084593 http.c:827              <= Recv header: Server: GitHub-Babel/3.0
16:26:29.084593 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000054 bytes (0x00000036)
16:26:29.084593 http.c:827              <= Recv header: Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; sandbox
16:26:29.084593 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000041 bytes (0x00000029)
16:26:29.085497 http.c:827              <= Recv header: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
16:26:29.085497 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000040 bytes (0x00000028)
16:26:29.085497 http.c:827              <= Recv header: www-authenticate: Basic realm="GitHub"
16:26:29.085497 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000020 bytes (0x00000014)
16:26:29.085497 http.c:827              <= Recv header: Content-Length: 26
16:26:29.085497 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000037 bytes (0x00000025)
16:26:29.085497 http.c:827              <= Recv header: Date: Wed, 24 Apr 2024 14:26:28 GMT
16:26:29.085497 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000023 bytes (0x00000017)
16:26:29.085497 http.c:827              <= Recv header: X-Frame-Options: DENY
16:26:29.085497 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000059 bytes (0x0000003b)
16:26:29.085497 http.c:827              <= Recv header: X-GitHub-Request-Id: E8B7:3AAD70:79142A0:7A63E19:66291694
16:26:29.085497 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000033 bytes (0x00000021)
16:26:29.085497 http.c:827              <= Recv header: Cache-Control: proxy-revalidate
16:26:29.085497 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000030 bytes (0x0000001e)
16:26:29.085497 http.c:827              <= Recv header: Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
16:26:29.085497 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000024 bytes (0x00000018)
16:26:29.085497 http.c:827              <= Recv header: Connection: keep-alive
16:26:29.085497 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000048 bytes (0x00000030)
16:26:29.085497 http.c:827              <= Recv header: Set-Cookie: BCSI-CS-ec5a8b0039345341=1; Path=/
16:26:29.085497 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000045 bytes (0x0000002d)
16:26:29.085497 http.c:827              <= Recv header: Proxy-support: Session-based-authentication
16:26:29.086482 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000002 bytes (0x00000002)
16:26:29.086482 http.c:827              <= Recv header:
16:26:29.086482 http.c:868              == Info: Connection #0 to host proxy**************************** left intact
16:26:29.086482 run-command.c:657       trace: run_command: bash -c 'cat >/dev/tty && read -r line </dev/tty && echo "$line"'
Username for 'https://github.com': ogerardin
16:26:31.829778 run-command.c:657       trace: run_command: bash -c 'cat >/dev/tty && read -r -s line </dev/tty && echo "$line" && echo >/dev/tty'
Password for 'https://ogerardin@github.com': 
16:26:35.053354 http.c:868              == Info: Found bundle for host: 0x1f77ebb7890 [serially]
16:26:35.053354 http.c:868              == Info: Can not multiplex, even if we wanted to
16:26:35.053354 http.c:868              == Info: Re-using existing connection with proxy proxy****************************
16:26:35.053354 http.c:868              == Info: Server auth using Basic with user 'ogerardin'
16:26:35.054358 http.c:815              => Send header, 0000000258 bytes (0x00000102)
16:26:35.054358 http.c:827              => Send header: GET /ogerardin/project-guarana.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1
16:26:35.054358 http.c:827              => Send header: Host: github.com
16:26:35.054358 http.c:827              => Send header: Authorization: Basic <redacted>
16:26:35.054358 http.c:827              => Send header: User-Agent: git/2.44.0.windows.1
16:26:35.054358 http.c:827              => Send header: Accept: */*
16:26:35.054358 http.c:827              => Send header: Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, br, zstd
16:26:35.054358 http.c:827              => Send header: Pragma: no-cache
16:26:35.054358 http.c:827              => Send header:
16:26:35.193444 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000027 bytes (0x0000001b)
16:26:35.193444 http.c:827              <= Recv header: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
16:26:35.193444 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000026 bytes (0x0000001a)
16:26:35.193444 http.c:827              <= Recv header: Server: GitHub-Babel/3.0
16:26:35.193444 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000054 bytes (0x00000036)
16:26:35.193444 http.c:827              <= Recv header: Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; sandbox
16:26:35.193444 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000041 bytes (0x00000029)
16:26:35.193444 http.c:827              <= Recv header: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
16:26:35.193444 http.c:868              == Info: Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
16:26:35.193444 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000040 bytes (0x00000028)
16:26:35.193444 http.c:827              <= Recv header: www-authenticate: Basic realm="GitHub"
16:26:35.194423 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000020 bytes (0x00000014)
16:26:35.194423 http.c:827              <= Recv header: Content-Length: 26
16:26:35.194423 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000037 bytes (0x00000025)
16:26:35.194423 http.c:827              <= Recv header: Date: Wed, 24 Apr 2024 14:26:35 GMT
16:26:35.194423 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000023 bytes (0x00000017)
16:26:35.194423 http.c:827              <= Recv header: X-Frame-Options: DENY
16:26:35.194423 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000059 bytes (0x0000003b)
16:26:35.194423 http.c:827              <= Recv header: X-GitHub-Request-Id: E8B7:3AAD70:79177DD:7A673E5:66291695
16:26:35.194423 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000033 bytes (0x00000021)
16:26:35.194423 http.c:827              <= Recv header: Cache-Control: proxy-revalidate
16:26:35.194423 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000030 bytes (0x0000001e)
16:26:35.194423 http.c:827              <= Recv header: Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
16:26:35.194423 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000024 bytes (0x00000018)
16:26:35.194423 http.c:827              <= Recv header: Connection: keep-alive
16:26:35.194423 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000048 bytes (0x00000030)
16:26:35.194423 http.c:827              <= Recv header: Set-Cookie: BCSI-CS-ec5a8b0039345341=1; Path=/
16:26:35.194423 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000045 bytes (0x0000002d)
16:26:35.194423 http.c:827              <= Recv header: Proxy-support: Session-based-authentication
16:26:35.194423 http.c:815              <= Recv header, 0000000002 bytes (0x00000002)
16:26:35.194423 http.c:827              <= Recv header:
16:26:35.194423 http.c:868              == Info: Connection #0 to host proxy**************************** left intact
remote: No anonymous write access.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/ogerardin/project-guarana.git/'
16:26:35.361915 exec-cmd.c:243          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Users/gerardin/scoop/apps/git/2.44.0/mingw64/bin
16:26:35.374911 git.c:463               trace: built-in: git config --bool core.sparseCheckout

It appears git is using basic authentication. I tried with my password, a PAT, or garbage, and the result is strictly the same.
BTW it's easy to reproduce with curl, with the same results:
$ curl -vvv -k --request GET --url "https://github.com/ogerardin/project-guarana.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack" --header "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" --user ogerardin 

If I try the same with a bearer authentication and my token, it also fails
$ curl -vvv -k --request GET --url "https://github.com/ogerardin/project-guarana.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack" --header "Accept: application/vnd.github+json"  --header "Authentication: bearer ***************************" 


Does debugging with this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25390120/11404396

@LokiRagnarok Not only OP is not using SSH, but he also said I can't use SSH because corporate blocks it

@dani-vta My bad, somehow I misread the linked answer specifically as unrelated to SSH.

@dani-vta indeed, SSH is out of the picture
