# Bitbucket garbage collection process slows down server performance

Tags: git, performance, garbage-collection, bitbucket

We use a Bitbucket server v5.7.
When pushing large git repositories (20GB) we sometimes see that git gc process is started automatically during the push and *extremely* slows down the server.

I understand git gc can be run manually, and usually prompts automatically when the repository reaches certain sizes/number of objects.

Is there any way we can control this automatic process to only start outside of office hours so it doesn't impact performance?
Or maybe we can cancel it altogether and schedule it to run manually at night?

EDIT: We want to control the git gc process prompted by the Atlassian Bitbucket server. This is because I believe git gc is orchestrated by Bitbucket to clean all its hosted git repositories. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks,
Yael

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Prevent Garbage Collection in GIT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28092485/how-to-prevent-garbage-collection-in-git)