# Is it possible to get `git gc` to pack reflog objects?

Tags: git, performance, garbage-collection

As hinted by answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32025729 I've configured remote bare repo with

```
git config gc.pruneExpire never
git config gc.reflogExpire never
```

and as a result, I always keep all stored commits of all branches and tags even if I do not create permanent branch names or tags for all those commits.

However, this will cause following warning to appear in long run:

```
warning: There are too many unreachable loose objects; run 'git prune' to remove them.
```

This is caused by the fact that the dangling commits that I want to keep forever are always stored as loose objects.

**Is there a nice way to get git to include dangling commits referenced only by reflog in pack files on purpose?** That would allow performance to keep high and not lose unnamed history.

I know that I can workaround the warning by setting `gc.auto` to some really high number but that will cause (minor?) performance problem in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is supposed to pack reflog-only-reachable objects. So what you
describe is not supposed to happen.

What could be happening is that you haven’t enabled the reflog in the
bare repository (it is by default not enabled). [1] To enable the
reflog in a repository:

```
git config core.logAllRefUpdates always
```

---

OP [asked](https://lore.kernel.org/git/39a0796a-7220-1e81-e7fe-3bf7329ed7de@peda.net/#t) about this on the Git mailing list. Jeff King
[respondend](https://lore.kernel.org/git/20190319064711.GD31801@sigill.intra.peff.net/).

> That's not what's supposed to happen. A normal git-gc (or directly
> running the "git repack" it spawns) should consider objects in reflogs
> reachable, and pack them as it would an object reachable from a ref.
> This has been the case since [63049292e0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/63049292e083faf80e033eba4fa43efdbac3acad) (Teach git-repack to preserve
> objects referred to by reflog entries., 2006-12-18).
>
> Just to double check: are you sure you have reflogs? They're not enabled
> by default in bare repos.

#### Notes

1. There’s also *cruft packs*, a pack type for unreachable objects. But
   that didn’t exist in 2019.

Comment: I'm marking this as accepted answer. I did run `git gc` on that server once and I haven't seen the problem since during the last 4 years and thousands of commits. I guess it was some old data because that same repo has been on the server since 2010 and maybe some older Git version had created some leftover data that triggered the warning.