# Git Extensions cpu usage on big repo

Tags: git, cpu-usage, git-extensions

Git Extensions takes ~42% of CPU, !PERMANENTLY!, when I open specific repositories (pretty big projects... but I would not say huge. I mean we have ~20000 commits on the repos I'm talking about)

Opening smaller repos is not a problem, CPU is loaded and then drops down.

Can I do something to avoid this? (+ it's only on my computer... my colleagues don't have this issue opening the same repo)

- Windows 10
- GIT 2.28
- Git Extensions 3.4.3.9999

Comment: btw, changing the 'Limit number of commits that will be loaded at startup' from 100000 to smaller amount (tested 5000), doesn't change anything.

Comment: Can you try, just for testing, https://stackoverflow.com/a/28092576/6309: `cd /path/to/repo; git config gc.auto 0`

Comment: Hi! Just tried it, it didn't change anything :-(, but thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same. What helped for me was turning off the 'Build server integration'. As soon as I turned that off, the CPU usage dropped to a normal level.