# making changes and committing them in in the detached head state

Tags: git, git-checkout

I used `git checkout <commit_SHA>` to visit an earlier commit in the git tree. Git showed me the following message:

```
You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.
```

Does this mean that any change that I make here (even by committing them) will not be kept when I return to the most recent commit (using `git checkout master`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git finds commits by their hash IDs.  The hash IDs are those big ugly strings of letters and digits, such as [`e1cfff676549cdcd702cbac105468723ef2722f4`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e1cfff676549cdcd702cbac105468723ef2722f4).  These *look* random, but aren't.

If you *write down* the hash IDs of each of your commits, you can get them back, for a while at least.  But what if you make a mistake or typo while copying down these hash IDs?  It would be better to have the *computer* save them.

That's what a *branch name* does.  In fact, though, it only saves *one* hash ID.  So that's all you'd really need to write down.  Every time you make a new commit in "detached HEAD" state, you would have to write down the hash ID of the *new* commit you just made.  You could erase the hash ID of any previous commit (though you don't have to).

Here's how it all works.  Every commit saves *two* things:

- Each commit stores a full snapshot of every file (that Git knows about at the time you, or whoever, make the commit).  These files are stored in a special, compressed, read-only, Git-only format, with the files being de-duplicated, so that if a new commit re-uses most of the files from an old commit, they don't actually take any space.
- And, each commit stores some *metadata:* information such as your name and email address, and some date-and-time-stamps.  In this metadata, Git stores the hash ID of the *previous* commit, that comes just before the new commit you just made.

So, if we have a chain of commits, all in a row, we can draw them like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` stands in for the actual hash ID of the *last* of these commits.  Git can yank commit `H` back out of its big database-of-all-commits,<sup>1</sup> using the hash ID.  That gets Git the saved snapshot, plus the metadata.  The metadata stores the raw hash ID of earlier commit `G`.

Git can use this to yank commit `G` back out of its database, which gets a different saved snapshot, and the metadata for `G` ... which includes the hash ID of earlier commit `F`.  So now Git can grab `F`, which has a snapshot and metadata.  This goes on and on: Git works *backwards*, from the *last* commit to the first.

But you, or someone or something anyway, has to get Git this *last* hash ID.  That's where a branch name is useful: a branch name, by definition, stores the *last* hash ID in the chain.  If you:

```
git checkout somebranch
```

(or use `git switch` to do the same) you get something that we might draw like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
```

The special name `HEAD` remembers *which name* you told Git to use.  The *name* holds hash ID `H`.  If you make a new commit now, Git will write out a new commit, which gets a new random-looking (but unique and not actually random at all) hash ID, which we'll call `I`.  Git then writes `I`'s hash ID into the name `somebranch`:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
```

So that's how Git remembers which commit is the *last one*.  It's in the branch name!

---

<sup>1</sup>This big database actually holds all of Git's internal objects.  Commits are just one of four types of objects.  A Git repository is basically two databases: this big one, and a smaller—well, usually smaller—one that maps names, like branch names, to hash IDs.  The smaller database lets you find the hash IDs, and the big database holds the commits.

---

#### Detached HEAD mode

In *detached HEAD* mode, you tell Git: *Don't store a **name** in the special name `HEAD`, store a raw hash ID instead.*  For instance, let's say you decide to look at historic commit `G`:

```
...--F--G   <-- HEAD
         \
          H--I   <-- somebranch
```

You can now look around at the files that came out of commit `G`.  If you make a *new* commit now, Git stores the new commit as usual: it gets some big ugly hash ID, unique to it, but we'll call it `J`:

```
          J   <-- HEAD
         /
...--F--G
         \
          H--I   <-- somebranch
```

Now suppose you `git checkout somebranch` again, to get back to this:

```
          J   ???
         /
...--F--G
         \
          H--I   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
```

The *name* `HEAD` now holds the *name* `somebranch`, rather than the actual hash ID of commit `J`.  How will you find commit `J`?

#### Reflogs

If you wrote the hash ID down, that's one way to find it.  Git will hang on to commit `J` for at least 30 days by default, and you can look up the hash ID and type it in again.  That's ... painful, at best.

Git also *saves the hash ID for you* in what Git calls a *reflog*.  The reflogs are also kind of painful to use.  Run `git reflog` any time, and Git will show you what's in the `HEAD` reflog.  The hash IDs are the true names of each commit that `HEAD` pointed to,<sup>2</sup> whether directly (detached HEAD) or indirectly (through a branch name), in the last 30 or more days.  But typically there are hundreds of these, and *finding* a useful one in the [maze of twisty little hash IDs, all alike](https://www.science20.com/staring_empty_pages/youre_maze_twisty_little_passages_all_alike-77025) is no fun.

---

<sup>2</sup>These are abbreviated for display.  They also have numbered names, such as `HEAD@{3}` or `HEAD@{14}`.  The number *increments* every time Git adds a reflog entry, while the hash ID—abbreviated or full—stays the same, always.

---

#### So what *should* you do?

If you don't care about finding your commits again later, just keep working in detached-HEAD mode.  If you *do* care about finding them later, create a new branch name.  Branch names are super-cheap: they just hold one of those big ugly hash IDs.

Use `git branch newname` to create the new branch name `newname` wherever you are right now.  Then use `git checkout` or `git switch` to switch to it, so that `HEAD` is attached to *that* name.  Or, combine these two steps: `git checkout -b newname` or `git switch -c newname` means *create the name, then check it out / switch to it*, all at once.

Comment: thank you, it was a great and comprehensive answer. I just have a follow-up question. What if a commit is created when we merge two or more branches. Then the branch_name and HEAD would point to the SHA of the new commit, but does this most recent commit points to both its parents or just one of them?

Comment: @amiref: yes (both): If it's an actual merge commit (as made by `git merge`, but note that `git merge --squash` *doesn't* make a merge commit), then it has two or more parents: that's the definition of a merge commit. The first parent is the usual parent of any commit, and the second is the other commit that participated in the merging action.

Answer (score 3):

The changes in a `detached HEAD` state will be kept until the Git garbage collection (GC) deletes it.

The documentation on [Detached HEAD](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout/en#_detached_head) is pretty good:

> It is important to realize that at this point **nothing refers to commit** f. **Eventually commit** f (and by extension commit e) **will be deleted by the routine Git garbage collection process, unless we create a reference before that happens.**

That means, you can either `checkout` / `switch` to another referenced branch. (e.g. `git switch main`) or you create a new branch to keep the current detached worktree with `git switch -c newbranch` or `git checkout -b newbranchname`.

When you create a new branch, the worktree is out of the `detached HEAD` state and has a reference on it. (the new branch name)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28092576) describes how you can disable the automatic garbage collection, if you want to.

Comment: how it is possible to create a reference to f?

Comment: @amiref I wrote that in my answer: Git holds a reference if you create a branch on that specific commit.