# What does git fetch really do?

Tags: git, merge, fetch

Now I want to merge a remote branch, naming it `origin/branch1`, with my local branch `branch1`, as my partner pushed a new commit to branch1 on remote after our last merge, and I haven't committed since his last commit and want to get update from this commit. I used the following commands:

```
$ git fetch origin branch1
Compressing...
*branch branch1 ->FETCH_HEAD
$ git merge origin/branch1
Already up-to-date
```

That was not what I intended. What was in my mind before doing this was using fetch to get what my partner added and made the remote branch `origin/branch1` being updated. However, the "Already up-to-date" means I failed to get the updates in my local branch1. Then I checked the sha1 value of `origin/branch1` by

```
$ git ls-remote origin
```

and found that it kept the stale value of old commit after we merged last time. It tells that the `git fetch origin branch1` cannot update `origin/branch1`. I did another experiment, where my partner created another branch named "branch2" in his side and pushed a commit in branch2 to the remote origin. Then I still used

```
$ git fetch origin branch2
Compressing...
$ git merge origin/branch2
No branch named "origin/branch2"
```

The "Compressing" told me that the first command downloaded something in branch2 in origin successfully, however, the second command told me that there was no branch named origin/branch2! Thus I concluded that neither could `git fetch origin branchname` update `origin/branchname` locally, nor could it create a remote branch if it doesn't exist.

After I replace `git fetch origin branch#` with `git fetch origin`, all the `git merge`s worked as I expected.

However, I often see the combination of

```
$ git fetch remote branch-name
$ git merge remote/branch-name
```

So my question is what is the difference between `git fetch remote` and `git fetch remote branch-name`? And in what conditions could I succeed in letting it work as my wish by this combination?

Comment: this is all covered in `git help fetch`, did you have a specific question that isn't addressed by the documentation?

Comment: @AndrewC I've read the `git help fetch`, especially the part referring to `git fetch [<repository> [<refspec>...]]`, word by word. However, limited by my knowledge to git, I don't think for now it could explain the scenario I described above. Could you kindly tell exactly which part of the `help` can help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `git fetch remote branch` fetches branch to FETCH_HEAD.  You normally want `git fetch remote branch:branch` which would fetch it to a local branch of the same name.  When you don't specify it at all it is falling back to your config which presumably specifies that (look for a line with fetch in it in .git/config).

Comment: @AndrewC Thanks, Andrew. I know that. But what I am wondering is if `git fetch origin branch1` would update the remote counterpart locally, which is `origin/branch1`. I thought it would, but it didn't at my side. I have to use `git fetch origin` all the time to update all remote branches when I want to update only one dedicated remote branch.

Comment: You need to post the section of your config for the remote, specifically the fetch specifiers.

Comment: @AndrewC My config for fetch is: `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`. Thanks to your tips and the help of `git fetch`, I understand the usage of `git fetch remote branch:branch`. But I still don't understand the meaning of the behavior of "falling back" when I don't specify a local branch.

Comment: What's your git version?

Comment: @AndrewC git version 1.7.10.4

Comment: I think the behavior changed to address that so 'git fetch origin branch' works to update origin/branch in addition to FETCH_HEAD.   I'd upgrade to a newer version

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewC. I will have a try of the newest version.

Answer (score 7):

If you need to know what exactly `git fetch` is doing or any other `git` command, just prefix it with `GIT_TRACE=1`, so it'll give you trace output with any other commands which are invoked, e.g.

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git fetch origin master
03:08:15.704945 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'fetch' 'origin' 'master'
03:08:15.706183 run-command.c:347       trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'git@github.com' 'git-upload-pack '\''FOO/BAR.git'\'''
03:08:16.006394 run-command.c:347       trace: run_command: 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all' '--quiet'
03:08:16.013096 run-command.c:347       trace: run_command: 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
03:08:16.013625 exec_cmd.c:129          trace: exec: 'git' 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
03:08:16.016617 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
From github.com:FOO/BAR
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
03:08:16.153070 run-command.c:347       trace: run_command: 'gc' '--auto'
03:08:16.153748 exec_cmd.c:129          trace: exec: 'git' 'gc' '--auto'
03:08:16.157704 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'gc' '--auto'
```

which basically is doing ssh to the remote host, running `git-upload-pack` which send objects packed back to `git-fetch-pack` which receives missing objects from another repository.

In `man git-upload-pack` we can read:

> Invoked by `git fetch-pack`, learns what objects the other side is missing, and sends them after packing.

And in `man git-fetch-pack` we can read:

> Invokes `git-upload-pack` on a possibly remote repository and asks it to send objects missing from this repository, to update the named heads. The list of commits available locally is found out by scanning the local refs/ hierarchy and sent to `git-upload-pack` running on the other end.

---

To answer the question, the difference between `git fetch remote` and `git fetch remote branch-name`, is that when you don't specify `<refspec>` parameter (such as branch), it fetches all branches and/or tags (refs, see: `git ls-refs`) from one or more other repositories along with the objects necessary to complete their histories. By default only tags which are reachable by the objects that are fetched are downloaded (e.g. you end up only with tags that point at branches that you are interested in).

And when you run with explicit branches and/or tags, git first determines what needs to be fetched, then getting only the relevant refs (branches or tags). E.g. `git fetch origin master` will fetch only the master branch.

Answer (score -1):

> running [git-upload-pack](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-upload-pack) which send objects packed back to [`git-fetch-pack`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch-pack) which receives missing objects from another repository.

You can see more about `git fetch-pack` with Git 2.19 (Q3 2018), since "`git fetch-pack --all`" used to unnecessarily fail upon seeing an annotated tag that points at an object other than a commit.

See [commit c12c9df](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c12c9df5275add49b7b47cad82879a84c6bea469) (13 Jun 2018) by [Kirill Smelkov (`navytux`)](https://github.com/navytux).
Helped-by: [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit e9502c0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e9502c0a7fdb5649e3a3aece4e0d54ddb22983df) (11 Jun 2018) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
Helped-by: [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0079732](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0079732e960dc20ab2a68043d5593de358f1377f), 28 Jun 2018)</sup>

> `Fetch-pack --all` became broken with respect to unusual tags in
> [5f0fc64](http://c) (`fetch-pack`: eliminate spurious error messages, 2012-09-09, Git v1.8.0),
> and was fixed only recently in [e9502c0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e9502c0a7fdb5649e3a3aece4e0d54ddb22983df) (fetch-pack: don't try to fetch
> peel values with `--all`, 2018-06-11).

> ### `fetch-pack`: don't try to fetch peel values with `--all`

> When "`fetch-pack --all`" sees a **tag-to-blob** on the remote, it tries to fetch both the tag itself ("refs/tags/foo") and the peeled value that the remote advertises ("`refs/tags/foo^{}`").
> Asking for the object pointed to by the latter can cause upload-pack to complain with "not our ref", since it does not mark the peeled objects with the OUR_REF (unless they
> were at the tip of some other ref).
>
> Arguably `upload-pack` *should* be marking those peeled objects. But it never has in the past, since clients would generally just ask for the tag and expect to get the peeled
> value along with it.
> And that's how "`git fetch`" works, as well as older versions of "`fetch-pack --all`".
>
> [Let's explicitly test all relevant cases with 4 tag objects](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c12c9df5275add49b7b47cad82879a84c6bea469/t/t5500-fetch-pack.sh#L531-L559) pointing to
>
> - 1. a blob,
> - 2. a tree,
> - 3. a commit, and
> - 4. another tag objects.
>
> The referenced tag objects themselves are referenced from under regular `refs/tags/*`
> namespace.
>
> Before e9502c0 (Git 2.19) `fetch-pack --all` was failing e.g. this way:
>
> ```
>    .../git/t/trash directory.t5500-fetch-pack/fetchall$ git ls-remote ..
>    44085874...        HEAD
>    ...
>    bc4e9e1f...        refs/tags/tag-to-blob
>    038f48ad...        refs/tags/tag-to-blob^{}    # peeled
>    520db1f5...        refs/tags/tag-to-tree
>    7395c100...        refs/tags/tag-to-tree^{}    # peeled
>
>    .../git/t/trash directory.t5500-fetch-pack/fetchall$ git fetch-pack --all ..
>    fatal: A git upload-pack: not our ref 038f48ad...
>    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
> ```

---

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), fetch-pack includes **[trace2 annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094711/6309)**.

See [commit 9e5afdf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e5afdf99703f0bc851b8f7fb2fe5d9817cc6f39) (19 Nov 2019) by [Erik Chen (`erikchen`)](https://github.com/erikchen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 76c6824](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76c68246c6b9752fd692f84b928cf867befd57cc), 05 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e5afdf99703f0bc851b8f7fb2fe5d9817cc6f39): add `trace2` instrumentation
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Erik Chen</sup>

> Add `trace2` regions to [`fetch-pack.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9e5afdf99703f0bc851b8f7fb2fe5d9817cc6f39/fetch-pack.c) to **better track time spent in the various phases of a fetch**:
>
> - parsing remote refs and finding a cutoff
> - marking local refs as complete
> - marking complete remote refs as common
>
> All stages could potentially be slow for repositories with many refs.

---

Example: (you can then follow what a `git fetch` does)

```
D:\git\git>set GIT_TRACE2_EVENT=1

D:\git\git>git fetch
23:58:43.225088 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: D:/newenv/prgs/gits/PortableGit-2.24.0.2-64-bit.7z/mingw64/bin

{"event":"version","sid":"20200111T225843.226090Z-H91a50d96-P00007560","thread":"main","time":"2020-01-11T22:58:43.234089Z","file":"common-main.c","line":48,"evt":"2","exe":"2.24.0.windows.2"}
{"event":"start","sid":"20200111T225843.226090Z-H91a50d96-P00007560","thread":"main","time":"2020-01-11T22:58:43.234089Z","file":"common-main.c","line":49,"t_abs":0.011593,"argv":["git.exe","fetch"]}
{"event":"data_json","sid":"20200111T225843.226090Z-H91a50d96-P00007560","thread":"main","time":"2020-01-11T22:58:43.260090Z","file":"compat/win32/trace2_win32_process_info.c","line":118,"repo":0,"t_abs":0.037686,"t_rel":0.037686,"nesting":1,"category":"process","key":"windows/ancestry","value":["git.exe","cmd.exe","explorer.exe"]}
{"event":"def_repo","sid":"20200111T225843.226090Z-H91a50d96-P00007560","thread":"main","time":"2020-01-11T22:58:43.261089Z","file":"repository.c","line":130,"repo":1,"worktree":"D:/git/git"}

23:58:43.262092 git.c:439               trace: built-in: git fetch
{"event":"cmd_name","sid":"20200111T225843.226090Z-H91a50d96-P00007560","thread":"main","time":"2020-01-11T22:58:43.262092Z","file":"git.c","line":440,"name":"fetch","hierarchy":"fetch"}
{"event":"region_enter","sid":"20200111T225843.226090Z-H91a50d96-P00007560","thread":"main","time":"2020-01-11T22:58:43.281090Z","file":"builtin/fetch.c","line":1361,"repo":1,"nesting":1,"category":"fetch","label":"remote_refs"}
{"event":"child_start","sid":"20200111T225843.226090Z-H91a50d96-P00007560","thread":"main","time":"2020-01-11T22:58:43.284088Z","file":"run-command.c","line":735,"child_id":0,"child_class":"remote-https","use_shell":false,"argv":["git","remote-https","origin","https://github.com/git/git"]}
23:58:43.284088 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: GIT_DIR=.git git remote-https origin https://github.com/git/git
```

---

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), the `ls-refs` protocol operation (used also by `git fetch`) has been optimized to narrow the sub-hierarchy of `refs/` it walks to produce response.

It furhter illustrates what a `git fetch` does.

See [commit b3970c7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3970c702cb0acc0551d88a5f34ad4ad2e2a6d39), [commit 16b1985](https://github.com/git/git/commit/16b1985be553b5fc6273eb9d7277173623e2d7cb) (20 Jan 2021) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
See [commit 83befd3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/83befd37249726f6a94e55f5aad1113fd18102a0) (20 Jan 2021) by [Jacob Vosmaer (`jacobvosmaer`)](https://github.com/jacobvosmaer).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6254fa1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6254fa13596cee0ea645317ba3eb4552430f38b4), 05 Feb 2021)</sup>

> ### [`ls-refs.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3970c702cb0acc0551d88a5f34ad4ad2e2a6d39): traverse prefixes of disjoint "ref-prefix" sets
>
> <sup>Original-patch-by: Jacob Vosmaer</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> `ls-refs` performs a single revision walk over the whole `ref` namespace, and sends ones that match with one of the given ref prefixes down to the user.
>
> This can be expensive if there are many refs overall, but the portion of them covered by the given prefixes is small by comparison.
>
> To attempt to reduce the difference between the number of refs traversed, and the number of refs sent, only traverse references which are in the longest common prefix of the given prefixes.
> This is very reminiscent of the approach taken in [b31e268](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b31e2680c46c43ece716080040e90b3a787b0bad) ("[`ref-filter.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b31e2680c46c43ece716080040e90b3a787b0bad/ref-filter.c): find disjoint pattern prefixes", 2019-06-26, Git v2.23.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b4b8c35729985a8f1f5e22f82259a2499efbc37a) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c9b961d7eb15fb583a2a812088713a68a85f1c0)) which does an analogous thing for multi-patterned '[`git for-each-ref`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b3970c702cb0acc0551d88a5f34ad4ad2e2a6d39/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref))</sup> invocations.
>
> The callback '`send_ref`' is resilient to ignore extra patterns by discarding any arguments which do not begin with at least one of the specified prefixes.
>
> Similarly, the code introduced in [b31e268](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b31e2680c46c43ece716080040e90b3a787b0bad) is resilient to stop early at metacharacters, but we only pass strict prefixes here.
> At worst we would return too many results, but the double checking done by `send_ref` will throw away anything that doesn't start with something in the prefix list.
>
> Finally, if no prefixes were provided, then implicitly add the empty string (which will match all references) since this matches the existing behavior (see the "no restrictions" comment in "[`ls-refs.c:ref_match()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b3970c702cb0acc0551d88a5f34ad4ad2e2a6d39/ls-refs.c)").

---

With Git 2.38 (Q3 2022), the common ancestor negotiation exchange during a "[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/098b7bfaa6c415f2b23885b82d6b5a31a8cdb7d2/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> session now leaves **trace log**.

Again, that helps seeing what a `git fetch` does.

See [commit a29263c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a29263cf5f419fb3095d01bcf8e806d12dd7ec71) (02 Aug 2022) by [Josh Steadmon (`steadmon`)](https://github.com/steadmon).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 098b7bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/098b7bfaa6c415f2b23885b82d6b5a31a8cdb7d2), 25 Aug 2022)</sup>

> ### [`fetch-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a29263cf5f419fb3095d01bcf8e806d12dd7ec71): add tracing for negotiation rounds
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Josh Steadmon</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Jeff Hostetler</sup>

> Currently, negotiation for V0/V1/V2 fetch have `trace2` regions covering the entire negotiation process.
> However, we'd like additional data, such as timing for each round of negotiation or the number of "haves" in each round.
> Additionally, "independent negotiation" (AKA push negotiation) has no tracing at all.
> Having this data would allow us to compare the performance of the various negotation implementations, and to debug unexpectedly slow fetch & push sessions.
>
> - Add per-round `trace2` regions for all negotiation implementations (V0+V1, V2, and independent negotiation), as well as an overall region for independent negotiation.
> - Add trace2 data logging for the number of haves and "in vain" objects for each round, and for the total number of rounds once negotiation completes.

Example:

```bash
GIT_TRACE2_EVENT="$(pwd)/trace2" 
git -C myclient fetch --progress origin main 
...
"key":"total_rounds","value":"6"
...
```

---

Git 2.43 (Q4 2023), allows for traces2 to differentiate between fetches and initial clones:

See [commit b8f58c2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b8f58c200cd3493ccf3c1669aa3c34927c884018) (17 Oct 2023) by [Robert Coup (`rcoup`)](https://github.com/rcoup).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a362332](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a362332c56e4d9c6239a0f4b53982d1b4bfc0b4d), 07 Nov 2023)</sup>

> ### [`upload-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b8f58c200cd3493ccf3c1669aa3c34927c884018): add tracing for fetches
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Robert Coup</sup>

> Information on how users are accessing hosted repositories can be helpful to server operators.
> For example, being able to broadly differentiate between fetches and initial clones; the use of shallow repository features; or partial clone filters.
>
> [a29263c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a29263cf5f419fb3095d01bcf8e806d12dd7ec71) ("`fetch-pack`: add tracing for negotiation rounds", 2022-08-02, Git v2.38.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/098b7bfaa6c415f2b23885b82d6b5a31a8cdb7d2) listed in [batch #15](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c46ea0ded70c921aedf22ced1afeea2a2a9ed26)) added some information on have counts to fetch-pack itself to help diagnose negotiation; but from a `git-upload-pack` (server) perspective, there's no means of accessing such information without using `GIT_TRACE_PACKET` to examine the protocol packets.
>
> Improve this by emitting a Trace2 JSON event from `upload-pack` with summary information on the contents of a fetch request.
>
> - haves, wants, and want-ref counts can help determine (broadly) between fetches and clones, and the use of single-branch, etc.
> - shallow clone depth, tip counts, and deepening options.
> - any partial clone filter type.