# How to see Git's working log (not commit history, But Git's process)

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am trying to do Git work in vscode's ssh remote control to another windows machine.
Other stuff jobs are not problems. (like editing, compiling...)
But When I tried to push/pull/fetch, git didn't respond anything. It seems like being pending by something.
So I want to see specific steps to turn out what is a problem.

Note:
  Log, show... commands are working correctly.
  When I am working in the machine directly, this problem doesn't occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set environment variables as defined in the documentation in the Debugging section [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables)

> **GIT_TRACE** 
>   controls general traces, which don’t fit into any specific category. This includes the expansion of aliases, and delegation to other sub-programs.

In the terminal you could set this variable `GIT_TRACE` to 1 and run your git command.
In Windows you can do `set GIT_TRACE=1` and in linux environment you can do `export GIT_TRACE=1`

In addition to this if you would like to see verbose output of the network related operations in git which involves curl, you can use set this environment variable `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE`.

> **Networking**
>
> Git uses the curl library to do network operations over
>   HTTP, so `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE` tells Git to emit all the messages generated
>   by that library. This is similar to doing `curl -v` on the command line.

Answer (score 3):

Better than GIT_TRACE, you have [since Git 2.25 the variable GIT_TRACE2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094711/6309), and [`git fetch` has been instrumented to emit traces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51110452/6309)

```
 # Windows
 set GIT_TRACE2_EVENT=1

 # Linux
 export GIT_TRACE2_EVENT=1

 # launch VSCode
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are exactly looking for this but it may help.

I would recommend using a different format than the default. My usual choice is summary with the graph, but one line summary alone usually does the trick.

**Option 1:** One line summary w/ Graph

```
git log --pretty=format:'%h : %s' --graph > log.log
```

Results in:

```
* 2d3acf9 : ignore errors from SIGCHLD on trap
*   5e3ee11 : Merge branch 'master' of git://github.com/dustin/grit
|\  
| * 420eac9 : Added a method for getting the current branch.
* | 30e367c : timeout code and tests
* | 5a09431 : add timeout protection to grit
* | e1193f8 : support for heads with slashes in them
|/  
* d6016bc : require time for xmlschema
```

**Option 2:** One line summary w/o Graph

```
git log --pretty=format:'%h was %an, %ar, message: %s' > log.log
```

Results in:

```
a6b444f was Scott Chacon, 5 days ago, message: dammit, this is the second time this has re
49d77f7 was Scott Chacon, 8 days ago, message: modified index to create refs/heads if it i
9764edd was Hans Engel, 11 days ago, message: Add diff-lcs dependency
e1ba1e3 was Hans Engel, 11 days ago, message: Add dependency for Open4
0f87b4d was Scott Chacon, 12 days ago, message: merged recent changes
```

You can find more formatting options in the docs [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats)