# SSH not working for public repos in submodules for GitHub

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have a public submodule:

```
[submodule "submodules/quickstart-microsoft-utilities"]
    path = submodules/quickstart-microsoft-utilities
    url = git@github.com:aws-quickstart/quickstart-microsoft-utilities.git
```

It does not init or produce any errors. I have keys in Github but this is public. The main repo that references the git submodules is private, but clones fine. Changing it to https works fine:

```
[submodule "submodules/quickstart-microsoft-utilities"]
    path = submodules/quickstart-microsoft-utilities
    url = https://aws-quickstart/quickstart-microsoft-utilities.git
```

Cloning via SSH on this public repo outside a submodule works fine:

```
git clone git@github.com:aws-quickstart/quickstart-microsoft-utilities.git
```

What gives?

Comment: let the user of your submodule decide how to clone it or include it. I usually use https for anonymous cloning.

Comment: Reading your question, I'm not clear what sort of error you're seeing. But generally, configure submodules meant for public consumption to use `https://`, and if you want to have them cloned locally using `ssh`, configure some `url.*.insteadof` options in your global git config.

Comment: I'm not seeing ANY error, it just silently fails. I assumed it was a git setting but I'm going to keep it as https

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your HTTPS includes github.com, or it won't work either.

Second try (with a recent Git version) a

```
git config -l --show-scope --show-origin | grep -i insteadof
```

Check if any setting would silently replace your SSH URL by anything else.

Regarding the (silent) error, try and `git clone --recurse-submodules` with traces.
You have [since Git 2.25 the variable GIT_TRACE2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094711/6309), and [`git fetch` has been instrumented to emit traces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51110452/6309).

```
 # Windows
 set GIT_TRACE2_EVENT=1

 # Linux
 export GIT_TRACE2_EVENT=1

 # run git clone
```