# GIT post-receive-pack hangs with TCP ZeroWindow

Tags: windows, git, tcp, msysgit

I'm trying to solve the generic "failed to post large file" issue that affects many clients that doesn't involve the generic fix "git config --global http.postBuffer"

I have applied that fix but it has not solved anything.

There are plenty of other threads where people seem to have the same problem where the config fix doesn't fix the issue. The generic response seems to be a shoulder shrug and a "duno, it must be your computer"

I created a test repo and turned the verbosity way up and turned on wireshark and saw something interesting. Unfortunately i'm not well versed in TCP level communication so i can't figure out what it means but i see that the stream ends with a whole lot of "TCP ZeroWindow" errors. Maybe someone can make sense of what is causing my failure to push a large commit?

I know the server can accept large git post as it is working on another persons computer. So there must be something on my computer that is making it break.

```
8760    11.934233000    myserver    192.168.0.58    TCP 60  [TCP ZeroWindow] 666→49997 [ACK] Seq=146 Ack=7784846 Win=0 Len=0
8762    12.233191000    192.168.0.58    myserver        TCP 55  [TCP ZeroWindowProbe] 49997→666 [ACK] Seq=7784846 Ack=146 Win=65536 Len=1
8766    12.423369000    myserver        192.168.0.58    TCP 60  [TCP ZeroWindow] [TCP ACKed unseen segment] 666→49997 [ACK] Seq=146 Ack=7784847 Win=0 Len=0
8790    13.161218000    192.168.0.58    myserver        TCP 55  [TCP Previous segment not captured] 49997→666 [ACK] Seq=7784847 Ack=146 Win=65536 Len=1
```

[image]
 FYI the stream died around the 7.784852mb mark.

Comment: how did you turn up the verbosity? Having the same problem with git on TFS with HTTPS

Comment: Its been a long time but i believe i used answers from here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178401/how-can-i-debug-git-git-shell-related-problems