# Fatal : The remote end hung up unexpectedly libcurl result = 7

Tags: git, tfs, libcurl

I have tried just about every answer on Stackoverflow, here is what I am seeing

```
Counting objects: 134, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (73/73), done.
Writing objects: 100% (79/79), 208.38 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 79 (delta 37), reused 1 (delta 0)
efrror: RPC failed; result=7, HTTP code = 401
atal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

important to note: I am using TFS Git server(Maybe that is my problem, lol)

Things I have tried:

- making sure the url is right with git remote -v (yep everything checked out)
- increasing the global http.postBuffer to 524288000

Interesting thing about error message: The RPC failed; result=7 is interesting in most cases on the stack overflow the result has either been in the 50's or in the 20's, the error I think comes from libcurl. If this is the case then I am getting a CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT (7), from TFS, which I have no idea why. Has anyone else encountered this error? Or know of way to fix the problem I am seeing?

Error codes for Curl are here
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it comes from libcurl. Because...

```
HTTP code = 401
```

... means that libcurl got a HTTP response back and the response code said 401. 401 means that you weren't authenticated to access that resource. Wrong username or password or similar.

Comment: You could be right, I guess from doing some digging, a lot of people were saying that the result= error code is from libcurl, but it could be from something else. Yea so I saw that it was a 401, but the odd thing is that I can log onto the online tfs dashboard for that repo with the same creds just fine. Is there something internal in tfs that would throw a 401?

Answer (score 0):

> error: RPC failed; result=7, HTTP code = 401

If this was working before, this most likely mean some temporary network issue.

See: `man curl`:

> `7` - Failed to connect to host.

And `HTTP 401` means authentication issues over HTTP transport.

This has been improved since Git v1.7.1:

> ```
>  * Authentication over http transport can now be made lazily, in that the
>    request can first go to a URL without username, get a 401 response and
>    then the client will ask for the username to use.
> ```

Please test your credentials by using `ssh` command, e.g.:

```
ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
```

If you still get the issues, use SSH protocol instead (test by: `ssh -T git@github.com`).

For further git debugging, see: [How can I debug git/git-shell related problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6178401/55075)