# How to check progress of upload code to GitHub in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, github

I am newbie to Github so I am not sure how to check the progress of uploading code to Github using Visual Studio (I am using 2019 version). 
If you know how to track it, please let me know, cause I did not see any notification of the uploading from Visual Studio yet. 
Thank you so much :).

Answer (score 2):

Considering the [Team Explorer Synchronization own documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pushing?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio) shows a video with Git commands from the command line, an alternative would be to push directly from the command line:

```
cd /path/to/repo
git push --progress
```

That would work considering the `--progress` option is more accurate [since Git 2.10 up to Git 2.25](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38788417/6309).

The alternative would be to [configure Visual Studio logs to include Git command execution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56261927/6309), but that seems tedious to monitor and use.