# How to review which gpg homedir version and `homedir` Git cmd is using?

Tags: linux, windows, git, gnupg

I'm trying to debug installations of various versions of *Git* & *GPG* on *Linux* and *Windows* platforms.

According to `git` & `gpg` man pages:

- *Git* uses `gpg.program` configuration-option to locate the `gpg` cmd;
- *GPG* uses `GNUPGHOME` environment variable (or `HKCU\Software\GNU\GnuPG:HomeDir` under *Windows*).
- According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38706495/548792), exporting `GIT_TRACE=1` env-var you get verbose 
  information about git's action, but for my case those are not enough.

Is there a way to verify the actual *homedirr* and executable-path of `gpg` used by `git` cmd?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to verify the actual homedir and executable-path of `gpg`

Simply open a `git bash` session and type:

```
echo $HOME
which gpg
```

For me:

```
vonc@bigvonc MINGW64 ~/git/git (master)
$ which gpg
/usr/bin/gpg
```

(`/` is the Git installation root folder)

You can also type `set GIT_TRACE=2` (or `export GIT_TRACE=2` in a bash session) and use a `git` command involving `gpg`:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\git>git tag -v v1.4.2.1
20:58:52.193034 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'tag' '-v' 'v1.4.2.1'
20:58:52.245921 run-command.c:369       trace: run_command: 'gpg' '--status-fd=1' '--keyid-format=long' '--verify' 'C:/Users/vonc/AppData/Local/Temp/.git_vtag_tmp4moGKa' '-'
object 883653babd8ee7ea23e6a5c392bb739348b1eb61
type commit
tag v1.4.2.1
tagger Junio C Hamano <junkio@cox.net> 1158138501 -0700

GIT 1.4.2.1

Minor fixes since 1.4.2, including git-mv and git-http with alternates.
gpg: Signature made Wed Sep 13 11:08:25 2006 RDT
gpg:                using DSA key C0C6D9A4F3119B9A
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
```

Here `gpg` is the one on the `$PATH`:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\git>where gpg
C:\prgs\git\latest\usr\bin\gpg.exe
C:\prgs\gpg2\latest\pub\gpg.exe
```

In my case, it is the one from Git itself used first.