# Git bash trace - Why so slow?

Tags: windows, git, bash

I am using git bash on Windows 7 which is extremely slow. The user profile is on a network drive, so I changed the start to start on the c: drive. I also removed the PS1 prompt and I just use `$`.

I also have done:

```
$ git config --global core.preloadindex true
$ git config --global core.fscache true
```

Some things have speed up, but the git commands themselves are extremely slow. Any idea why? Here is a strace.

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git stash
09:27:27.099458 git.c:594               trace: exec: 'git-stash'
09:27:27.099458 run-command.c:369       trace: run_command: 'git-stash'
09:27:28.862258 git.c:594               trace: exec: 'git-sh-i18n--envsubst' '--variables' 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
09:27:28.862258 run-command.c:369       trace: run_command: 'git-sh-i18n--envsubst' '--variables' 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
09:27:29.096258 git.c:594               trace: exec: 'git-sh-i18n--envsubst' 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
09:27:29.096258 run-command.c:369       trace: run_command: 'git-sh-i18n--envsubst' 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
09:27:29.877258 git.c:369               trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--git-dir'
09:27:30.267258 git.c:369               trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--git-path' 'objects'
09:27:30.766458 git.c:369               trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--show-toplevel'
09:27:30.984858 git.c:369               trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--git-path' 'index'
09:27:31.281258 git.c:369               trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-colorbool' 'color.interactive'
09:27:31.608858 git.c:369               trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-color' 'color.interactive.help' 'red bold'
09:27:31.967658 git.c:369               trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-color' '' 'reset'
09:27:32.375258 git.c:369               trace: built-in: git 'ls-files' '--error-unmatch' '--'
09:27:32.702858 git.c:369               trace: built-in: git 'update-index' '-q' '--refresh'
09:27:33.048058 git.c:369               trace: built-in: git 'diff-index' '--quiet' '--cached' 'HEAD' '--ignore-submodules' '--'
09:27:33.392258 git.c:369               trace: built-in: git 'diff-files' '--quiet' '--ignore-submodules' '--'
No local changes to save
```

---

On Cygwin, real time is only 3 seconds. Here on git bash, 9 seconds.

```
$ time git stash
No local changes to save

real    0m9.172s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.108s
$
```

---

Here is Cygwins trace to compare against:

```
$  GIT_TRACE=1 git stash
13:02:51.567376 git.c:595               trace: exec: 'git-stash'
13:02:51.567376 run-command.c:369       trace: run_command: 'git-stash'
13:02:52.740271 git.c:595               trace: exec: 'git-sh-i18n--envsubst' '--variables' 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
13:02:52.740271 run-command.c:369       trace: run_command: 'git-sh-i18n--envsubst' '--variables' 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
13:02:52.990489 git.c:595               trace: exec: 'git-sh-i18n--envsubst' 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
13:02:52.990489 run-command.c:369       trace: run_command: 'git-sh-i18n--envsubst' 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
13:02:53.459647 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--git-dir'
13:02:53.694226 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--git-path' 'objects'
13:02:53.975720 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--show-toplevel'
13:02:54.085191 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--git-path' 'index'
13:02:54.194661 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-colorbool' 'color.interactive'
13:02:54.304131 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-color' 'color.interactive.help' 'red bold'
13:02:54.413601 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-color' '' 'reset'
13:02:54.523071 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'update-index' '-q' '--refresh'
13:02:54.775294 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'diff-index' '--quiet' '--cached' 'HEAD' '--ignore-submodules' '--'
13:02:54.900403 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'diff-files' '--quiet' '--ignore-submodules'
No local changes to save
```

Comment: Call me a cynic but perhaps it's because the Linux sub system was developed by Microsoft.

Comment: What's "strace" doing in the title? If you had a syscall-level trace of what was going on, you'd probably know exactly where it was slow. This is **much** higher-level, and comparatively useless as a result.

Comment: ...beyond that, I'm not really sure that this is on-topic just from a breadth/scope perspective. This is a topic on which I could easily see someone doing a few weeks of investigation, and for which there would be a new and different answer as soon as the most immediate bottlenecks are removed, as opposed to a question with a clean and canonical answer.

Comment: (I'd strongly suggest validating that your network store isn't actually being hit during these operations, btw -- perhaps you might pull out wireshark for the purpose).

Comment: The strace is recommended from Git For Windows https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/Diagnosing-performance-issues to diagnose performance issues.

Comment: That's not strace.  That's git's internal trace, a different beast entirely.

Comment: @RamanSailopal Did Microsoft create the bash client that comes with git? That's news to me.

Comment: Are you running 32-bit or 64-bit git/bash?

Comment: What does the equivalent trace look like for Cygwin? The network drive immediately draws my attention, it's a variable you cannot control. Can you remove it from the testing?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\git-bash.exe"` and `git version 2.13.0.windows.1`

Answer (score 0):

First, regarding strace, you now have a new option with Git 2.27 (Q2 2020)

See [commit 3efc128](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3efc128cd59fefb6aa159548d0cf7666ce5e34a9) (09 Apr 2020), and [commit b6852e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6852e19794245566f7c961a434c56ca3b7a883b) (08 Apr 2020) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
See [commit a748f3f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a748f3f3dc0adff1d8a83dfc098ed819658998d0) (08 Apr 2020) by [Matthias Aßhauer (`rimrul`)](https://github.com/rimrul).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b3eb70e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3eb70e0f8988dbf36f42e0bea201e2cd71f248e), 22 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`mingw`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3efc128cd59fefb6aa159548d0cf7666ce5e34a9): help debugging by optionally executing bash with strace
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>
> MSYS2's strace facility is very useful for debugging... With this patch, the bash will be executed through `strace` if the environment variable `GIT_STRACE_COMMANDS` is set, which comes in real handy when investigating issues in the test suite.
>
> Also support passing a path to a log file via `GIT_STRACE_COMMANDS` to force Git to call **`strace.exe`** with the `-o <path>` argument, i.e. to log into a file rather than print the log directly.
>
> That comes in handy when the output would otherwise misinterpreted by a calling process as part of Git's output.
>
> Note: the values "`1`", "`yes`" or "`true`" are *not* specifying paths, but tell Git to let strace.exe log directly to the console.

Second, don't forget recent Git version (2.22+) the [**`trace2`** utility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094711/6309)

In your case, `set GIT_TRACE2_PERFORMANCE=1&& git <command>` would help see where the performance issue occurs