# Runtime.getRuntime().exec() git commit -m XXX with wrong exitcode of "1"

Tags: git, runtime, git-commit

As the title says, I use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` to execute `git commit -m XXX` command.

Unfortunately, it returns the unmormal exitcode with 1 (btw,the right code is 0).

I try to type the command on the command line，the commit command is working OK.

Anybody knows where the problem is?

```
public static int commit(String dir,String commitMsg) {
    String command = "git commit -m " + commitMsg;
    exitCode = ProcessUtil.safeSyncRun(command, dir);
    System.out.println(command + " exitcode = " + exitCode);
    return exitCode;
}
public static int safeSyncRun(String command, String workingDir) {
    Process process;
    int exitValue = -1;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, new File(workingDir));
        process.waitFor();
        exitValue = process.exitValue();
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("exception : " + e);
    }finally{
        process = null;
    }
    return exitValue;
}
```

Outputs below:

```
git commit -m test commit msg 
exitcode = 1
```

Comment: Did the commit actually occur? Do you have a post-commit hook or other hooks installed?

Comment: nope,there is not some hooks installed.

Comment: OH!!!  i know why the commit not worked. because the commitMsg i assgned has space identifier.so the whole commit command like this,git commit -m test commit msg.I try to update my code as below,     public static int commit(String dir,String commitMsg) {
  String command = "git commit -m \'" + commitMsg + "\'";
  exitCode = ProcessUtil.safeSyncRun(command, dir);
  System.out.println(command + " exitcode = " + exitCode);
  return exitCode;
 }  it doesn‘t work either. why?

Comment: Well, now you're getting into questions about your language (Csharp? I don't know, you did not specify) and its `safeSyncRun` command.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a bash, try instead (using "[How can I debug git/git-shell related problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38706495/6309)"):

```
String command = "bash -c 'export GIT_TRACE=true; export GIT_TRACE_SETUP =true; git commit -m \"" + commitMsg + "\"'";
```

Note the `\"` around your `commitMsg`: that can help `git commit` interpret correctly your commit message.