# How to troubleshoot an abnormally slow git-diff?

Tags: git, git-diff

I recently cloned a remote repo in which some `git` commands run extremely slowly.  For example, running

```
git diff --quiet
```

...takes ~40 s.  (For what it's worth, the repo is clean.  I am using `git` version 2.20.1.)

While trying to figure out what's causing this sluggishness, I have bumped into a handful of procedures that abolish it, though I have no idea why.

Of these procedures, the simplest/quickest one I've found is this: (starting from a freshly-cloned instance of the repo) create a branch off `master`, and checkout it out.  After this, if I check out `master` once more, now `git diff --quiet` finishes quickly (under 50ms).

Below is an example interaction, showing timing information for the various opertions<sup>1</sup>:

```
rm -rf ./"$REPONAME"      #  0.174 s
git clone "$URL"          # 54.118 s
cd ./"$REPONAME"          #  0.007 s

git diff --quiet          # 39.438 s

git branch VOODOO         #  0.032 s
git checkout VOODOO       # 31.247 s
git diff --quiet          #  0.014 s

git checkout master       #  0.034 s
git diff --quiet          #  0.012 s
```

As I've already stressed, this is only one of several possible procedures that "fix" the repo, and they are all equally mysterious to me.  This only happens to be the simplest/quickest one I've found.

The above sequence of timings is very reproducible (i.e. I get roughly the same timings every time I run that specific sequence exactly as shown).

It is, however, *very* sensitive to seemingly small variations.  For example if I replace the `git branch VOODOO; git checkout VOODOO` with `git checkout -b VOODOO`, the subsequent profile of timings changes radically:

```
rm -rf ./"$REPONAME"      #  0.015 s
git clone "$URL"          # 45.312 s
cd ./"$REPONAME"          #  0.007 s

git diff --quiet          # 46.145 s

git checkout -b VOODOO    # 42.363 s
git diff --quiet          # 41.180 s

git checkout master       # 47.345 s
git diff --quiet          #  0.018 s
```

I would like to figure out what is going on.  How can I troubleshoot the matter further?

Is there a permanent ("committable") way to "fix" the repo?  (By "fix" I mean: get rid of the long delays for `git diff --quiet`, `git checkout ...`, etc.)

(Incidentally, `git gc` won't fix the repo, even transiently; I tried it.)

I figure that what ends up "fixing" the repo is that `git` gets around to building *and caching* some *auxiliary data structure* that allows it to perform some operations efficiently.  If this hypothesis is correct, then my question can be rephrased as: what is the most direct way to cause `git` to build such auxiliary data structure?

---

**EDIT:** One additional bit of information that may shed light on the above is that this repo contains one exceptionally large (1GB) file.  (This explains the slowness of the `git clone` step.  I don't know if this has anything to do with the slowness of `git diff --quiet`, etc., and if so, how.)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Needless to say, I've named the branch `VOODOO` to reflect my ignorance of what's going on.</sup>

Comment: `git clone` seems to be in the same ballpark as the other long operations. Are you surprised that `git clone` also takes a long time? When you look at its progress indicator, where does it spend most of the time?

Comment: @j6t: Indeed, the cloning is surprisingly slow.  I've made an EDIT to my post that sheds light on this point.  Briefly, the cloning spends most of its time in the "Receiving objects" stage.

Comment: Do you type the example commands on the command line, i.e., with some delay between commands, or are you invoking them from a script so that they run without delay? Also, what happens if you run two `git diff` back to back? When the first one is slow, is the second one fast or slow?

Comment: @j6t: I use a script to run the commands, to ensure reproducibility.  If I add a second `git diff --quiet` command immediately after each  `git diff --quiet` command in the original sequence, I find that the second  `git diff --quiet` command of each pair takes roughly the same amount of time as the first one (of that pair).

Comment: This more or less excludes the "racily clean index" case, which requires to scan the worktree data. (The second `git diff` would have been fast in that case.) I suggest you gather more data. For example, if you are on Linux or similar, run `strace -f -tt -e file,clone,execve -o /tmp/git.strace git diff --quiet` and inspect the timestamps in `/tmp/git.strace`. Perhaps it reveals where the time is spen.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1160349/git-is-extremely-slow-on-windows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check first if the issue persists with Git 2.27, and even the upcoming 2.28 (Q3 2020)

I would use [**`GIT_TRACE2_PERF`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094711/6309) for any performance measure. (as [I did here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59817528/6309))

With Git 2.28 (Q3 2020), the memory usage during "`diff --quiet`" in a worktree with too many stat-unmatched paths has been considerable reduced.

Its patch description illustrates a use-case where "`diff --quiet`" can be slow:

See [commit d2d7fbe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d2d7fbe12945dd9032c9c7c14a4563dbecc7e629) (01 Jun 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0cd0afc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0cd0afc9c6193dd4a762f5a2d1bc23e58629b23f), 18 Jun 2020)</sup>

> ### [`diff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d2d7fbe12945dd9032c9c7c14a4563dbecc7e629): discard blob data from stat-unmatched pairs
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Jan Christoph Uhde</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> When performing a tree-level diff against the working tree, we may find that our index stat information is dirty, so we queue a filepair to be examined later.
> If the actual content hasn't changed, we call this a **`stat-unmatch`**; the stat information was out of date, but there's no actual diff.
>
> Normally `diffcore_std()` would detect and remove these identical filepairs via `diffcore_skip_stat_unmatch()`.
>
> However, when "`--quiet`" is used, we want to stop the diff as soon as we see any changes, so we check for stat-unmatches immediately in `diff_change()`.
>
> That check may require us to actually load the file contents into the pair of `diff_filespecs`.
> If we find that the pair isn't a stat-unmatch, then no big deal; we'd likely load the contents later anyway to generate a patch, do rename detection, etc, so we want to hold on to it.
> But if it is a stat-unmatch, then we have no more use for that data; the whole point is that we're going discard the pair. However, we never free the allocated `diff_filespec` data.
>
> In most cases, keeping that data isn't a problem. We don't expect a lot of stat-unmatch entries, and since we're using `--quiet`, we'd quit as soon as we saw such a real change anyway.
>
> However, there are extreme cases where it makes a big difference:
>
> 1. We'd generally mmap() the working tree half of the pair.
>    And since the OS may limit the total number of maps, we can run afoul of this in large repositories. E.g.:
>
>    ```
>     $ cd linux
>    $ git ls-files | wc -l
>    67959
>    $ sysctl vm.max_map_count
>    vm.max_map_count = 65530
>    $ git ls-files | xargs touch ;# everything is stat-dirty!
>    $ git diff --quiet
>    fatal: mmap failed: Cannot allocate memory
>    ```
>
> It should be unusual to have so many files stat-dirty, but it's possible if you've just run a script like "`sed -i`" or similar.
>
> After this patch, the above correctly exits with code 0.
>
> 2. Even if you don't hit mmap limits, the index half of the pair will have been pulled from the object database into heap memory.
>    Again in a clone of `linux.git`, running:
>
>    ```
>    $ git ls-files | head -n 10000 | xargs touch
>    $ git diff --quiet
>    ```
>
> peaks at 145MB heap before this patch, and 94MB after.
>
> This patch solves the problem by freeing any `diff_filespec` data we picked up during the "`--quiet`" stat-unmatch check in `diff_changes`.
> Nobody is going to need that data later, so there's no point holding on to it.
> There are a few things to note:
>
> - we could skip queueing the pair entirely, which could in theory save a little work. But there's not much to save, as we need a `diff_filepair` to feed to `diff_filespec_check_stat_unmatch()` anyway.
>   And since we cache the result of the `stat-unmatch` checks, a later call to `diffcore_skip_stat_unmatch()` call will quickly skip over them.
>   The `diffcore` code also counts up the number of stat-unmatched pairs as it removes them. It's doubtful any callers would care about that in combination with `--quiet`, but we'd have to reimplement the logic here to be on the safe side. So it's not really worth the trouble.
> - I didn't write a test, because we always produce the correct output unless we run up against system mmap limits, which are bot unportable and expensive to test against. Measuring peak heap would be interesting, but our perf suite isn't yet capable of that.
> - note that diff without "`--quiet`" does not suffer from the same problem. In `diffcore_skip_stat_unmatch()`, we detect the `stat-unmatch` entries and drop them immediately, so we're not carrying their data around.
> - you *can* still trigger the `mmap` limit problem if you truly have that many files with actual changes. But it's rather unlikely. The `stat-unmatch` check avoids loading the file contents if the size don't match, so you'd need a pretty trivial change in every single file.
>   Likewise, inexact rename detection might load the data for many files all at once. But you'd need not just 64k changes, but that many deletions and additions. The most likely candidate is perhaps break-detection, which would load the data for all pairs and keep it around for the content-level diff. But again, you'd need 64k actually changed files in the first place.
>
> So it's still possible to trigger this case, but it seems like "I accidentally made all my files stat-dirty" is the most likely case in the real world.

---

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), "[`git diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bf69da56c9e8adac1eee91b7a8b000363156c583/Documentation/git-diff.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup> and other commands that share the same machinery to compare with working tree files have been taught to take advantage of the `fsmonitor` data when available.

See [commit 2bfa953](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2bfa953e5daf3253cc5fae2de2c68fbd206dfe12), [commit 471b115](https://github.com/git/git/commit/471b1157451ef06d7cfe092c07a87e93142a8dc4), [commit ed5a245](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed5a24573d8caf222dbb81a46dc97a4459928e2d), [commit 89afd5f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/89afd5f5ad920d1b5f01548bf5c8aeca8e56e899), [commit 5851462](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5851462e8d905ea18f84ea549569563b242e40d1), [commit dc69d47](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc69d47d216b9ba1b23ecd67e199dfa11192ebbb) (20 Oct 2020) by [Nipunn Koorapati (`nipunn1313`)](https://github.com/nipunn1313).
See [commit c9052a8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9052a8392878d9e38381db5d2172f7f8f7272a3) (20 Oct 2020) by [Alex Vandiver (`alexmv`)](https://github.com/alexmv).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bf69da5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf69da56c9e8adac1eee91b7a8b000363156c583), 09 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`t/perf`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/89afd5f5ad920d1b5f01548bf5c8aeca8e56e899): add `fsmonitor` perf test for `git diff`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Nipunn Koorapati</sup>

> Results for the git-diff fsmonitor optimization in patch in the parent-rev (using a 400k file repo to test)
>
> As you can see here - [`git diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89afd5f5ad920d1b5f01548bf5c8aeca8e56e899/Documentation/git-diff.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup> with `fsmonitor` running is significantly better with this patch series (80% faster on my workload)!
>
> `GIT_PERF_LARGE_REPO=~/src/server` ./run v2.29.0-rc1 . -- p7519-fsmonitor.sh
>
> ```
> Test                                                                     v2.29.0-rc1       this tree
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 7519.2: status (fsmonitor=.git/hooks/fsmonitor-watchman)                 1.46(0.82+0.64)   1.47(0.83+0.62) +0.7%
> 7519.3: status -uno (fsmonitor=.git/hooks/fsmonitor-watchman)            0.16(0.12+0.04)   0.17(0.12+0.05) +6.3%
> 7519.4: status -uall (fsmonitor=.git/hooks/fsmonitor-watchman)           1.36(0.73+0.62)   1.37(0.76+0.60) +0.7%
> 7519.5: diff (fsmonitor=.git/hooks/fsmonitor-watchman)                   0.85(0.22+0.63)   0.14(0.10+0.05) -83.5%
> 7519.6: diff -- 0_files (fsmonitor=.git/hooks/fsmonitor-watchman)        0.12(0.08+0.05)   0.13(0.11+0.02) +8.3%
> 7519.7: diff -- 10_files (fsmonitor=.git/hooks/fsmonitor-watchman)       0.12(0.08+0.04)   0.13(0.09+0.04) +8.3%
> 7519.8: diff -- 100_files (fsmonitor=.git/hooks/fsmonitor-watchman)      0.12(0.07+0.05)   0.13(0.07+0.06) +8.3%
> 7519.9: diff -- 1000_files (fsmonitor=.git/hooks/fsmonitor-watchman)     0.12(0.09+0.04)   0.13(0.08+0.05) +8.3%
> 7519.10: diff -- 10000_files (fsmonitor=.git/hooks/fsmonitor-watchman)   0.14(0.09+0.05)   0.13(0.10+0.03) -7.1%
> 7519.12: status (fsmonitor=)                                             1.67(0.93+1.49)   1.67(0.99+1.42) +0.0%
> 7519.13: status -uno (fsmonitor=)                                        0.37(0.30+0.82)   0.37(0.33+0.79) +0.0%
> 7519.14: status -uall (fsmonitor=)                                       1.58(0.97+1.35)   1.57(0.86+1.45) -0.6%
> 7519.15: diff (fsmonitor=)                                               0.34(0.28+0.83)   0.34(0.27+0.83) +0.0%
> 7519.16: diff -- 0_files (fsmonitor=)                                    0.09(0.06+0.04)   0.09(0.08+0.02) +0.0%
> 7519.17: diff -- 10_files (fsmonitor=)                                   0.09(0.07+0.03)   0.09(0.06+0.05) +0.0%
> 7519.18: diff -- 100_files (fsmonitor=)                                  0.09(0.06+0.04)   0.09(0.06+0.04) +0.0%
> 7519.19: diff -- 1000_files (fsmonitor=)                                 0.09(0.06+0.04)   0.09(0.05+0.05) +0.0%
> 7519.20: diff -- 10000_files (fsmonitor=)                                0.10(0.08+0.04)   0.10(0.06+0.05) +0.0%
> ```
>
> I also added a benchmark for a tiny [`git diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89afd5f5ad920d1b5f01548bf5c8aeca8e56e899/Documentation/git-diff.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup> workload w/ a pathspec.
> I see an approximately .02 second overhead added w/ and w/o `fsmonitor`.
>
> From looking at these results, I suspected that `refresh_fsmonitor` is already happening during [`git diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89afd5f5ad920d1b5f01548bf5c8aeca8e56e899/Documentation/git-diff.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup> - independent of this patch series' optimization.
> Confirmed that suspicion by breaking on `refresh_fsmonitor`.
>
> ```
> (gdb) bt  [simplified]
> ```
>
> - 0  `refresh_fsmonitor`  at [`fsmonitor.c`#176](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89afd5f5ad920d1b5f01548bf5c8aeca8e56e899/fsmonitor.c#L176)
> - 1  `ie_match_stat`  at [`read-cache.c`#375](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89afd5f5ad920d1b5f01548bf5c8aeca8e56e899/read-cache.c#L375)
> - 2  `match_stat_with_submodule` at [`diff-lib.c`#237](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89afd5f5ad920d1b5f01548bf5c8aeca8e56e899/diff-lib.c#L237)
> - 4  `builtin_diff_files`  at [`builtin/diff.c`#260](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89afd5f5ad920d1b5f01548bf5c8aeca8e56e899/builtin/diff.c#L260)
> - 5  `cmd_diff`  at [`builtin/diff.c`#541](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89afd5f5ad920d1b5f01548bf5c8aeca8e56e899/builtin/diff.c#L541)
> - 6  `run_builtin`  at [`git.c`#450](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89afd5f5ad920d1b5f01548bf5c8aeca8e56e899/git.c#L450)
> - 7  `handle_builtin`  at [`git.c`#700](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89afd5f5ad920d1b5f01548bf5c8aeca8e56e899/git.c#L700)
> - 8  `run_argv`  at [`git.c`#767](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89afd5f5ad920d1b5f01548bf5c8aeca8e56e899/git.c#L767)
> - 9  `cmd_main`  at [`git.c`#898](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89afd5f5ad920d1b5f01548bf5c8aeca8e56e899/git.c#L898)
> - 10 `main`  at [`common-main.c`#52](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89afd5f5ad920d1b5f01548bf5c8aeca8e56e899/common-main.c#L52)

Comment: How does this only have one upvote! So much info and research. Let's fix that...

Comment: @Codebling The credits go to Jeff King, Nipunn Koorapati and Alex Vandiver. I just reported their findings.