# git repo migration to new server fails

Tags: git, gitlab

Trying to move a repo to a new server using git clone --mirror. But when pushing it fails with 
`remote: fatal: git cat-file: could not get object info`

Here my steps:

```
git clone --mirror oldRepoUrl
cd old cloned repo
git remote add newRepoName newRepoUrl
git push -f --tags newRepoName refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
```

The destination is a new empty repo.

Heres the error I get:

```
remote: System hooks checking refs/heads/master
remote: fatal: git cat-file: could not get object info
remote: fatal: git cat-file: could not get object info
remote: warn: committer emails ["email1@mail.com",...etc multiples] are not found in Github
```

Could this be due to the committers that are no longer part of the project? Or something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any submodules on the repo you're cloning?

Comment: Nope - no submodules.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the refspec "`refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*`", try instead a [`git push --mirror`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---mirror), and see if the issue persists.

For testing, try and push it to a brand new empty repository.

Note: the committers are mentioned as a warning.
The fatal error comes from something else ([this issue](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/issues/7709) illustrated the submodule cause, but if you don't have any `.gitmodules`, that should not concern you)

Comment: Same error with git push newRepoName --mirror . newRepoName is a new empty repository.

Comment: @kipper3d I meant: `git push --mirror newRepoName` (`--mirror` before the remote). And `newRepoName` would be the name of a remote (`git remote -v`) referencing the URL of the new empty repository)

Comment: Same error... Any way to get more information out of this error because 'remote: fatal: git cat-file: could not get object info' really doesn't tell us much. It is followed by warning due to missing committers.

Comment: @kipper3d If you have a recent version of Git (2.22+), you can activate  trace2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094711/6309, as documented in https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/api-trace2.txt