# Ignore warning when pushing to heroku git master

Tags: bash, git, heroku

I'm deploying an app to Heroku, which means [pushing to their git repo](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git). When do `git push heroku master` (or the equivalent remote alias) I get this warning:

> WARNING: You're about to push to master, is that what you intended? [y|n]

Which is kinda annoying but not a big deal. However, I'm now scripting deployments so I don't want to have interact with the script - how I do get my bash script to answer `y` automatically?

I tried doing `yes | git push heroku master` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have a `pre-push` hook in `.git/hooks/pre-push`?  If so, can you provide the contents of it as a text block by editing your question?

Comment: @bk2204 Nope, no such file

Comment: Does it work if you do `git push --no-verify heroku master`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agree with @bk2204, I would check if a git hook is being used that you are unaware of.

Git hooks are not version controlled, so make sure you are searching for this at the machine where you get this error.

The git hook may live elsewhere other than the `.git` directory. Check if `git config core.hooksPath` is set and if so, it will point to the directory where your git hook is.

The hook file that you are looking for will most likely have the name `pre-push`. The solution in this case is to remove or rename this hook file, and git won't run it before push.

Comment: Ah. That was indeed the case! I guess this was pre-configured on my work laptop

Answer (score 0):

> Nope, no such file

And yet, this is exactly what a `.git/hooks/pre-push` would do, [like this one](https://gist.github.com/ColCh/9d48693276aac50cac37a9fce23f9bda).

To rule that out, [activate (with your local Git 2.25+) trace2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094711/6309).
That will allow you to see what is used on the client side (your PC) by Git:

```
git config --global trace2.normalTarget ~/log.normal
```

Try your push, type 'n' (to abort), and check  `~/log.normal` for clues.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to solve the problem of automating responses to the prompts. You can use `expect` to take care of interactive warnings/ prompts.

After writing the deployment script `deploy.sh`, you can write a expect script and spawn the `deploy` script in it, for response to

*WARNING: You're about to push to master, is that what you intended? [y|n]*

message, you can send 'y' from expect.

The following snippet can be taken as example

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn bash ./deploy.sh

expect "WARNING: You're about to push to master, is that what you intended? [y|n]\r"

send -- "y\r"
```