# Git hanging on status / add / commit

Tags: git, ubuntu

I seem to have got a stuck git repo. It hangs on all basic add,commit commands, git push returns everything as up to date.
From other posts I have done git gc and git fsck/
I figure the basic debug step is git status, so:

```
GIT_TRACE=1 git status
```

returns this repetition - I am not sure what it means but seems in a loop ?

```
16:51:27.575926 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'status'
16:51:27.669849 run-command.c:334       trace: run_command: 'status' '--porcelain'
16:51:27.672090 exec_cmd.c:120          trace: exec: 'git' 'status' '--porcelain'
16:51:27.680657 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'status' '--porcelain'
16:51:27.730535 run-command.c:334       trace: run_command: 'status' '--porcelain'
16:51:27.732571 exec_cmd.c:120          trace: exec: 'git' 'status' '--porcelain'
```

also tried:

```
git count-objects -v
```

gives output:

```
count: 0
size: 0
in-pack: 28167
packs: 1
size-pack: 1117374
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 0
size-garbage: 0
```

I am not sure what debug steps to take next, so appreciate help here.
This is running on WSL with Ubuntu, other repos are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the only way I could resolve this was to clone the repo again

UPDATE:
I encountered this again and found this post:

https://medium.com/@marcosantonocito/fixing-the-gh001-large-files-detected-you-may-want-to-try-git-large-file-storage-43336b983272

EG basically ...

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch fileNameToRemove.extn'
```

or

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch pathToFile/fileNameToRemove.extn'
```

Then do a git pull and push

Comment: `filter-branch` is obsolete: consider `filter-repo`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63878194/6309

Answer (score 0):

An infinite loop on git status has been seen before ([hbons/SparkleShare issue 1170](https://github.com/hbons/SparkleShare/issues/1170) as an example)

The next step, with a Git 2.25+, would be to enable trace2, which [I present here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094711/6309):

```
GIT_TRACE2_EVENT=1 GIT_TRACE2_PERF=1 git status
```

You can see more in "[A Deep Dive into Git Performance using Trace2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/a-deep-dive-into-git-performance-using-trace2/)" from [Jeff Hostetler](https://twitter.com/jeffhostetler).

Comment: Sorry this did nothing to help

Comment: @Datadimension No problem, at least you managed to make it work.