# unable to access Could not resolve host

Tags: git, github, gitlab, repository, commit

I was developing code on Ubuntu using VMware. Everything was fine, I was coding and committing it to my Github account without any problem. BUT suddenly it stopped working, it would say:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/hm0ss/nst.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com

What Have I done? I searched it on google and used config command and other advice, with no avail.
I also made another git repository, but that failed either.
I switched to GitLab and made a repository there, which had no benefit:
"Unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/hma.globe/nst2.git/': Could not resolve host: gitlab.com" 
I need to say that I was using a proxy (socks indeed) but even disconnecting socks server (or removing proxies from google chrome) did not work either.
By the way, I even switched to windows and tried to commit but came across to same error.
After trying some 2 hours, I'm now in big trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if the issue persists.

GitHub status has been reporting several issues recently (in the last few hours) which could explain "sudden" problems of yours.

For example: [this incident](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/dsf2qtzh4jpz): "We are investigating degradations to GitHub.com".

[GitLab had no recent issues though](https://status.gitlab.com/pages/history/5b36dc6502d06804c08349f7), which means a network issue on your side could also be a factor.

The OP did a reset of the VMware to solve the network issue.
And a full reset to `origin/master` + copy of the current work to lake and push a new commit successfully to GitHub.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. About your point on my network problem, I am able to surf the internet quite normally, even I'm able to open Github or Gitlab. I also used two commands which other people told to resolve proxy issue (if present) :
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
But nothing has worked. After 3 hours of trying, I think I'll upload them manually on GitHub website.
But this is quite weird :|

Comment: @m0ss I was thinking to a local Git config issue indeed. Note that removing http.proxy config would still leave an environment variable like `HTTP_PROXY` active (if you have one set) and used by Git.

Comment: Yes, I saw some threads mentioning this, but unfortunately, I don't have any ideas about how to fix them. All I say about HTTP_PROXY was some commands which I did not know how to use them and even where to enter them?
I have removed my .git folder many times and initialized it again but didn't work.
I have been using proxies and VPNs for a long time but had not ever had this issue.
But recently, I came across it before this time, which was resolved spontaneously.
I'd be appreciated if you explain more how to solve that HTTP_PROXY issue.

Comment: @m0ss First, type `env|grep -i proxy` to check if you had any proxy-related environment variable set.

Comment: I did. It came out:
ADSK_CLM_WPAD_PROXY_CHECK=FALSE

Comment: By the way, I deleted git several times and tried to re init it and post again.
after git init, I also set my remote using git remote add .....
but when I try to push, it says:
fatal: 'github/hm0ss/nst' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists

I don't really know why it keeps annoying me :||

Comment: I should also say now that I check VMware, I see it's not even connected to the internet!
That's really strange because at the same time I'm browsing sites on windows

Comment: @m0ss Strange indeed. What are the network settings in your browser? Especially regarding DNS: it must contact one to be able to resolve the URLs.

Comment: Using ipconfig, it came out to be 192.168.1.1
I tried it on windows by the way.

Comment: @m0ss That looks about right. Maybe some of the suggestions in https://superuser.com/a/1127602/141 could help?

Comment: Thanks, 
By the say that although I have the internet on my windows and can surf quite normally, git still does not work on windows!
That is, I copy the repository from my VMware to my windows desktop and use git bash to push that, but it say:
fatal: 'github/hm0ss/nst' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: @m0ss Can you activate TRACE2 as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61307754/6309? You might have more clues that way.

Comment: I coppy pasted GIT_TRACE2_EVENT=1 GIT_TRACE2_PERF=1 git status in my git bash.
The result was too long to be printed hear, but after a lot of stuff, it said:
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212317/discussion-between-vonc-and-m0ss).

Answer (score 10):

I had issues like this and  there is no one specific set of instructions to resolve this   .
however i tried running this command and it worked for me

```html
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Then run

```html
git remote  set-url origin <repository link>
```

After commiting your new changes  try running
this command if regular push gives you an error

```html
git push origin <branch>  --force
```

Comment: Can you change it from snippet to code block?

Answer (score 1):

### DNS Resolution:

It's possible that GitHub's IP address isn't resolving correctly. Attempt to use a different DNS server temporarily to resolve the GitHub domain. You can change your DNS settings to a public DNS server like Google (8.8.8.8) or Cloudflare (1.1.1.1) to check if that resolves the issue.

For temporary DNS update:

```bash
sudo echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

Other possible techniques for resolving:

- restarting the VM/device
- rechecking Firewall or Network Restrictions
- restarting **Network Services**

  ```bash
  sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager  # For CentOS 8 and later
  ```

Answer (score 0):

For your additional information just in case you find this post. there are two scenario why it was happen
First you enable your proxy so git --unset http.proxy

second you network using proxy so configure your proxy. which i found this  [useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server-fails-with-request-timed-out)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).