# How to remove commits from history for the files that no longer exist in the repo

Tags: github, git-commit, git

So my Github repo contains many projects over the years, and now there are only a couple remaining. Is it possible to clean my commit history so that instead of thousands of commits about files/projects that no longer exist in this repo, down to maybe a hundred commits that pertain to the files in the couple of projects remaining.
Thanks.

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes, use replace and filter-branch to construct any history you want from the history that's there now."  Without a more specific question, it's going to be hard to provide a more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks jthill. I was able to resolve this using git filter-repo to filter out the projects that's no longer in the repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider the [new `git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), which [will replace the old `git filter-branch` or BFG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).

It has [many usage examples](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES), inclusing path-based filtering:

> To keep all files except these paths, just add --invert-paths:
>
> ```
> git filter-repo --path README.md --path guides/ --path tools/releases --invert-paths
> ```

Comment: Thank you VonC! This is exactly what I was looking for!