# Fatal error in while adding files in git and github

Tags: git, github

I have more that one file. When I want to add all the files I type `git add -A` but after pressing enter it start showing warning and at last it shows

> fatal: adding files failed.

I don't know how to solve this error or problem.

Comment: Insted of that there is then sorry.

Comment: Please click [edit] under the question and include the full output the command gives. The other warnings might not mean anything to you, but without them, everyone else has to waste time guessing.

Comment: See also [ask], which gives general advice on how to arrange things so that other StackOverflow users *can* help you.

Comment: Did you try `git add --ignore-errors .`

Answer (score 0):

Would be useful to know your git version (`git --version`). Also how many files are in there? What's the current status (`git status`)?

Also see [how to debug git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38706495/3091524).

Comment: Hello, Actually I am a beginner so that's why I don't know too much, according to your question my version is 2.33.0.windows.2. . Not that much file actually I am learning so that's why I just made 3 files. My current status is I am in branch master and after typeing git status it shows {warning: could not open directory 'Application Data/': permission denied} and it is not showing only this warning it is showing so much warning.

Answer (score -1):

If there is a permission issue, resolving that first could be a good first step.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer]. This sounds more like a comment. Once you earn enough reputation you'll be able to comment; until then, please ask and answer questions that don't require clarification to earn reputation points.