# In Git Bash how to trace a non-git command?

Tags: git-bash

I run a installation script in Git Bash. The script seems to be hanging.

Had this happened in Linux, I would have used strace command to see where the process stuck.

Is there something similar in Git Bash, or in Windows in general?

Git Bash is seen in many places in Windows, eg, running by itself or embedded in VS Code.

Clarification:

- This is NOT about tracing a Git command which has a debug mode.
- This is about a general tracing method for all commands in Git Bash or on Windows
  10.

My Git Bash is

```
$ uname -a
MINGW64_NT-10.0-19044 mypc 3.1.6-340.x86_64 2020-07-09 14:33 UTC x86_64 Msys
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is about a general tracing method for all commands in Git Bash or on Windows 10.

So, since [Git TRACE2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094711/6309) alone is not relevant for you, you can try [**rabbitstack/fibratus**](https://github.com/rabbitstack/fibratus/)

> Fibratus is a tool for exploration and tracing of the Windows kernel.
>
> It lets you trap system-wide events such as process life-cycle, file system I/O, registry modifications or network requests among many other observability signals.
>
> In a nutshell, Fibratus allows for gaining deep operational visibility into the Windows kernel but also processes running on top of it.

You still need to configure exactly what this tool will capture though.

[Nedo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1027467/nedo), the author of [Fibratus](https://github.com/rabbitstack/fibratus/) (GitHub account [`bhnedo`](https://github.com/bhnedo)) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71454190/in-git-bash-how-to-trace-a-non-git-command/71464877?noredirect=1#comment128795353_71464877):

> Fibratus relies on internal Windows tracing mechanism.
> This means no kernel drivers are installed on your machine.
>
> You need a simple filter expression by running `fibratus` as ([String filter operator](https://github.com/rabbitstack/fibratus/blob/4e324480e086a234c960c87e5ff6e2cfb3b1d279/docs/filters/operators.md#string-operators)):
>
> ```
> fibratus run ps.name icontains 'git'
> ```

Comment: Thank you @VonC. This seems to be a very powerful tool, so powerful that I worry about its security risk to my PC.  I am looking into it.

Comment: Author here. Fibratus relies on internal Windows tracing mechanism. This means no kernel drivers are installed on your machine. You need a simple filter expression by running fibratus as: fibratus run ps.name icontains 'git'. Let me know if this was useful.

Comment: @Nedo It is useful, thank you for this. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Appreciate that. Thanks!