# VSCode Git has slowed down substantially

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Hoping someone can help; my VS Code Git functions are all taking quite a long time compared to previously. I've suffered through it a while now but getting a bit fed-up (hence the post) but unfortunately can't pin-point a date it started.

My output console for Git shows a lot of processes taking over 1000ms, up to 3800ms for certain functions. Individually it's not a big deal, but all together it's now slowing my commit process down to a good 30 odd seconds each so I'm getting sloppy with my commits.

I have no idea where to go from here; I've updated to the latest version of VS Code which hasn't made a difference.

I've manually tried staging and committing changes via the git bash CLI and it runs as normal with everything operating in under 0.6ms.

Here is my VSCode git output when doing a simple commit; a lot of extra commands running compared to what I would do manually, but even the first line of add is over 1s

```
[2022-10-17T23:15:35.215Z] > git add -A -- . [1037ms]
[2022-10-17T23:15:37.232Z] > git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file - [1536ms]
[2022-10-17T23:15:38.937Z] > git status -z -uall [1223ms]
[2022-10-17T23:15:39.818Z] > git ls-files --stage -- C:\Code\temp\strapi-frontend\test4.txt [1291ms]
[2022-10-17T23:15:40.864Z] > git symbolic-ref --short HEAD [1272ms]
[2022-10-17T23:15:41.849Z] > git cat-file -s e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391 [1405ms]
[2022-10-17T23:15:42.950Z] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track)%00%(upstream:remotename)%00%(upstream:remoteref) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main [1400ms]
[2022-10-17T23:15:44.462Z] > git show --textconv :test4.txt [1969ms]
[2022-10-17T23:15:45.115Z] > git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname) [1505ms]
[2022-10-17T23:15:45.583Z] > git remote --verbose [1120ms]
[2022-10-17T23:15:47.084Z] > git config --get commit.template [1012ms]
[2022-10-17T23:15:48.536Z] > git config --get commit.template [970ms]
```

And here is via the command line

```
$ git add test3.txt
00:11:21.377977 read-cache.c:2303       performance: 0.000341300 s:  read cache .git/index
00:11:21.378973 name-hash.c:600         performance: 0.000015000 s:   initialize name hash
00:11:21.378973 dir.c:2369              performance: 0.000189100 s:  read directory
00:11:21.378973 diff-lib.c:251          performance: 0.000008100 s:  diff-files
00:11:21.380457 read-cache.c:3030       performance: 0.000506700 s:  write index, changed mask = 28
00:11:21.381449 trace.c:475             performance: 0.006232800 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe' add test3.txt
git

jonco@JON-DESKTOP (main)
$ git commit -m "Test git via CLI again"
00:11:33.121011 read-cache.c:2303       performance: 0.000124200 s:  read cache .git/index
00:11:33.123987 read-cache.c:1617       performance: 0.001619800 s:  refresh index
00:11:33.125471 cache-tree.c:444        performance: 0.001810500 s:  cache_tree_update
00:11:33.125967 read-cache.c:3030       performance: 0.000484900 s:  write index, changed mask = 20
00:11:33.129442 unpack-trees.c:1548     performance: 0.000017000 s:    traverse_trees
00:11:33.129442 unpack-trees.c:1645     performance: 0.000033400 s:   unpack_trees
00:11:33.129442 diff-lib.c:537          performance: 0.000143700 s:  diff-index
00:11:33.129442 cache-tree.c:444        performance: 0.000071500 s:  cache_tree_update
00:11:33.627922 trace.c:475             performance: 0.002758800 s: git command: git gc --auto
[main 13c670a] Test git via CLI again
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 test3.txt
00:11:33.630895 trace.c:475             performance: 0.514299600 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe' commit -m 'Test git via CLI again'
```

Anyone got any tips?

Comment: Here's a similar example, his solution may or may not be applicable to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71758917/421195

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I opened a sub-folder Containing the code that I work on and a Parent folder containing the .git file, When opening VScode it asked me to use the parent folder git, and I said yes which caused the issue. **Change or rename the directory you're working on that should Reset VScode**

Comment: fyi: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49325617