# How can I abort a commit from VS Code's UI?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sometimes when I do commit from UI I need to wait a long time (in the order of several minutes). How can I abort this operation?

[image: vscode]

Problem occurs when for example I have pre commit analysis or when I click I know the commit won't pass but still it take some time to process. I wonder if there is any way of aborting the operation?

Or at leat some kind of timeout to not wait longer than 30s.

[image: vscode]

Comment: Have you checked the logs ? Maybe you have a hook that takes some time. If you want to abort the operation, restart VSCode

Comment: As you see on screenshot it take almost 3 minutes to just commit. OK it's nx monorepo with almost 7 projects but still 3 minutes?

Comment: Can you link the repository so we can check if there's any weird files being processed ?

Comment: I can't. It's an internal company project. Maybe something with linting or config?

Comment: Have you checked this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71551269/git-through-vscode-is-unusably-slow ?

Comment: OK, it looks like VSCode is using Credential Manager, and it is causing problems. So I think it's a bug.

Answer (score 2):

There are two related issue tickets:

- [Add the possibility to abort a pre commit hook operation #66821](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/66821), which is closed with a recommendation to just restart/reload VS Code, which kills the child git process (I'd also suggest doing this as a workaround for the time being). See also the `Developer: Reload Window` command in the command palette.
- [Git - Add support for cancelling long commit operation (including its pre-commit script) #171353](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/171353). Currently in the backlog. There is a setting `git.supportCancellation` for cancelling sync operations, but cancelling commits is not currently supported. I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".

I'd also suggest that you check the Output Panel's Git channel to see if there are any related-looking messages in there.