# sudo npm install -g hfc fails

Tags: git, hyperledger

I am trying to get my hyperledger dev environment up and running but I run into issues. the step that fails is the installation on hfc. The OS I am using is Ubuntu 20.04

I am following the instructions as provided [here](https://openblockchain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/NodeSDK-setup/) which is pretty straightforward.
the first command immediately fails however: npm install -g hfc

This is the output I get:

```
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/mcavage/node-asn1.git
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

I have checked the ssh certificates which were missing and have generated these. Checked the file permissions on the certificates as well and these are what they should be.

Next I checked the presence of the referenced git repository (mcavage/node-asn1.git) and I can not find it.

So my question:
Am I still missing credentials to actually see the repository?
Or has the repo been renamed?
Or am I missing something else?

Comment: https://github.com/TritonDataCenter/node-asn1 exists. It is your keys that are not setup correctly. Can take a look at this answer to try to debug your ssh connection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38706495/887539

Comment: Thanks @AndreasLouv, I did some more browsing on the SSH keys. Got it sorted now.

Comment: I'm happy that you figured it out.

Comment: Did some more research after new issues came up. The key issue for my problem was that node (and npm) had been installed using a different account. Found that the preferred way to go about this is the use of nvm: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm