# Git push HTTPS with Personal access token asking for password

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote

I cloned the origin remote repo to my local repository using my generated Personal access token. Now I want to push commit changes to my remote repository, git is asking for password.

I searched around here and I found help in setting my origin URL from SSH to HTTPS using;

```
git remote set-url origin https://<PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN>@github.com/<Username>/<repo>.git
```

I confirmed the change using `git remote -v` its now showing

```
origin  https://ghp_kGuXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX8dd@github.com/<correct_user>/<right_repo>.git (fetch)                                
origin  https://ghp_kGuXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX8dd@github.com/<correct_user>/<right_repo>.git (push)
```

Still, when I try `git push` it still ask for password. Please I need help. I'm frustrated already. How can I push to my remote repo using on PAT without password prompt.

Comment: This is a simple syntactic error: as [kadewu answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72297372/1256452), the syntax is a literal `https://` followed by the user name followed by a colon followed by the PAT followed by an at-sign `@` followed by the host name followed by a slash followed by the repository path on that host. But remember that a token *is* a kind of password: by putting it into cleartext here, you are broadcasting the password to anyone who can look at things on your machine. It's usually wiser to keep these secret, using a credential manager.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate. The 'username:' after the 'https://' is it to be typed verbettim or to be replaced with my own username?

Comment: Replaced with your user name, yes.

Comment: I just tried the answer provided by @kadewu and I'm getting an error message `fatal: authentication for <said url> failed`. What could still be wrong please?

Comment: Hard to be sure with https, but see [How can I debug git/git-shell related problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6178401/1256452)

Comment: @Thundrizzy did you ever get this working?

Comment: No, there is *NOT* a username after the @, just the token. This error means you are using an old (invalid) token.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use PAT via URL in HTTPS you should define it this way.

```
git remote set-url origin https://username:token@github.com/put_username_here/repo-name.git
```

You are missing the username.

Comment: Unfortunately, running `git push origin main` after setting the origin URL returns the following error message: `remote: Invalid username or password. fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/<my username>/<my repo>.git/'`

Comment: @KiriSakow That means you provided wrong credentials.

Comment: No, there should *NOT* be a username before the token. Just use the token itself.

Comment: @CpnCrunch What is the reasoning behind that statement? The fact that e.g. GH doesn't require right now `username` doesn't mean it should not be placed.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, it does work with a username. I should have said that the username isn't necessary, and won't fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by using an old (invalid) token. For some reason github just shows a confusing error message saying "enter password", then says you can't use a password.

If you have a working repo that you can push to, type "git remote -v" to show the correct token. If not, just create a new token:

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens