# git fetch, git pull not working in my VM in GCP

Tags: git, github, google-cloud-platform, ssh, virtual-machine

I am a GCP user. I have a VM that is running in GCP.

But recently, when I try to run the "`git pull`" or "`git fetch`" commands to update my project, it just hung there, and there are no responses.

My project is on GitHub.
It worked very well a few weeks ago. I didn't change any ssh or network config.

Not sure what kind of problem it is. I will appreciate it if anyone could give some advice.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem and resolved it. Hope this can help other people who faced the same issue as mine.

This was my ssh config file

```bash
Host github.com
      HostName github.com
      PreferredAuthentications publickey
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      AddKeysToAgent yes
```

After I removed the line `AddKeysToAgent yes`, it works now. I don't know why it worked before.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to make sure if you are indeed using ssh on GCP in your repository folder:

```
cd /path/to/repository
git remote -v
# Check the URL is
# git@github.com:you/yourRepository
#              ^^^ (note the :)
# Or:
# ssh://git@github.com/you/yourRepository
#                    ^^^ (note the /)
```

Check also your environment variables:

```
env|grep -i SSH
```

(A `GIT_SSH...` environment variable might affect how Git operates with SSH)

And see if the network route is still opened from your GCP shell to GitHub:

```
curl -v telnet://github.com:22
# You should see
Connected to github.com (140.82.121.3) port 22 (#0)
```

For testing, check if you can use (while entering your GitHub account and a [GitHub Personal Acccess Token or PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)) use HTTPS:

```
git ls-remote https://github.com/You/yourRepository
```

---

If you are using SSH, activate traces on SSH ,and on Git itself with [`TRACE2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094711/6309):

```bash
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tv'
GIT_TRACE2_EVENT=1 git pull
# or
GIT_TRACE2=1 git pull
```

As noted in the OP [Louis Hong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4673233/louis-hong)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72961757/6309), activating the traces would show the step where, by tring to add a key to an `ssh-agent` (from the `~/.ssh/config`), said ssh-agent might request a passphrase for *another* (encrypted) key, thereby hanging on stdin.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Yes, I am sure I am using ssh in my repository. I also use `curl -v telnet://github.com:22` to check the network, it works and the result is just like you posted. Checked my `env`, and there is no variable with the prefix `GIT_SSH`.

Comment: I also logged in with my GitHub account and Personal Access Token, and it succeed. But `git fetch` and `git pull` are still not working.

Comment: @LouisHong Did you HTTPS clone it on GCP, with the same GCP account than the one used when doing a git pull/fetch. And those pull/fetch are done from the newly cloned repository folder?

Comment: @LouisHong I have edited the answer to include traces.

Comment: Thank you so much! I found there is a problem in my ssh config file. I fixed it and it works now!