# Git commands get stuck if done in quick succession

Tags: git, github, ssh

I use Git remote operations like `pull`, `push`, and `fetch` very often and usually in quick succession. However, after I started using two GitHub accounts on my computer, I noticed that these operations would often get stuck if done too close together. It is almost as if there is an operation limit of 1 or 2 per minute. If I call `git push` and then `git pull` immediately after, the `git pull` will hang and never finish. However, if I wait a minute, then the `git pull` command will work again.

I've tried many ways to configure working with two GitHub accounts on my computer. I use SSH so I have a proper ssh config file set up with two keys and separate hosts. This did not work. I'm currently using the `.gitconfig` method where I identify what `ssh` command to use per repo. This also does not work.

How can I diagnose the cause of this problem and how can I fix it?

My Setup:

- macOS Monterey
- Git version 2.37.1
- Standard firewall and antivirtus (nothing special)

Thanks!

Comment: What OS and version of Git are you using?  Are you using a non-default anti-virus or firewall, or any sort of other proxy or monitoring software?

Comment: Updated my post!

Comment: For what it's worth, this *should not* be a problem, but people will probably need VonC's recommended trace output to figure out what's going on and why it actually *is* being a problem. :-) The trace output might not be sufficient as it probably involves some sort of lower level network glitch, but what that might be, I have no idea.

Comment: (We've seen the occasional really-bizarre network glitch on macOS, though pre-Monterey, that a whole collection of networking nerds never managed to figure out, even with proper tracing tools and everything.)

Answer (score 0):

You can enable logs, with [`GIT_TRACE2_EVENT`](https://git-scm.com/docs/api-trace2#_the_event_format_target) (with [trace2 presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094711/6309))

```
export GIT_TRACE2_EVENT=~/log.event
```

Then repeat your commands until being stuck, and you will see what Git was doing at the time of the issue.